# Tips for golfing in Common Lisp

Tags: code-golf, tips, lisp

What general tips do you have for golfing in Common Lisp? I'm looking for ideas which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to Common Lisp (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: Narrower version of [Tips for golfing in Lisp](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79719/tips-for-golfing-in-lisp).

Comment: @zyabin101 right. I thought that since original topic didn't have too many answers, and Lisp itself is a huge family, I might as well ask for a specific language.

Answer (score 2):

Use `'` (quote) as synonym for `""` for single words.

Quote stops evaluation of symbol, allowing you to e.g. print it. Note that the casing is dependant on `*print-case*` variable (most of the time it's in the upcase).

```
(print"yes")
(print'yes) ; saved a byte!
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use the best looping construct for the job

Use looping constructs that are as short as possible - `loop for` is rarely the way to go:

- `(dotimes(i <number>))` to loop a certain number of times
- `(mapcan lambda list)` to map a list
- `(mapcar lambda list)` to map and flatten a list
- `(do((var1 initialvalue1 nextvalue1)(var2 initialvalue2 nextvalue2)...)((endcondition)returnvalue))` for more complex loops
- `(map'string body list)` to map string -> string
- `(map nil body list)` to iterate over a list