# Output programming language name

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source

### Challenge:

In the programming language of your choice, take no input and output your programming language's name.

Fair enough, right?

**Restrictions:**

- You can't use any character that is included in your programming language's name in your code. E.g., if I use Batch, I must not use the chars 'B' 'a' t' 'c' 'h' in my code. Note that this is case sensitive. I can still use the char 'b' because it's different from 'B'.
- You can have "junk output" before or after the name of the language
- Version number doesn't count as part of the name of the language. E.g., I can use the number 3 in the code in my answer if it's in Python 3
- The output of the programming language name is not case sensitive.
- Brute-forcing all possible letter combinations and hoping you get your language name is forbidden.

---

**Example outputs:** (let's say my programming language is called Language) (✔ if valid, else ✖)

- `Language` ✔
- `Body language is a type of non-verbal communication in which physical behavior, as opposed to words, is used to express or convey information. Such behavior includes facial expressions, body posture, gestures, eye movement, touch and the use of space.` ✔
- `Language 2.0 - © 1078 AD some company` ✔
- `foobar` ✖

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) thus shortest code wins.

Comment: The rule about case sensitive restrictions is very ambiguous. Which is the correct orthography: BASIC Basic or basic? I'm pretty sure I can find examples for all three.

Comment: Obligatory "Just having your code be blank but have a flag like `--version` isn't allowed"?

Comment: Have case-insensitive output while banning the language name case-sensitively allows boring solutions that just output the language name case-swapped.

Comment: Does the output need to go to the screen/be printed, or can it be returned as well?

Comment: @xnor Agreed. This should be changed.

Comment: @xnor I won't change it, because outputting the name case-swapped would need at least the amount of bytes the name is, which allows more creative answers to win, since they would have lower byte count.

Comment: Can I pass my language name as a command line argument if my language does not have a method to reliably print what's passed, and may even automatically error on certain command line arguments? The idea is that the command line argument specifies the regex that is used to parse the source code. My language name happens to be valid regex, and would lead to a (semi-) interesting solution. Because of certain constraints, it may not even be optimal, as command line arguments add to your byte count.

Comment: You made a mistake by allowing users to output junk data. All they have to do is use a language where the compiler include the name whenever there's an error. It's cool but not the challenge I was hoping for

Comment: Can the filename of the program include the language name?

Comment: This question really needs to be specified that "Code" must be run.  Most languages will show their name in the usage dump if you don't give any code--for instance "Java" or "Groovy" at the command line with no code will display the correct name, however if you pass code (even "empty" code) as in (groovy -e "") you will get an empty response.  Same for compile problems, the compiler usage or error output does not mean you wrote a program.

Comment: @Lynob to be honest, if we wanted something creative we would need to ban ascii code/unicode/and such things.

Comment: @Lynob preventing output to stderr should prevent a lot of language to use such a trick

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it in Smalltalk. ```Object comment``` uses 2 characters in the name Smalltalk.

Comment: Just want to point out how amusing it is that this is absolutely impossible in ///!

Comment: If it's "brute forcing", then I'm not really "hoping" for the right answer. It's 100% deterministic.

Answer (score 88):

### Outputs to STDERR

[Outputting to STDERR](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2451/20260) is now at +33/-21 as an allowed default, which is positive but contested. This is a [CW answer to collect answers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11211/20260) that just invoke an error in a language where error messages includes the language name.

#### [Haskell, 1 byte](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@2/4/z8A)

```haskell
1
```

Error:

```
Parse error: naked expression at top level
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
```

#### [Lua, 1 byte](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@2/4/z8A)

```lua
1
```

Error:

```
lua: .code.tio:1: syntax error near <eof>
```

(file name is unimportant)

#### Batch, 1 byte

```
~
```

Error:

```
'~' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

#### [tinylisp, 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8nMq8zJLC74/18jWUPT8P9/AA)

```
(c()1
```

Error:

```
Error: cannot cons to Int in tinylisp
```

#### R, 1 byte

```
)
```

Error:

```
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"
```

#### Java bytecode, 0 bytes

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
```

#### Groovy, 1 byte

```
a
```

Note that `a` can be replaced with any other character

Error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a ...
```

#### MATLAB, 1 byte

```matlab
\
```

Error:

```
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

#### [PHP, 3 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/php#@29jb/v/PwA)

```
<?=
```

Error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/runner/.code.tio on line 1
```

#### CJam, 1 byte

```
/
```

Error:

```
/
^
RuntimeException: The stack is empty
Java exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: The stack is empty
    at net.aditsu.cjam.CJam.pop(CJam.java:75)
    at net.aditsu.cjam.Op2.run(Op2.java:10)
    at net.aditsu.cjam.Block.run(Block.java:304)
    at net.aditsu.cjam.CJam.runCode(CJam.java:210)
    at net.aditsu.cjam.CJam.main(CJam.java:240)
```

#### [Twig, 2 bytes](https://twigfiddle.com/h1bvzf)

Twig is a template language written in PHP. It's possible that this is a polyglot.

```
{{
{%
{#
```

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message [...] in [...][...]:n:
Stack trace:
#0 [...]
```

The message varies depending on which program you choose.

#### [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 2 bytes

```
x+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@1@h/f8/AA)

Trivially invokes undocumented behavior. Silos is the name of the language.

#### Python, 6 bytes

```
pYTHON
```

As the character restriction is case insensitive, and the output doesn't have to be in the correct case, this is a valid answer. The error message it produces is something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".code.tio", line 1, in <module>
    pYTHON
NameError: name 'pYTHON' is not defined
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@18QGeLh7/f/PwA) (outputs to 'debug' tab)

#### JavaScript, 10 bytes

```
jAVAsCRIPT
```

This produces the following error message or similar in all environments:

```
ReferenceError: jAVAsCRIPT is not defined
```

#### [QBIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108030/44874), 6 bytes

```
?b(12)
```

In 6 bytes, we can put QBIC encountered error: 9 on the screen, signifying an out-of-bounds error.

#### ForceLang, 2 bytes

```
()
```

Error produced:

```
Exception in thread "main" lang.exceptions.IllegalInvocationException: null is not a function.
    at lang.ForceLang.parse(ForceLang.java:99)
    at lang.ForceLang.main(ForceLang.java:129)
```

#### [Pip, 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fsC4hOuH/fwA)

```
1~`[`
```

(Note: this works in the current version as of this writing, [0.17.09.01](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip/commit/6723e170f5baab521af5a7114ac401dd7b639582). No guarantees the interpreter won't change to handle this error differently in the future.)

Tries to regex match with a syntactically invalid pattern. The error produced will look something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pip/pip.py", line 221, in <module>
    pip(interactive=False)
  File "/opt/pip/pip.py", line 206, in pip
    state.executeProgram(tree, args)
  File "/opt/pip/execution.py", line 56, in executeProgram
    returnVal = self.functionCall(mainFunction, cmdLineArgs)
  File "/opt/pip/execution.py", line 368, in functionCall
    returnVal = self.getRval(returnExpr)
  File "/opt/pip/execution.py", line 235, in getRval
    expr = self.evaluate(expr)
  File "/opt/pip/execution.py", line 213, in evaluate
    result = opFunction(*args)
  File "/opt/pip/execution.py", line 1134, in FIRSTMATCH
    matchObj = regex.asRegex().search(str(string))
  File "/opt/pip/ptypes.py", line 175, in asRegex
    self._compiled = re.compile(pyRegex)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 855, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 765, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 523, in _parse
    source.tell() - here)
sre_constants.error: unterminated character set at position 8
```

#### [Stax, 2 bytes](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=0u&i=&a=1)

```
0u
```

Error:

```
Stax runtime error: rational divide by zero
```

`zh` also works.

#### [ink, 1 byte](http://tio.run/##y8zL/v@/7v9/AA)

```
~
```

`~` at the start of a line marks that the line is a statement to be executed, rather than text to be printed. As of whichever version of inklecate TIO is using, if there's nothing after the `~`, the interpreter crashes with the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Ink.InkParser.LogicLine () [0x000b1] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.StringParser.ParseObject (Ink.StringParser+ParseRule rule) [0x00012] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.StringParser.OneOf (Ink.StringParser+ParseRule[] array) [0x0000a] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.InkParser.StatementAtLevel (Ink.InkParser+StatementLevel level) [0x00009] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.InkParser+<>c__DisplayClass134_0.<StatementsAtLevel>b__0 () [0x00000] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.StringParser.ParseObject (Ink.StringParser+ParseRule rule) [0x00012] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.StringParser.Interleave[T] (Ink.StringParser+ParseRule ruleA, Ink.StringParser+ParseRule ruleB, Ink.StringParser+ParseRule untilTerminator, System.Boolean flatten) [0x00040] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.InkParser.StatementsAtLevel (Ink.InkParser+StatementLevel level) [0x0004f] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.InkParser.Parse () [0x00000] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.Compiler.Compile () [0x00033] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.CommandLineTool..ctor (System.String[] args) [0x001a3] in <d64e27e7788347b2a5377c9e19bbdcab>:0 
  at Ink.CommandLineTool.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <d64e27e7788347b2a5377c9e19bbdcab>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Ink.InkParser.LogicLine () [0x000b1] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.StringParser.ParseObject (Ink.StringParser+ParseRule rule) [0x00012] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.StringParser.OneOf (Ink.StringParser+ParseRule[] array) [0x0000a] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.InkParser.StatementAtLevel (Ink.InkParser+StatementLevel level) [0x00009] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.InkParser+<>c__DisplayClass134_0.<StatementsAtLevel>b__0 () [0x00000] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.StringParser.ParseObject (Ink.StringParser+ParseRule rule) [0x00012] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.StringParser.Interleave[T] (Ink.StringParser+ParseRule ruleA, Ink.StringParser+ParseRule ruleB, Ink.StringParser+ParseRule untilTerminator, System.Boolean flatten) [0x00040] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.InkParser.StatementsAtLevel (Ink.InkParser+StatementLevel level) [0x0004f] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.InkParser.Parse () [0x00000] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.Compiler.Compile () [0x00033] in <b1e5e74f4ee842fc961297862cf23e07>:0 
  at Ink.CommandLineTool..ctor (System.String[] args) [0x001a3] in <d64e27e7788347b2a5377c9e19bbdcab>:0 
  at Ink.CommandLineTool.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <d64e27e7788347b2a5377c9e19bbdcab>:0
```

#### [Rust, 0 bytes](https://tio.run/##KyotLvkPBAA)

Error:

```
error[E0601]: `main` function not found in crate `code`
  |
  = note: consider adding a `main` function to `code.tio`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0601`.
```

#### [sed, 1 byte](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlwYKlpSVpuhYLHSE0lAsTBgA)

```
A
```

Error:

```
sed: file /ATO/code line 1: unknown command: `A'
```

#### [flat assembler, 0 byte](https://tio.run/##SywuTs1NyqnUTUsszv0PBAA)

Error:

```
flat assembler  version 1.73.16  (16384 kilobytes memory, x64)
1 passes, 0 bytes.
```

#### GolfScript, 1 byte

```
\
```

Error:

```
/opt/golfscript/golfscript.rb:118:in `block in to_gs': undefined method `to_gs' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/golfscript/golfscript.rb:118:in `each'
    from /opt/golfscript/golfscript.rb:118:in `inject'
    from /opt/golfscript/golfscript.rb:118:in `to_gs'
    from (eval):1:in `block in initialize'
    from /opt/golfscript/golfscript.rb:306:in `go'
    from (eval):1:in `block in initialize'
    from /opt/golfscript/golfscript.rb:306:in `go'
    from (eval):1:in `block in initialize'
    from /opt/golfscript/golfscript.rb:306:in `go'
    from /opt/golfscript/golfscript.rb:500:in `<main>'
```

#### [Thunno, 0 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZoFJQGAA)

Error (for Thunno v1.2.1):

```
Thunno, v1.2.1
```

#### [Vyxal, 2 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m720rLIiMWfBgqWlJWm6FovP7a5YUpyUXAzlw8QB)

```
λx
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/vyxal", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vyxal/main.py", line 470, in cli
    execute_vyxal(file_name, flags, inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vyxal/main.py", line 430, in execute_vyxal
    vy_print(output, ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vyxal/elements.py", line 7253, in vy_print
    res = safe_apply(lhs, *args, ctx=ctx, arity_override=override)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vyxal/helpers.py", line 983, in safe_apply
    ret = function(
  File "<string>", line 10, in _lambda_36f6fb46b5889e1e4e91c1f138c09b37
  File "<string>", line 10, in _lambda_36f6fb46b5889e1e4e91c1f138c09b37
  File "<string>", line 10, in _lambda_36f6fb46b5889e1e4e91c1f138c09b37
  [Previous line repeated 982 more times]
  File "<string>", line 8, in _lambda_36f6fb46b5889e1e4e91c1f138c09b37
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vyxal/LazyList.py", line 184, in __len__
    next(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vyxal/LazyList.py", line 198, in __next__
    item = vyxalify(next(self.raw_object))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vyxal/helpers.py", line 1488, in vyxalify
    return sympy.nsimplify(value, rational=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/simplify/simplify.py", line 1436, in nsimplify
    return sympify(as_int(expr))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py", line 383, in sympify
    return conv(a)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sympy/core/cache.py", line 72, in wrapper
    retval = cfunc(*args, **kwargs)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: Isn't the empty string contained in the language's name? :D

Comment: The C and R ones are **c**leve**r**.

Comment: @mbomb007 but it's not a character, therefore it's not a character included in the language's name.

Comment: The PHP version can be disabled, if I'm not mistaken. Using something like `<??` will be more effective and can't be disabled.

Comment: C can be 0 bytes, since if theres nothing it will complain that theres no main

Comment: PHP, 1 byte: `php -r '1'`

Comment: Does the S.I.L.O.S one count? It doesn't output the periods.

Comment: "_**Java bytecode, 0 bytes**_". First time I see Java triumphing above ALL of those other languages mentioned. :)

Answer (score 54):

## SmileBASIC, 11 bytes

```
sPsET.,1474
```

Equivalent to `SPSET 0,1474`. Sets sprite 0 to definition 1474, which is the SmileBASIC logo.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 45):

## R, 1 byte:

```
T
```

`T` is an alias for the constant `TRUE`. So the output for the above is:

```
[1] TRUE
```

Since junk is allowed around the name, the “R” in there is the language name.

([As noted in a comment elsewhere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107964/output-programming-language-name?page=2&tab=oldest#comment262884_108035), pretty much any single letter and many glyphs will work equally well because they trigger the message “Error: …”, which contains “r”.)

Answer (score 44):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 1 byte

```
Y
```

Output is through STDERR, which is [allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2451/36398).

The output from the offline compiler is

```
Error using matl_parse (line 339)
MATL error while parsing: Y not recognized at position 1
Error in matl (line 234)
    S = matl_parse(s, useTags);
```

Or [try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x/5/z8A) (expand "debug" section).

Comment: Should you merge with [this](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107992/43394)?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm not sure. I asked in chat and got [these](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35001113#35001113) two [replies](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35001843#35001843), so it's not really clear

Comment: yeah but Y tho?

Comment: @sagiksp Anything that throws an error will do, such as `X` or `Z`. This is because `X`, `Y` or `Z` are prefixes of two-char function names, so a `Y` by itself is invalid

Answer (score 32):

## HTML, <s>24</s> 20 bytes

```html
&#72;&#84;&#77;&#76;
```

---

## HTML, 16 bytes

[As pointed out by @Bob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107964/output-programming-language-name/107990?noredirect=1#comment262780_107990), modern browsers will recognize HTML entities without semicolons, though it's technically invalid HTML. Of course, it's perfectly valid for code golf.

```html
&#72&#84&#77&#76
```

---

## HTML, 4 bytes

And of course, the uninteresting answer.

```html
html
```

---

Also, see my [CSS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108001/47097).

Comment: You can save four characters by using decimal instead: `&#72;&#84;&#77;&#76;`. You can save an additional four characters by dropping the semicolons, at the cost of being technically invalid HTML (but still working in modern browsers).

Comment: Why doesn't `HTML` count?

Comment: @OrangeDog "You can't use any character that is included in your programming language's name in your code"

Comment: But `html` should be valid, reducing the score by 12 bytes.

Comment: @Christoph Added.

Comment: Is this a valid HTML document? I thought you had to include the whole doctype + header + body stuff. If you must have header, it's impossible to complete this challenge with HTML.

Comment: @Clearer This is code golf! As long as it works in at least one environment, who cares whether W3C thinks it's valid?

Comment: How can `html` be valid?  Either it uses letters of the programming language's name (if you think case doesn't matter) or it doesn't output the programming language's name (if you think case matters).  The restriction of not being allowed to use the letters of the programming language's name is clearly to avoid exactly this approach.

Comment: @Alfe Read rules carefully. It says that output is not-case sensitive while only characters of other case can be used. As pointed out in comments below question, it is easy to bypass yet valid.

Answer (score 29):

## Vim, 0 bytes

When you start Vim, the editor displays a splash screen which looks like this:

[image: Vim splash screen]

You can see it says `Vim` here:

[image: Vim splash screen with vim highlighted]

Previous answer:

## Vim, 1 byte

```
<Ctrl-C>
```

In Vim 8, pressing  will display `Type  :quit<Enter>  to exit Vim` at the last line. I'm not completely sure if this counts.

Comment: It should count. Ctrl-C actually has its own ASCII code (code 3, also called ETX or "end of text"), so this is a pure-ASCII program (if not purely *printable* ASCII). You can use that to prove that the program's one byte long, and displaying text on screen counts.

Comment: Since when is "vim" a programming language?

Comment: @DepressedDaniel vim is actually a scripting language if you take a deeper look into the internals. All those fancy keystrokes are instructions => you're programming when you're controlling your editor.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel is it turing complete? If it's not, I don't think it should count.

Comment: @Clearer, several significant languages are not Turing complete by default (e.g., Coq, Agda, and Isabelle) or have non-Turing complete modes of operation (e.g., Idris). It would be very sad if those were excluded!

Comment: @dfeuer I've come to agree with you, since I made that comment more than 2 years ago.

Answer (score 21):

## Python, 15 bytes

### Python 2 (15)

```py
exec"\150elp()"
```

It concatenates the strings uses the octal `150` which is `h` and `"elp()"` and runs the result. This prints the `help()` command which says `"Welcome to Python 3.5's help utility!"`, meeting the requirements.

### Python 3 (17)

```py
exec("\150elp()")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@6@sEFBZkpGfp2DMpayQWpGarKEUY2hqkJpToKGppMnFBZc34uICSSPJ/v8PAA)

Comment: Not sure `help` counts, it only works in a REPL environment.

Comment: It still prints out the Python. That's all that's required.

Comment: If it works in TIO surely it's a valid answer?

Comment: Never mind, I was mistaken and it works as a program. Sorry about that.

Comment: you have used the letter 'p'

Comment: `p` is allowed but `P` isn't. Rule 1.

Comment: oh yes, my bad! nice answer

Comment: In the REPL, it prints Python and the version, sooooo????

Answer (score 19):

## C, 0 bytes.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/oYZvTj)

Comment: where is the name ? Or do you refer to the c characters in there ?

Comment: This should be marked as C (gcc), because other compilers have different messages.

Comment: Meh, your `c`'s come from extremely implementation-dependent sources. Would have been nicer if you at least provoked a message that contains `c` in some boilerplate output.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel undefined referen**c**e to 'main'

Comment: @LorenPechtel Fair enough, missed that.

Comment: C has always been the "bite me"-language.

Comment: This is not `C`, this is `gcc`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 No, it's not GCC. GCC isn't a language. You're correct that it isn't C however. This answer is simply incorrect.

Comment: This is 0 bytes of C. Also works in ISO C: `prog.c:1: error: ISO C forbids an empty translation unit [-Werror=pedantic]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`

Comment: @Jakob Of course it is GCC, you put something in GCC and the output is the compiled program and the diagnosis messages (warnings, errors, ...). GCC expects C, but that isn't C.

Comment: It also works in **c**c1: https://ideone.com/8Az8yY

Answer (score 19):

## Huh?, 0 bytes

<sup>(no, there's nothing in that code block)</sup>

[The language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Huh%3F) is named for its output, so...

In [the implementation I checked](https://github.com/kade-robertson/pythuhn/blob/master/pythuhn.py), the interpreter takes the length mod 8 of each line of a given file, and switches depending on the result. For zero, it prints `Huh?`. Since it strips trailing newlines, you could also do a 1 byte (`\n`) version.

Note that it's not outputting to stderr or caseswapping or any other trickery. It's just that Huh?'s very confused interpreter finally came in handy.

Comment: Wait, is this language Turing complete?

Answer (score 17):

### C, <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 5 Bytes

Compiled C on a Linux machine with a German locale:

`main;`

It will try to call the variable `main` which is not allowed because `main` is stored  in the bss section which has the NX bit set, therefore generates a SIGSEGV and prints `Speicherzugriffsfehler` (german for Segmentation fault) on stderr.

Stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1770717/6082851

---

**Old answer with 14 Bytes**

Compiled C on a Linux machine with the C locale on AMD64, compiled with gcc:

`main(a){a/=0;}`

This will create a division by zero exception and print `Floating point exception` on stderr. Not sure about other implementation, architectures or compilers since it uses UB.

---

**Old answer with 15 Bytes**

Compiled C on a Linux machine with a German locale:

`main(){main();}`

It will run to a stack overflow and print `Speicherzugriffsfehler` (german for Segmentation fault) on stderr.

Comment: ............ :-D

Answer (score 14):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 2 bytes

```
¬U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@39oTej//wA)

The obvious answer is:

```
év~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394ZVnd//8A)

Which is "Insert the letter 'v', and toggle case". However, since you allow for junk output before/after the language name, this works too.

The `¬` command takes two characters for input, and inserts every ASCII character between them. If we don't supply the second character, it automatically defaults to `ÿ` (ASCII 0xff), so this program inserts every character in the latin1 encoding between `U` and `ÿ`.

Answer (score 14):

### [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 54 bytes

```
+[[-<]-[->]<-]<.<<<<.>>>>-.<<-.<.>>.<<<+++.>>>---.<++.
```

Outputs `brainfuck`, assuming an 8-bit tape open on the left. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#FYiBCQAwCMMOKtkFxUfE/89wNRAIWXXjoakx4@fwKpCM6XuS7kJWcvcD)

As always, partial credits go to [@primo's Hello, World! answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68494/21487).

#### Alternatives with different casing

**Brainfuck** (62 bytes):

```
+[<-[-<]-[->]<<]<---.<<<<<<--.>>>-.<+.<.>---.<<+++.>>---.<---.
```

**BrainFuck** (68 bytes):

```
-[[-<]->+[->]<-]<<.<<<<<--.>>+.<-.+++++.>>>------.<<<<+++.>>++.<---.
```

Answer (score 13):

## Python, <s>27</s> <s>53</s> <s>49</s> <s>48</s> <s>45</s> 31 bytes

-3 bytes from @wizzwizz4

```
exec'IM\x50ORT THIS'.swapcase()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboW-1MrUpPVPX1jKkwN_INCFEI8PIPV9YrLEwuSE4tTNTQhqqCKYZoA)

Prints the following text, which has "Python" on the first line.

```
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Comment: @Arnauld fixed!

Comment: `HELP()` or `HELP(HELP)` is shorter.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you swap the case of the import string, because you're making it lower-case anyway. -3 bytes.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur the Python 3 answer already covered it and better (pretty sure my code would be the exact same), so I'm not in the mood to use it too. Guess I'm sticking to `import this`.

Comment: @ValueInk Alright then.

Comment: I don't like this approach.  Then also a simple `'pYTHON'.swapcase()` works.

Comment: @Alfe `'pYTHON'.swapcase()` does not output anything -- it's a snippet and will not print anything when run from a file. If you use the solution I'm using with an exec/eval/lower/swapcase combo, `print'python'` is longer than `import this` anyways. If you have any other ideas feel free to make your own solution -- after all there are at least two other Python solutions here that are shorter than mine.

Answer (score 13):

### Python 2, 2 bytes, 1 character

```
è
```

output...:

[image: output]

Comment: Are you sure this is only 1 byte?

Comment: Agreed. It's 2 bytes in UTF-8

Comment: The key is "non-ASCII" -- try `0xa0` (nbsp) or basically any other high byte you like and you'll get the same error!

Comment: This is 1 byte in Win1252, which the error message shows this is using.

Comment: This requires a file, and files need at least 1 byte of naming, which makes this 2 bytes

Answer (score 13):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/index.html), 229 bytes

```
why?w-h-y?always a war,many flaws,a sham,a fraud,a sad day
luxury a la shahs,a day a la Buddha?ah,many days usually always a burn
a husband hungry?uh-huh
awful suburbs,always a handful
sadly,a man runs harshly away
hardly unusual
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?NY7BDcQwCAT/roICkhosXSdroRwP4ocR8lF9DifKCy077DIl6txljwqdCCPQxNhO9KBDMW0DmeDMcQw4LwkmRhT1n4/IA70RWWjun8XHmQUV8kTxinZzqCbwNjUfvYDEraFzzv4dUV12cSmYhyuZJ9Qy@r2RJNMo@YVGNmY8De@WxjBZ6QmWFGmT97vzuhr4Dw)

Prints `Poetic`.

This was an interesting challenge. Not only did I have to write the shortest program that prints `Poetic`, but I challenged myself to create a somewhat coherent series of sentences without using `p`, `o`, `e`, `t`, `i`, or `c` (in keeping with the spirit of the language). That makes this program a "lipogram".

Answer (score 12):

## MATLAB, 3 bytes

```matlab
ver
```

Output is as follows. Irrelevant info has been replaced by `[...]`). Some parts of the output may change depending on version, installed toolboxes etc.

```matlab
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version: 8.6.0.267246 (R2015b)
MATLAB License Number: [...]
Operating System: [...]
Java Version: Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with [...]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB                                                Version 8.6         (R2015b)
Communications System Toolbox                         Version 6.1         (R2015b)
Curve Fitting Toolbox                                 Version 3.5.2       (R2015b)
[...]
Wavelet Toolbox                                       Version 4.15        (R2015b)
```

Comment: Uses a v and an e

Comment: Your language is `Octave`, so you can't use `v` and `e`.

Comment: Woops. Corrected by changing language to Matlab (which was my initial intent anyway)

Answer (score 11):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
"2,:o:2-o|
```

This will continually print ><> until the interpreter runs out of space.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@69kpGOVb2Wkm1/z/z8A)

12 byte version below for those who like a clean output. Recommended by Aaron (no error, 1 output)

```
":3+:o$1+oo;
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: @Emigna - Thanks, the final version was after a bunch of failed golfs but I quite like it because with the error it prints ><> and fish :D

Comment: Nice one ! Here's a 14 bytes version which only prints once and doesn't errors out : `"-o-o-o;_!\ _!`

Comment: @Aaron if you check the edit the first version did that at 12. I do like how clean yours looks though :)

Comment: I like your 12 bytes version (the 10 bytes too :)), I think you should have left it included to your answer as an aside ("for those who like a clean output,[...]") !

Comment: @Aaron - edited it back in as you're right, I'll keep it in mind for any futures golfs too :)

Answer (score 10):

## [C](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), 1 byte

```c
]
```

Output:

```c
.code.tio.c:1: error: declaration expected
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/z/2/38A)

Comment: What about empty? I get `tcc: error: main not defined`, which includes the letter c in it. Does that count?

Answer (score 9):

## JAVA, 1 byte

```
1
```

The output to stderr is:

```
Main.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
1
^
1 error
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Command exited with non-zero status 1
    Command being timed: "/srv/wrappers/java-openjdk"
    User time (seconds): 1.40
    System time (seconds): 0.80
    Percent of CPU this job got: 40%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:05.40
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 44564
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 205
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 11301
    Voluntary context switches: 2666
    Involuntary context switches: 1677
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 78312
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 1
```

Comment: This is output from compilation, rather than running the program. I don't know whether this is allowed by default.

Comment: Also, if you chose a different file extension, it wouldn’t output "java" would it? (Not sure if that’s possible with java)

Comment: if you change from java to java bytecode you could reduce by one character. trying to run empty class file will throw java.lang.ClassFormatError

Comment: Programs outputting to stderr should be edited into [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107992/34718).

Answer (score 8):

## CSS, 25 bytes

```css
:after{content:'\43\53\53
```

Note that extra markup is added to Stack Overflow snippets, causing "CSS" to be displayed more than once. Open an `.html` file with contents

```
<style>:after{content:'\43\53\53
```

to see the result as intended.

Answer (score 8):

## J, 2 bytes

```
   a.


┌┬┐├┼┤└┴┘│─ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

`a.` returns the alphabet of the J language — a built-in list of all bytes.

### My original: 4 bytes

```
   %:_1
0j1
```

This just seems pretty cool to me. The square root (`%:`) of negative 1 (`_1`) is *i* (`0j1`).

Comment: 2 Bytes: `a.`. Prints the alphabet, which obviously includes 'J'. Definetly not as cool though :/

Comment: Gotta golf it. :-) That said, I am attached to my original answer.

Answer (score 7):

## bash CLI, 9

```
printf $0
```

---

If you want an actual script and not just a command at the interactive command line, then you can do this:

## bash, 13

```
printf $SHELL
```

Outputs `/bin/bash`

Comment: `echo $0` should work

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That works at the shell command line, but in a script it will output the name of the script.

Comment: `echo $SHELL` isn't any better anyway. http://pastebin.com/BfsWjCni Regardless whether you run it from command line or script and whether you use shebang in that script or not.

Comment: `x $0` works, assuming there's no executable called x on the path. In which case substitute any other letter, digit, or non-special character.

Comment: 'h' is illigal character for you, and you are using it in echo

Comment: `$'ec\x68o' $0` cures that detail.

Comment: Doh. Better `printf $0`. (Glad I not posted any solution today.)

Comment: @manatwork Doh indeed.  `printf` it is then. :)

Comment: You could just use `print $0` .

Comment: @ckjbgames I'm not familiar with that one.  The `print` on my Ubuntu VM apparently does this "run-mailcap,  view,  see,  edit,  compose, print - execute programs via entries in the mailcap file".  Output is `Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/print line 528.
Error: no "print" mailcap rules found for type "inode/directory"`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Must be getting my languages confused...

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, [Piotr Grochowski](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/63913/piotr-grochowski) in his [Bash tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105772) also claims such `print` exists. At least on his Android.

Comment: `.$0` should also work

Comment: Any character which is not a command do work: 1-Byte solution: `x`. message: `bash: x: command not found`. Something like `/` will always work (there can not be a command called `/`)

Answer (score 7):

### BASIC (ZX Spectrum), <s>4</s> 2 bytes

*crossed out 4 is still regular 4*

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ShaunBebbers.

```
0õ
```

Note: In the ZX Spectrum character set, these bytes display as

```
0 PRINT
```

When you enter this in, the Spectrum starts by parsing an optional number followed by a line of code. Normally the line number is `1..9999` which causes the code to be added to the stored program. However if no line number is supplied then the code is executed immediately instead. Unfortunately a bug in the Spectrum means that it mistakes a line number of zero for no line number at all, but it still tries to execute the zero as part of the line of code, which is illegal, thus causing the error.

The previous 4-byte version generates a true error rather than relying on an interpreter bug:

```
õ°""
```

Note: In the ZX Spectrum character set, these bytes display as

```
PRINT VAL ""
```

which outputs

```
C Nonsense in BASIC, 0:1
```

because the empty string is not a valid numeric expression. (I could of course have used any statement that takes a single integer.) If this answer is unacceptable, then for 6 bytes you can write a program consisting of a single line with one of the keywords that accepts no arguments, then use `POKE` to replace it with an illegal keyword, then attempt to `RUN` the program.

Comment: or `0 REM` produces the same error

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Does that even pass syntax checking?

Comment: yes it does on a real Spectrum.

Answer (score 7):

## brainfuck, 105 Bytes

```
--[----->+<]>----.[--->+<]>----.+++[->+++<]>++.++++++++.+++++.--------.-[--->+<]>--.+[->+++<]>+.++++++++.
```

Try it online [here](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=LS1bLS0tLS0-KzxdPi0tLS0uWy0tLT4rPF0-LS0tLS4rKytbLT4rKys8XT4rKy4rKysrKysrKy4rKysrKy4tLS0tLS0tLS4tWy0tLT4rPF0-LS0uK1stPisrKzxdPisuKysrKysrKysu)

Comment: Well, not a problem in BrainFuck ;)

Comment: @devRicher not at all ;)

Comment: @mbomb007 I see.

Comment: @mbomb007 updated

Comment: Is there any reason for the excessive `---` in your markdown?

Comment: @FlipTack er, not particularly.

Answer (score 6):

## dc, 6

```
25699P
```

Outputs `dc`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@29kamZpGfD/PwA).

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>60</s> 67 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(){System.\u0043onsole.Write("\x43\x23");}}
```

Comment: Is this actually your answer, or did a bug messed up your answer?

Comment: @auhmaan Sorry, [fixed](https://tio.run/nexus/cs-mono#@5@ck1hcrBBQXVySWJKZrFCWn5mi4JuYmaehWR1cWVySmqsXU2pgYGKcn1ecn5OqF16UWZKqoRRTYWIcU2FkrKRpXVv7/z8A). I initially tested on LINQPad, and forgot it has a few default namespace imports.

Comment: I was referring to the `\u0043` and alikes

Comment: @auhmaan That's intentional because I need `Console` but can't use `C` as per question rules. In C# you can use Unicode escape sequences in identifiers.

Comment: I'm sure you can use an anonymous method for this, I can't see a restriction requiring a full program, so you could do `_=>System.\u0043onsole.Write("\x43\x23");`

Comment: '\x43' could be replaced with 'c'

Comment: @NPSF3000 Not really, it's officially written as `C#` with the capital `C`

Comment: @Metoniem read the rules "The output of the programming language name is not case sensitive."

Answer (score 6):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

```
'IWR C80
```

Takes the character `I` and `WR`aps it in `C`hr(`80`), resulting in `PIP`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@6/uGR6k4Gxh8P8/AA)

Using the `I` feels a bit like cheating, so here are [two 9-byte solutions](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@x/NpVDlYBEeVOVgaMqloFFloR1nbmCuyRX7//9/3RwA) that don't use any of `PpIi`:

```
z@8WRz@15
(z8+^707)
```

Both output `pip`. I'm particularly pleased with the second one:

```
    ^707   Split 707 into a list of characters        [7;0;7]
  8+       Add 8 to each one                          [15;8;15]
(z      )  Use list to index into lowercase alphabet  ["p";"i";"p"]
           By default, lists are printed without a separator
```

For proper capitalization, we need a [10-byte solution](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@6/uGR6k4GxhEFbBxWWt4JdfkmqlEAYTVCjOyC/NSVHISCxLVSjPL8pOTdFRSCotUUgEkukKBUWpZal5JakpCplAoRKFkoxUhZLM3FSF/DQwOzkjMScnNS89Ve//fwA):

```
'IWR C80Vx
```

How this one works is left as an exercise for the reader. ;^)

Answer (score 6):

## Forth, 5 bytes

```
WORDS
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@x/uH@QS/P8/AA)

Prints a list of every word in the language. `Forth` happens to be in the list (first word on line 125), though I don't know what it does.

Answer (score 6):

## Excel, 35

Closing parens already discounted.

Simple enough:

- `A1` - `=RIGHT(0=1)` - `E` from `FALSE`
- Output - `=A1&ROMAN(90)&A1&ROMAN(50)` - `EXCEL`

`ROMAN(90)` = `XC`, `ROMAN(50)` = `L`

Comment: Or is it 0 because of the splash screen when you start up Excel?

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 11 bytes

```r
cat("\x52")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@5@cWKKhFFNhaqSk@f8/AA)

Comment: `version$l` 9 bytes

Comment: Probably `version` is enough (7 bytes)

Comment: Or just 'r'. 3 bytes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You can't use... wait; the specs are case sensitive in checking but not output... Clever.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Yeah … but [I’ve since posted a solution that only needs one character](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108125/1710), and even gets the case right.

Comment: `LETTERS[18]` is also 11 :)

Comment: @Punintended that contains `R`, unfortunately.

Comment: @Giuseppe: Derp, you're right.  In that case, depending on how the OP defines "junk output", you could argue a case for `c`.  That outputs `function (...)  .Primitive("c")`, which contains the `r` character

Comment: @Punintended I'm sure that would be perfectly valid; Konrad Rudolph's answer is just `T`, which prints `[1] TRUE` of course. I also recently started an [R chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75004/golfr) in case you want to ever have a nice discussion about R golfing not in the comments section :)

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, 3 bytes

```
:h<CR>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@2@VwfX/PwA)

This opens up the default help file and outputs:

```
*help.txt*  For Vim version 7.4.  Last change: 2016 Mar 31

                        VIM - main help file
                                                                         k
      Move around:  Use the cursor keys, or "h" to go left,        h   l
                    "j" to go down, "k" to go up, "l" to go right.   j
Close this window:  Use ":q<Enter>".
   Get out of Vim:  Use ":qa!<Enter>" (careful, all changes are lost!).

Jump to a subject:  Position the cursor on a tag (e.g. |bars|) and hit CTRL-].
   With the mouse:  Double-click the left mouse button on a tag, e.g. |bars|.
        Jump back:  Type CTRL-T or CTRL-O.  Repeat to go further back.

Get specific help:  It is possible to go directly to whatever you want help
                    on, by giving an argument to the |:help| command.
                    Prepend something to specify the context:  *help-context*

                          WHAT          PREPEND    EXAMPLE  ~
                      Normal mode command          :help x
                      Visual mode command     v_       :help v_u
                      Insert mode command     i_       :help i_<Esc>
                      Command-line command    :    :help :quit
                      Command-line editing    c_       :help c_<Del>
                      Vim command argument    -    :help -r
                      Option              '    :help 'textwidth'
                      Regular expression      /    :help /[
                    See |help-summary| for more contexts and an explanation.

  Search for help:  Type ":help word", then hit CTRL-D to see matching
                    help entries for "word".
                    Or use ":helpgrep word". |:helpgrep|

VIM stands for Vi IMproved.  Most of VIM was made by Bram Moolenaar, but only
through the help of many others.  See |credits|.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                *doc-file-list* *Q_ct*
BASIC:
|quickref|  Overview of the most common commands you will use
|tutor|     30 minutes training course for beginners
|copying|   About copyrights
|iccf|      Helping poor children in Uganda
|sponsor|   Sponsor Vim development, become a registered Vim user
|www|       Vim on the World Wide Web
|bugs|      Where to send bug reports

USER MANUAL: These files explain how to accomplish an editing task.

|usr_toc.txt|   Table Of Contents

Getting Started ~
|usr_01.txt|  About the manuals
|usr_02.txt|  The first steps in Vim
|usr_03.txt|  Moving around
|usr_04.txt|  Making small changes
|usr_05.txt|  Set your settings
|usr_06.txt|  Using syntax highlighting
|usr_07.txt|  Editing more than one file
|usr_08.txt|  Splitting windows
|usr_09.txt|  Using the GUI
|usr_10.txt|  Making big changes
|usr_11.txt|  Recovering from a crash
|usr_12.txt|  Clever tricks

Editing Effectively ~
|usr_20.txt|  Typing command-line commands quickly
|usr_21.txt|  Go away and come back
|usr_22.txt|  Finding the file to edit
|usr_23.txt|  Editing other files
|usr_24.txt|  Inserting quickly
|usr_25.txt|  Editing formatted text
|usr_26.txt|  Repeating
|usr_27.txt|  Search commands and patterns
|usr_28.txt|  Folding
|usr_29.txt|  Moving through programs
|usr_30.txt|  Editing programs
|usr_31.txt|  Exploiting the GUI
|usr_32.txt|  The undo tree

Tuning Vim ~
|usr_40.txt|  Make new commands
|usr_41.txt|  Write a Vim script
|usr_42.txt|  Add new menus
|usr_43.txt|  Using filetypes
|usr_44.txt|  Your own syntax highlighted
|usr_45.txt|  Select your language


REFERENCE MANUAL: These files explain every detail of Vim.  *reference_toc*

General subjects ~
|intro.txt| general introduction to Vim; notation used in help files
|help.txt|  overview and quick reference (this file)
|helphelp.txt|  about using the help files
|index.txt| alphabetical index of all commands
|help-tags| all the tags you can jump to (index of tags)
|howto.txt| how to do the most common editing tasks
|tips.txt|  various tips on using Vim
|message.txt|   (error) messages and explanations
|quotes.txt|    remarks from users of Vim
|develop.txt|   development of Vim
|debug.txt| debugging Vim itself
|uganda.txt|    Vim distribution conditions and what to do with your money

Basic editing ~
|starting.txt|  starting Vim, Vim command arguments, initialisation
|editing.txt|   editing and writing files
|motion.txt|    commands for moving around
|scroll.txt|    scrolling the text in the window
|insert.txt|    Insert and Replace mode
|change.txt|    deleting and replacing text
|indent.txt|    automatic indenting for C and other languages
|undo.txt|  Undo and Redo
|repeat.txt|    repeating commands, Vim scripts and debugging
|visual.txt|    using the Visual mode (selecting a text area)
|various.txt|   various remaining commands
|recover.txt|   recovering from a crash

Advanced editing ~
|cmdline.txt|   Command-line editing
|options.txt|   description of all options
|pattern.txt|   regexp patterns and search commands
|map.txt|   key mapping and abbreviations
|tagsrch.txt|   tags and special searches
|quickfix.txt|  commands for a quick edit-compile-fix cycle
|windows.txt|   commands for using multiple windows and buffers
|tabpage.txt|   commands for using multiple tab pages
|syntax.txt|    syntax highlighting
|spell.txt| spell checking
|diff.txt|  working with two to four versions of the same file
|autocmd.txt|   automatically executing commands on an event
|filetype.txt|  settings done specifically for a type of file
|eval.txt|  expression evaluation, conditional commands
|fold.txt|  hide (fold) ranges of lines

Special issues ~
|print.txt| printing
|remote.txt|    using Vim as a server or client
|term.txt|  using different terminals and mice
|digraph.txt|   list of available digraphs
|mbyte.txt| multi-byte text support
|mlang.txt| non-English language support
|arabic.txt|    Arabic language support and editing
|farsi.txt| Farsi (Persian) editing
|hebrew.txt|    Hebrew language support and editing
|russian.txt|   Russian language support and editing
|ft_ada.txt|    Ada (the programming language) support
|ft_sql.txt|    about the SQL filetype plugin
|rileft.txt|    right-to-left editing mode

GUI ~
|gui.txt|   Graphical User Interface (GUI)
|gui_w32.txt|   Win32 GUI

Interfaces ~
|if_cscop.txt|  using Cscope with Vim
|if_pyth.txt|   Python interface
|if_ruby.txt|   Ruby interface
|debugger.txt|  Interface with a debugger
|sign.txt|  debugging signs

Versions ~
|vim_diff.txt|  Main differences between Nvim and Vim
|vi_diff.txt|   Main differences between Vim and Vi
                                                *sys-file-list*
Remarks about specific systems ~
|os_win32.txt|  MS-Windows
                                                *standard-plugin-list*
Standard plugins ~
|pi_gzip.txt|      Reading and writing compressed files
|pi_netrw.txt|     Reading and writing files over a network
|pi_paren.txt|     Highlight matching parens
|pi_tar.txt|       Tar file explorer
|pi_vimball.txt|   Create a self-installing Vim script
|pi_zip.txt|       Zip archive explorer

LOCAL ADDITIONS:                *local-additions*

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*bars*      Bars example

Now that you've jumped here with CTRL-] or a double mouse click, you can use
CTRL-T, CTRL-O, g<RightMouse>, or <C-RightMouse> to go back to where you were.

Note that tags are within | characters, but when highlighting is enabled these
characters are hidden.  That makes it easier to read a command.

Anyway, you can use CTRL-] on any word, also when it is not within |, and Vim
will try to find help for it.  Especially for options in single quotes, e.g.
'hlsearch'.

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 vim:tw=78:fo=tcq2:isk=!-~,^*,^\|,^\":ts=8:ft=help:norl:
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 19 bytes

Basically a direct linear flow wrapped inside the hexagon.

```
h;E;N;Y;X;A;;@/OG;/
```

[Try this 19 byte un-interesting solution online!](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#@59h7WrtZx1pHWHtaG3toO/vbq3//z8A)

More interesting 28 bytes:

```
I]f.@]z;.(;[.$>]z(]b]\(]p]h<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/hexagony#@@8Zm6bnEFtlradhHa2nYhdbpRGbFBujEVsQm2HDpaDw/z8A)

This uses the small `h`, which is allowed.  Uses the IP1 (Initial is 0) as a "function" which does "Decrement and print as char".

#### Expanded view

```
   I ] f .
  @ ] z ; .
 ( ; [ . $ >
] z ( ] b ] \
 ( ] p ] h <
  . . . . .
   . . . .
```

Saves `I` in the memory, go to the next instruction pointer with `]`, then IP1 runs from NE corner in SE direction and hits `..>` which directs to E, wrapped to the bottom 5 no-ops `.` and then to `(` (decrement), `;` (print as char) and then `[` which returns to IP0.

IP0 starts reading from where it stopped to `f`, go through the no-op `.` and to the middle `]` which runs the "function" again: IP1 starts from where it stopped and hits no-op `.` then `$` which skips the `>` and runs through the bottom again... to print `e`.

The program keeps doing things like that.  Found out that I could've just printed `n` by calling the function again after printing `o`.  Mm.. can't think of ways to shorten this further though I replace 1 byte by no-op with this discovery.

Leave me a comment if you want to see diagrams in this explanation!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 0 bytes

An amazing trick that I just learned from Kevin Cruijssen.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/Q8EAA)

It outputs contents of info.txt, which of course contains the name `05AB1E`.

Answer (score 4):

### R, 10 bytes

```
citation()
```

Outputs :

> To cite R in publications use:
>
> R Core Team (2016). R: A language and environment for statistical computing. R Foundation for
>     Statistical Computing, Vienna, Austria. URL https://www.R-project.org/.
>
> A BibTeX entry for LaTeX users is
>
> @Manual{,
>       title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
>       author = {{R Core Team}},
>       organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
>       address = {Vienna, Austria},
>       year = {2016},
>       url = {https://www.R-project.org/},
>     }
>
> We have invested a lot of time and effort in creating R, please cite it when using it for data
>   analysis. See also ‘citation("pkgname")’ for citing R packages.

Quite verbose just to have `R`'s name to appear right ?

From @djhurio's comment on an this [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107964/output-programming-language-name/107983#107983) using R, `version` does the trick too.

Comment: *"The output of the programming language name is not case sensitive."* So why not just `"r"`? Or depending on strict *"You can have "junk output" before or after the name of the language."* you could also just do `T`.

Comment: Following on @Billywob 's comment, all that is needed to output is an `r` or `R`, so another approach is to output to STDERR via a syntax error. `)` outputs `Error: unexpected ')' in ")"`, which contains an `r`.

Comment: @Billywob I agree to your comment, as well as rturnbull's. I wrote this answer quickly earlier and should have precised that, even though it makes the code and the answer futilely long, I find it funny to output all this junk just to make "R" appears. Moreover, it's the shortest way to my knowledge to write make R write its name on purpose.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 5, 36 bytes (35 + 1 for `-E`)

```
$^X=~s/.+(.)(...)$/\U$1\E$2/;say$^X
```

Run with the `-E` flag.

```
$ perl -E 'say$^X=~s/.+(.)(...)$/\U$1\E$2/r'
Perl
```

The [variable `$^X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24EXECUTABLE_NAME) is the path to the executable that is running the current program. Since the Perl interpreter is called `perl`, we then need to make he first letter upper-case. But the `ucfirst` function contains an `r`, which is not allowed, so we have to resort to `\U` and `\E`, which turn upper-case-conversion on and off.

We cannot use the `/r` modifier for `s///` to return the changed string because the `r` is not allowed.

It's important to know that [the name of the Perl programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Name) is *Perl*, and the name of the interpreter is *perl* with a lower-case `p`. There is no *PERL*.

Comment: Technically, I think `perl -v` satisfies the constraints of the challenge, but this is much more interesting :) Although it makes assumptions that don't hold on all systems (e.g. `$^X` is `/home/foo/.plenv/versions/5.16.3/bin/perl5.16.3` for me, but it could just as well be `/home/foo/python` if I were twisted like that).

Comment: @this not sure if that would be within the rules. They say pick a language and do stuff. But `perl -v` is not anything in Perl. So I think it doesn't count. But I do think there are easier ways. About the different systems, I think we can fix it with a bit more regex magic.

Comment: There are a bunch of zero-byte solutions already that rely on default behavior (e.g. printing of version numbers). Nothing in the rules explicitly prohibits it. But it's definitely boring and feels "cheaty."

Comment: Looking at the rules again, you could actually just do the uber boring `perl -E'say$^X'`.

Comment: @this indeed. I thought it's case sensitive. I obviously had that first, but it's boring.

Comment: I managed it in [22 bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108507/2771) :)

Comment: How about `-E'say\`$^X -v\`'` ? That's indisputably a program.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 2 bytes

The `perl` is the call to the interpreter from command line:

```
$ perl -M6
```

Outputs (for my version of Perl):

```
Perl v6.0.0 required--this is only v5.16.3, stopped at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
```

---

### Perl, 17 bytes

```
80.101.114.108->_
```

Outputs

```
Can't locate object method "_" via package "Perl" (perhaps you forgot to load "Perl"?) at -e line 1.
```

Can be shortened to **14 bytes** if `PERL` is acceptable:

```
80.69.82.76->_
```

---

All solutions make use of [version strings](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Version-Strings).

Comment: That's awesome.

Comment: I believe this updated 2-byte solution should qualify

Comment: This must be the shortest answer in Perl ever!

Comment: @simbabque I'm trying to figure a way to get `perl -x` to spit out ["No Perl script found in input"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html)

Comment: `perl -x .` says _Can't open perl script ".": Is a directory_. But that's not a program.

Comment: @Zaid `perl -x -e1`

Comment: (Although if you use that, you may want to add it to [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107992/31388), since it's not clear whether outputting to stderr is allowed.)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot all of my solutions in their present form are abusing `STDERR`. If that isn't allowed, the 18 byte solution is the best I can do with version strings: `say+80.101.14.108`

Comment: That one is pretty ingenious in itself.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 23 bytes (without Error)

This works on little-endian machine.
`67` is `0x00000043` and the layout on memory is `{0x43,0x00,0x00,0x00}` (32bit, little-endian) . This memory block is a valid c string (zero-ending char array). Then, just pass the pointer of this memory block into `puts`.

```c
main(i){i=67;puts(&i);}
```

As the restrictions:

- `putchar` is not allowed (contains c). Then `puts` is used.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

Flagless and without dictionary compression.

```
kaṖṅ
```

This prints out all the possible permutations of the lowercase alphabet.
In the online interpreter the code times out (for understandable reasons). Does it count?
[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrYeG5lmbhuYUiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Comment: Nice loophole lol

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
exec"pri\156\164'pYTHON'"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59akZqsVFCUGWNoahZjaGaiXhAZ4uHvp670/z8A)

Prints `pYTHON`. Uses octal codes for the banned characters `n` and `t`.

If functions are allowed, we can just do:

```python
lambda:"pYTHON"
```

Comment: Very nice! Of course, I have bias towards my `import this` solution for the creativity factor, but you can take the shorter answer :P

Comment: @RaisingAgent Rule 4 says `The output of the programming language name is not case sensitive.`

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, 13 bytes

```
<?=phpinfo();
```

Returns a lot of information, including a line such as:

```
PHP Version => 7.0.10
```

#### Command line version, 6 bytes:

```
php -v
```

Returns something along those lines:

```
PHP 7.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2016 09:48:53) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

*Thanks to Martinj for suggesting this one.*

Comment: Commandline php would be `php -v`, which is 6 :)

Comment: @Martijn You're right. Thanks! Because we need `php` anyway, I wonder if it's not just 2 bytes for the `-v` flag...

Comment: You could skip the opening `<?=` and just print `php`, which in a webserver context would end up being rendered inside `<body>` in your browser; 3 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## C <s>24</s> 20 Bytes (Clang 3.8.1)

Thanks to @squeamish ossifrage for helping me save 4 bytes.

```
main(){putchar(67);}
```

Comment: How about `putchar(67);`?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage yep, thanks

Comment: Just curious, but wouldn't `printf('c')` also be valid? You're not allowed to use uppercase "C", but you are lowercase, and the result is case-insensitive.

Comment: Sure sounds like it would, @jocie, but `67` is shorter than `'c'` :-)

Comment: and `printf` is shorter than `putchar` :-)

Comment: @Jocie `printf` needs a `char *` so I need to use `""`

Comment: if result is not case sensitive, then puts("c") saves a few bytes, and does not use uppercase C... Rules might need an edit then

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
“Ẏṃ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc7DXX0PdzYf2v3/PwA)

Jelly supports a dictionary-compressed string representation which is based off an English dictionary; every word in English (according to the dictionary) has a short compressed representation. Luckily, `jelly` is an English word, so it's in the dictionary. `Ẏṃ` is the compressed representation when the word's just by itself like this (although the representation is based on base conversion so the actual characters used depends on what other words appear in the compressed string), and `“…»` are the necessary delimiters to treat it as a string literal and decompress it.

Comment: Nitpick, but this outputs 'jelly' without a capital J.

Comment: @steenbergh `The output of the programming language name is not case sensitive.`

Comment: @Mego Huh, my bad. Could've sworn that it was...

Comment: @steenbergh: this technique works to output a capital J just as well, but it's a byte longer. Because the question allows case-insensitive output, I had to exploit that to bring the byte count down.

Answer (score 3):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```
76.65.66.89.82.73.78.84.72.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/labyrinth#@29upmdprmdpoWdoaGJlqqdnaAAklQ2tDPTM9Ez0HP7/BwA)

Prints `LABYRINTH`.

Answer (score 3):

### Groovy, 1 byte

```
a
```

In fact, `a` can be replaced by any character except the ones in `Groovy`. This raises a `MissingPropertyException` and outputs the following to `STDERR-`

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a ...
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, 1 byte

```
v
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=v)

Outputs file path to stderr. Only guaranteed to work on online interpreter.

#### 2 bytes

```
~f
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%7Ef)

Outputs every permutation of alphabetical characters

Comment: The online interpreter times out before reaching `pyke` (on the second solution) :(

Comment: @devRicher I'd be surprised if it didn't. That would use far too much memory in my browser to even display that many permutations (think about 450000 lines of output)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 1 byte

```
e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@5/6/z8A)

Outputs to `STDERR`:

```
ERROR: Prolog initialisation failed:
ERROR: brachylog_main/3: Undefined procedure: default/0
```

The reason being that `e`, as of this version of Brachylog, is not implemented and is thus linked to no predicate name in the source code. This causes an ill-defined transpiling behavior which causes the main predicate (called `brachylog_main`) to contain incorrect Prolog code.

Comment: @mbomb007 Completely forgot about that, fixed. `e` does the exact same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 0 bytes

Starting `Vim` from the command line with no arguments yields:

```
~                                        VIM - Vi IMproved
~
~                                          version 8.0.92
~                                     by Bram Moolenaar et al.
~                           Vim is open source and freely distributable
~
~                                  Help poor children in Uganda!
~                          type  :help iccf<Enter>       for information
~
~                          type  :q<Enter>               to exit
~                          type  :help<Enter>  or  <F1>  for on-line help
~                          type  :help version8<Enter>   for version info
~
~
~
~
~
~
```

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge, 0, 1 or 19 bytes

Assuming the program doesn't need to terminate, then you can use a 0 byte file as the source, and the reference interpreter will by default will output its version header before going into an infinite loop:

```
Befunge-93 Interpreter/Debugger v2.23
```

If the program does need to terminate, then a singe byte exit command will suffice.

```
@
```

If the version header doesn't count as valid output, here's a more interesting 19 byte solution:

```
"kmt{lkH">0#,-:#6_@
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=ImttdHtsa0giPjAjLC06IzZfQA&input=)

The string "Befunge" has just been offset by 6 bytes to avoid using any of the characters in the name.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP (2 Byte)

```
a;
```

Run it on the console, no opening tag required. `a` isn't defined and the semicolon closes the statement and because it's not in a block, it gets evaluated immediately.

This will cause the following warning to be printed:

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a' in php shell
>   code on line 1

As you can see, it starts off with the name of the programming language.

I won't go for the really cheap way of saying that the name of the programming language is displayed on the shell, though. On the shell, it reads "php" (lowercase) and PHP is commonly written both ways. In fact, the title of http://php.net is written in all-caps, whereas the logo only contains lowercase letters. The only thing that's for sure in this regard is that people who write it as "Php", are just wrong.

Answer (score 3):

## COMMODORE 64 BASIC, 11 bytes

```
1sY830*78-2
```

To get around the case-sensitive "can't use the characters of the languages's name" restriction, put the computer in "shifted mode" so you can enter the "s" in lower-case.  This code performs a soft reset of the computer, taking it out of shifted mode (so the name is printed in upper-case) and printing out the name.  The output printed:

```
    **** COMMODORE 64 BASIC V2 ****

 64 K RAM SYSTEM  38911 BASIC BYTES FREE

READY.
```

Comment: You don't require the line number here as you can execute any `sys` call in direct mode.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers, the line number is what makes it a program rather than an immediate command.

Comment: Yes you are right; If it specifically says you need it in a program or as an executable in the rules then you require the line number; if not, you have saved one `PETSCII` character on your submission.

Answer (score 3):

## [UPL](https://github.com/declued/upl), 0 bytes

I tried to be funny by finding an unnamed programming language where an empty file produces no output, instead I found this. Trying to compile anything with the Unnamed Programming Language compiler results in:

```
This is going to be the UPL compiler...
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 94 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYtJCgAgDAPPzSvyNRFBb4KCz6/a5ZJMBnL62G3NUpsqSZAikb8oj6xdM9hdTrgjkMaOkM/mAKhe)

```
ssslssttslssttsslssststtlssstttslssslsssttttlssstsslsssttlssttttsl
                push [0, -2, -4, 11, 14, 0, 15, 4, 3, -14]
lssl            label print
sssttsststl     push 101
tsss            add
tlss            print char
lsll            jmp print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 5 bytes

```c
main;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTPP@v9/AA)

- Output "type defaults to ‘int’ in de**c**laration of ‘main’" to stderr while compile.
- Output "Segmentation fault (**c**ore dumped)" to stderr while execute.

-2 bytes, thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 17 bytes

With this magic trick, I will turn apples into bacon!

```
1⊸+⌾(¯1⊸⊏)1+"APL"
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=MeKKuCvijL4owq8x4oq44oqPKTErIkFQTCI=)

### Explanation

```
1⊸+⌾(¯1⊸⊏)1+"APL"
             "APL"   - Take each letter of "APL"
           1+        - Add one to it, giving the next letter.
   ⌾(¯1⊸⊏)          - Then take the last letter of "BQM"
1⊸+                  - And add one to it.
```

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 7 bytes

And now for the golfy answer.

```
"APM"+1
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=IkFQTSIrMQ==)

### Explanation

```
"APM"+1
"APM"    - Take each letter of "APM"
     +1  - ...and add one to it, giving the next letter.
```

Comment: useful userscript for submissions: https://github.com/razetime/userscripts/blob/main/bqncgcc.user.js

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 (15 Bytes)

```py
exec"\x68elp()"
```

## Python 3 (17 Bytes)

```py
exec('\x68elp()')
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>41</strike> <strike>39</strike> 33 bytes

*- 2 bytes thanks to [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)

- 6 bytes thanks to [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/wheat-wizard)*

```python
exec"p"+'RINT"pYTHON"'.swapcase()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7UiNVmpQElbPcjTL0SpIDLEw99PSV2vuDyxIDmxOFVD8/9/AA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Unfortunately this isn't quite valid as it contains a lowercase `o` and `n`. You  can get around this using [hexadecimal escapes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7UiNVmpoCgzpsIsNabC3ERJW12pIDLEw99PSV2vuDyxIDmxOFVD8/9/AA), and it saves two bytes.

Comment: @emanresuA thanks (btw I'm a sock lol)

Comment: *how* did I not see the anagram

Comment: Why use escape codes when you can just [use uppercase letters](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7UiNVmpQElbPcjTL0SpIDLEw99PSV2vuDyxIDmxOFVD8/9/AA "Python 2 – Try It Online")?

Comment: @WheatWizard oh, wait

Answer (score 2):

## RProgN, 19 Bytes.

```
~(70811.911.)71.+c.
```

Nice and easy! This was the first time (I think) I've gotten to use Stack Constructors in a challenge!

### Explanation

```
~(70811.911.)71.+c.
~                   # Start a Zero Space Segment
 (          )       # Push a Stack
  7                 # Literal Numbers, the . concatenates two digits to form a single number.
   0                #
    8               #
     11.            #
        9           #
         11.        #
             71.+   # Add 71 to every value in the stack.
                 c. # Convert to their char values. Although this stack is configured 'backwards', when . is called, the stack concatenation works backwards. That's just how RProgN does it.
                    # Print is implicit.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn#@1@nYW5gYWioZwnEmuaGetrJev//AwA)

### Boring Cheaty Way

```
`rpROGn
```

Because the text output isn't case sensitive but the characters is...

Comment: The Boring Cheaty Way isn't allowed because you're using `R` and `r`.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 15 bytes

```
exec"\150elp()"
```

Takes part of my Python 3 answer and @xnor answer to make this

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
qz
```

Results in the following error message

```
 -- LAMBDA = qz (A, B)
 -- LAMBDA = qz (A, B, OPT)

Additional help for built-in functions and operators is
available in the online version of the manual.  Use the command
'doc <topic>' to search the manual index.

Help and information about Octave is also available on the WWW
at http://www.octave.org and via the help@octave.org
mailing list.
```

Answer (score 2):

## GNU CLISP (2.49+, on Cygwin) (5 or 6 bytes)

`'clisp` (6 bytes)

Outputs:

`CLISP`

(answer based on quote usage in https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89234/59547 )

If you reduce it to

`clisp` (5 bytes)

you can get the error

```
*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable CLISP has no value....
```

Answer (score 2):

### Bash, 9 bytes

```
--verSion
```

Will output the following:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

which has the word [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) in it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I only see the word `bash` in the command itself and not the output.  I don't think that counts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is valid if you call it a REPL answer. When I run `x` from the REPL, I get the following output: `DJ@DJ-PC:~$ x;
bash: x: command not found;
DJ@DJ-PC:~$;` (Note that the semicolons are newlines) (Also note that I tested it on git-bash)

Comment: changed it completely now, the new version is reproducible

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 8 bytes

```
f4*:2+oo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@59momVlpJ2f//8/AA)

Prints the string `><` repeatedly.

Answer (score 2):

### [FerNANDo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/FerNANDo), 79 bytes

```
3 3
1
2 2
0 3 0 0 0 2 2 1
0 3 2 0 1 3 1 2
0 3 2 2 0 1 2 0
0 3 1 0 3 3 3 1
1 1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fernando#LYnRDQBADEH/TWGEo/vP1tOmEeTRxYJgGo/FtwpRyw4prft9S3JZnBwJGnd/)

Based on [primo's technique for "Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58280/8478). The idea is to loop twice through four printing commands, while using the variables `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` for all possible combinations of the values `0`/`1`:

```
variable                0  1  2  3
value on 1st iteration  0  0  1  1
value on 2nd iteration  0  1  0  1
```

With these, we can then encode arbitrary pairs of characters to be printed, which allows us to print four characters in each iteration. I used [this CJam script](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6/kllrk5@jnkq9UnWmUZBGSGl2raqJfVV1llJYUrOVXq/r/PwA) to compute the printing commands (change the `4` to a different value if you want to print a different number of characters per iteration).

I also tried doing 3 iterations, like primo's answer (which would require printing a trailing linefeed), but that ends up being a few bytes longer. It might be possible to save bytes by using 4 iterations, since you need only a few of the possible byte combinations (`0 2 4 7 9 12 15`, specifically), but I need to take more time to figure out how to compute them efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 2 bytes (0 bytes of code plus 2 bytes for extra command line arguments)

```
-i
```

Outputs a ton of stuff, including:

```
PHP Version => 7.1.1
PHP API => 20160303
PHP Extension => 20160303
PHP Extension Build => API20160303,NTS
PHP License
```

Comment: `-i` doesn't run a program. Not sure if this is valid

Comment: <shrug> If actually running a program is a requirement then all the answers which rely on a compile error are not valid as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (+ coreutils), <s>8</s> 3 bytes

```bash
env
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@aV/b////yxCIA)

Output is

```bash
  .
  .
  .
SHELL=/bin/bash
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Note that on Unix this is your login shell, not the running shell. So `bash` may not be listed.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5.10+, 18 bytes

```
$ perl -E'/.\KIO/~~%::;say$`'
Perl
```

Requires Perl 5.10 or higher for `say`, [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f%3c%3dpattern)-%5cK), and the [smartmatch operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) `~~`.

Per [this meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/274/31388), I'm not counting `-E`, although there are [dissenting opinions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7539/31388).

## How it works

The main symbol table `%main::` (or `%::` for short) always contains an entry for [PerlIO](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html):

```
$ perl -E'say $main::{"PerlIO::"}'
*main::PerlIO::
```

A symbol table is just a hash; you can search for keys that match a given regex using smartmatch:

```
$ perl -E'say "match" if /.\KIO/ ~~ %main::'
match
```

(There's also an entry for `IO::`, but it doesn't match this regex.)

`\K` causes the regex engine to "keep" everything matched up to that point and not add it to `$&`, so you end up with the text "IO" in `$&` and "Perl" in `` $` ``.

---

On newer versions of Perl, smartmatch will trigger a warning, but the output is still valid:

```
$ perl -E'/.\KIO/~~%::;say$`'
Smartmatch is experimental at -e line 1.
Perl
```

## Shorter solution for Perl < 5.18

Perl 5.18.0 introduced [hash randomization](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5180delta.html#Hash-randomization). Before that, functions like `keys` always returned hash keys and values in the same order from run to run.

On my installation of Perl 5.16.3 on Linux, the entry for `PerlIO::` always appears before the entry for `IO::`, so I can shave off three bytes from the regex:

```
$ perl5.16.3 -E'/IO/~~%::;say$`'
Perl
```

I suspect this will work for other installations < 5.18 (I've only checked 5.16.3 and 5.8.8).

Comment: `say%::` is good enough to meet the specs :)

Comment: @Zaid I see you were reading my comments on simbabque's answer :) But what a stupid rule that is...filtering out extra output makes the challenge much more fun.

Answer (score 2):

## [Juggle](https://github.com/Zavada42/Juggle), 34 bytes

Golfed:
`3<5=a5<1|a"5<2|1|a"a|7""6<1|a"a|5"`

Ungolfed:

```
3<5=a
5<1|a"
5<2|1|a"
a|7""
6<1|a"
a|5"
```

Explanation:

Juggle is always read left to right and will never back track. The only arithmetic available is bitwise operations, so I create a base of `3` left-shifted by `5` digits, resulting in a base value of `96`. Juggle is also limited to integer literals of 0-9. The rest of it is just pretty much bit math with `a` as a base, since all the characters start with `11` in the most significant digits. The `"` outputs that integer as a character with no new line.

[image: Proof of the output, Juggle's on the linked Github.]

Answer (score 2):

## Forth (gforth), 4 bytes

```
COLD
```

This word prints the following text (version number may vary):

```
Gforth 0.7.3, Copyright (C) 1995-2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Gforth comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `license'
Type `bye' to exit
```

Answer (score 2):

## [chicken](http://torso.me/chicken) (not scheme), 1 byte

The language name might also be chicken chicken, see [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5969959)

```
a
```

outputs:

```
Error on line 1: expected 'chicken'
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain. This seems perfectly valid to me

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL - 58 Bytes

```
print left(char(84)+char(45)+substring(@@version,11,3),5)
```

Making use of the casing difference on the highlighted chars.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
exec('pRINt'.upper().swapcase()+' "pYTHON"')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59akZqsoV4Q5OlXoq5XWlCQWqShqVdcnliQnFicqqGpra6gVBAZ4uHvp6Su@f8/AA)

It works by taking a weirdly capitalized string and making it normal, then executing it. I originally solved this by using this method to import `sys`, but then I realized I could just use it with `print`.

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P7UiNVm9IMjTL0SpIDLEw99PSV2vtKAgtUhDU6@4PLEgObE4VUPz/38A "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Ly, 10 bytes

```
(76)(89)&o
```

Pretty easy with Ly, due to the short name and little use of letters.

Outputs:

```
LY
```

[Try it online!](http://lylang.herokuapp.com/?program=(76)(89)%26o)

Comment: I thought the `y` was lower case so I cam up with `'&2*o'z1-o` which is the same length (so no improvement on your answer).  In fact I found lots (and lots) of different ways to generate the codepoint for `L` and `y` in 4 characters, leading to lots of 10 character options. :)

Comment: This one is fun IMO since it uses two different approaches and it's 8 chars :)  `76Jo'z,o`

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 28 bytes

```
show("\x6A\x75\x6C\x69\x61")
```

As it turned out, the hardest part wasn't encoding the string (easy enough with escapes and an ASCII table), but finding a function in the standard library to show it. Most of them have one of the letters of ['a', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'u'] in them.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 9 bytes

```
"-o_!\ _!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0k3P14xRiFe8f9/AA)

Same byte count, much cleaner output. Now it *only* outputs `><>` and nothing else by subtracting the difference between pairs of no-ops. I was very lucky that `>` + `!` is `_` which is a no-op when traveling horizontally.

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 9 bytes

```
"2*4-o! !
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X8lIy0Q3X1FB8f9/AA)

#### How It Works:

Initially the `"` pushes the source code in reverse. `2*4-o` multiplies the value of the final `!` by 2 and subtracts 4 to make it correspond to `>`. The `!` skips over the `"` so no more code is pushed to the stack, and it repeats the operation over the rest of the source code, resulting in an output of `` ><>ÚVdP` ``

Answer (score 2):

## Unix shells (bash, sh, zsh, etc) to STDERR, 1 byte

The shells `bash`, `ksh`, `sh`, `zsh` all output their name to STDERR when you give them an unknown command, e.g.

```
1
```

Examples:

```
λ bash<<<1
bash: line 1: 1: command not found

λ zsh<<<1
zsh: command not found: 1

λ ksh<<<1
ksh: line 1: 1: not found

λ sh<<<1
sh: line 1: 1: command not found

λ fish<<<1
fish: Unknown command 1
```

If the challenge requires output to STDOUT, add 5 bytes `2>&1` to redirect it:

```
λ bash<<<1 2>&1
bash: line 1: 1: command not found
```

If the challenge had specified "use a valid program"... **zsh, 18 bytes**

```zsh
<<<$'\x7a\x73\x68'
```

- *[try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGRT2mwjwRiI1jKsws1P//BwA)*
- *not like this! <s>`echo "\x7a\x73\x68"`</s>, as Gamma pointed out*

Comment: NB: `csh` and `tcsh` don't do this STDERR trick..

Comment: You can't use echo, "h" is in zsh. `<<<$'\x7a\x73\x68'` works for -1 byte though.

Comment: The challenge popped up again on active, so hi again. zsh and bash can use `$'\x73'et` for stdout.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 10 bytes

```
ÿ∙╤Æⁿ½]$╦y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9tYXRoZ29sZv//w7/iiJnilaTDhuKBv8K9XSTilaZ5//8)

### Explanation

```
ÿ∙╤Æⁿ        Push "∙╤Æⁿ"
     ½       uninterleave, pushing "∙Æ" and "╤ⁿ" to the stack
      ]      wrap stack in array
       $     push ord(a) for each element in the array
        ╦    fetch dictionary words ("Math" and "Golf")
         y   join array without separator to string or number
```

With dictionary popping using strings, which should be coming in the next version, this will be 1 byte shorter (remove `$`).

### The boring solution (1 byte)

```
'
```

From TIO:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mathgolf/math_golf.py", line 750, in <module>
    result = evaluate(code_list[:], stdin, Stack([]))
  File "/opt/mathgolf/math_golf.py", line 115, in evaluate
    stack.append(code.pop().char)
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

This is implementation dependent, but if you're planning on using MathGolf, you'll probably pull the git repository, which is named `mathgolf`, meaning that unless the directory is renamed, the error will persist.

Comment: More boring [10 bytes alternative](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///w7kcdMw@3qTyaugzInLrkUeN@EPv/fwA) (using MathGolf's strength of implicitly joining and printing the stack) which would be 2 bytes shorter once we can remove the `$`s. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Haha, of course... didn't even think to test the simpler method. Nice catch. I still have to check how dictionary fetching using strings should work when mapped to lists, but once I have verified that there should be a new version coming to TIO.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•₄)í•hÁ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOiR00tmofXAhkZhxv//wcA)

**Explanation:**

```python
•₄)í•    # Push compressed integer 5943776
     h   # Convert it to hexadecimal: "5AB1E0"
      Á  # Rotate it once towards the right: "05AB1E"
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•₄)í•` is `5943776`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 0 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8//DwIA)

**Output**: package main: 
code.**go**:1:1: expected 'package', found 'EOF'

Answer (score 2):

## Linux, Unix Shell (sh/bash...) (6 bytes)

```
find /
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 5 Bytes

```
"pYTH
```

Simple prints the string `pYTH` to stdout.

Comment: This is 5 bytes, `"` `p` `Y` `T` `H`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), (See below)

### Depends on invokation

#### [pxemi.7z](https://vivibit.net/download/dlm_download-3430/), 0 bytes (on invokation).

Compile the source code in C++ and run the interpreter with no arguments, like this: `/path/to/pxemi`.
The following line is output to stderr: `usage: pxemi pxemFileName`.

#### [RPxem](https://github.com/wktk/rpxem), 0 bytes (on invokation)

Just like nk.'s pxemi, run with no arguments: `Usage: rpxem path-to-pxem-file.pxe` can be seen.

### Programs

#### Pxem, 6 bytes of filename only, case-insensitive, boring.

- Filename: `pXEM.p`.
- Content: none.

#### Pxem, 18 bytes of filename only, case-sensitive output, depends on ASCII-compatible filesystem.

- Filename: `@-.+23.+7A.+%+.+.p`
- Content: None

How it works

On every `??.+` each character is generated with sum of two characters' ASCII code from backwards.

Comment: Pxem is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 1 byte

```
.
```

[Try it here!](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=.&debug=0)

On the online interpreter, prints the following to stderr:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyth.py", line 737, in <module>
    py_code_line = general_parse(pyth_code, safe_mode_on)
  File "pyth.py", line 46, in general_parse
parsed, tokens = parse(tokens, safe_mode)
  File "pyth.py", line 74, in parse
    raise PythParseError(active_token, rest_tokens)
extra_parse.PythParseError: . is not implemented, 1 from the end.
```

The exact error message differs depending on the environment Pyth is running in, but it always includes `PythParseError`.

Answer (score 2):

## Red, 9 bytes

```
prin 'rED
```

Due to the rules, this is valid, but it's boring, so let's not do that, ok?

---

### Non-trivial, 35 bytes

```
prin#"Q"+ 1 prin#"f"- 1 prin#"c"+ 1
```

This takes `Q`, `f`, and `c` as character codes, adds or subtracts 1, then prints them without newlines. `Q + 1 = R`, `f - 1 = e`, `c + 1 = d`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work on TIO, but you can try it [locally](https://www.red-lang.org/p/download.html).

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 5 bytes

```
`c$75
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs0pIVjE35eJKAwAPHAJu)

There seems to be no rules for inplementation-specific programming languages, so I will assume the name of the implementation doesn't need to be included.

Comment: This is likely quite unstable, but another 5-byter is [`1?"A"`](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwztFdyVAIAAwAA9g==)

Answer (score 2):

## APPLESOFT BASIC, 87 bytes /  62 tokenized bytes

```
0x$="":goto1to==^atint>notabscolor=fntoint-spc(pr#
1pokepeek(131)+peek(132)*256,19:?x$
```

Enter the program in lower-case. The output printed:

```
 ":+1APPLESOFT BASIC
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>18</s> <s>16</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

Feels like cheating to be able to use different cases, but OK sure

The language can be case-insensitive??? Wow

-1 byte from @manatwork

```
p:rUBY
```

Comment: As all kind of garbage is accepted around the name: `p:rUBY`.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>29</s> 45 bytes

There's probably a better way.

```js
let f =

_=>'\x4A\x61\x76\x61\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74'

console.log(f())
```

Comment: @ETHproductions This turns out to be more complicated than I expected. Here is a fixed (but weak) version.

Comment: Huh, none of the hex values contain a letter, except for J. Perhaps that could be useful in some way (though I highly doubt it...)

Comment: Abuse case-insensitive requirements for output to print `jAVAsCRIPT`?

Comment: @ValueInk I supposed I could do that but I actually wish this rule didn't exist. It kinda ruins the game.

Comment: How about just `_=>'\x45\x53'+(5+1)`? It is technically ECMAScript6

Comment: @Arnauld ok then, good job, carry on.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
"cjAM"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6@UnOXoq/T/PwA)

#### Old version

```
"BI`l":)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6/k5JmQo2Sl@f8/AA)

```
"BI`l"    e# Push this string
:)        e# Add 1 to the code point of each char. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 19 bytes

Sadly, the shortest answer is also the least interesting:

```js
_=>'jAVAsCRIPT'
```

Yes, the challenge allows for this. I also wish it didn't.

I first tried to do this using [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob), but forgot that the name of that function contains forbidden letters. I also tried using `open` with a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) using base64-encoding, only to realize once I had finished writing my answer that `open` also contains a forbidden character…

One valid solution that outputs *JavaScript* with the correct casing would be encoding the whole name as `\x4A\x61\x76\x61\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74`, but that solution was [already taken](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107975/13486).

**Edit**ed multiple times because various solutions turned out to be invalid.

Comment: Your code is invalid, it contains `t` & `a`

Comment: @TrojanByAccident I deleted the invalid solution.

Comment: Isn't this still invalid as the code contains both `A` and `t` which are found in **ECMAScript**?

Comment: and the `c` in EMCAS**c**ript

Comment: @Emigna Apologies, I seem to keep overlooking those invalid characters. Case in point: I just wasted another 45 minutes on a solution that turned out to be invalid... So for now I'll just go for the boring-but-valid solution.

Comment: @TrojanByAccident The `console.log`
 fragment was not part of the solution, I just put it there so you could
 see the output using the Stack Snippet. Anyway, I updated my submission. After writing a new solution that turned out to be also invalid, with the valid (but boring) solution above.

Comment: "the shortest" this is not the shortest, the shortest is `jAVAsCRIPT`

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>15</s> 6 bytes

The way to do this without errors and with the proper capitalisation costs 15 bytes:

```
?ucase$(@qbic`)
```

Since QBIC is in all-caps, this code is allowed: it takes the string literal `qbic` and prints it in uppercase.

An error-output (which feels kinda cheaty to me) is shorter:

```
?b(12)
```

In 6 bytes, we can put `QBIC encountered error: 9` on the screen, signifying an out-of-bounds error. [See here why](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/104323/shortest-auto-destructive-loop/104402#104402).

There's also this 6-byter that prints QBIC in lowercase:

```
?@qbic
```

That string literal doesn't need a closing backtick, it is auto-closed because of EOF.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 3 bytes

```ruby
p$:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DF6v9/AA)

From the documentation:

***The array contains the list of places to look for Ruby scripts and binary modules by load or require. It initially consists of the arguments to any -I command line switches, followed by the default Ruby library, probabl "/usr/local/lib/ruby", followed by ".", to represent the current directory. (Mnemonic: colon is the separators for PATH environment variable.)***

This is not guaranteed to work on any system, but works at least on TIO, and on most (if not all) Linux distributions when Ruby is installed.

Comment: I had this thought too, but I was wondering if it was too platform dependent. Granted any standard installation should work, but I could create a platform that wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

## [QC](http://github.com/0xqookie/qc) 16 bytes

`&000051430A0D00#`

```
&0000 Write hex to memory at address 00 until 000 is reached
51430A0D00 QC with a new line and the terminator at the end
# Print contents of memory until first 00 is reached
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
¾4>'§ÅX69çJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39on4md@qHlh1sjzCwPL/f6/x8A)

**Explanation**

```
¾              # push counter (initially 0)
 4>            # push 4+1
   '§Å         # push the word "ab"
      X        # push variable X (initially 1)
       69ç     # push char value of 69: "E"
          J    # join as string
```

Comment: `•äƵí•hR` works for 7.

Answer (score 1):

### [Chicken](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Chicken), 1 byte

```
g
```

This could be pretty much any character and it would be the same.

Outputs `Error on line 1: expected 'chicken'`.

[Try it here](http://torso.me/chicken).

Answer (score 1):

### Excel 2010 VBA 113 bytes

I am assuming paragraph spacing is 1 byte. This won't work with earlier versions of Excel. For those who dont have/use Excel, column 14925 is VBA

```
n = 14925
Do While n > 0
c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
s = Chr(c + 65) & s
n = (n - c) \ 26
Loop
Debug.Print s
```

[*Credit where credit is due.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15366979/5784703)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! For further reference, you don't need to CW-ify an answer if you didn't make it. Simply linking to the source works.  Also, you should probably post the plain VBA answer separately.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk Ok, I didn't know if it was necessary or not to CW an answer but I wouldn't feel right if I didnt .. the plain VBA answer I will leave, I made that within the first minute of reading the question and found it uninteresting

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <s>84</s> 44 bytes

```
#import<stdio.h>
main(){puts("\103\53\53");}
```

Thanks to @Clearer for saving a lot of bytes.

Comment: This isn't a valid C++ program. Try this instead: `#include<cstdio>
int main(){char c[]={67,43,43,0};printf(c);}` It's shorter and correct C++.

Comment: @Clearer Yes, that's what I would have done, but like I said, I wanted to completely avoid using the character `c`, upper or lower case. As this does compile on the MinGW compiler I'm using, and I don't think there is any undefined behaviour, it is valid at least on one implementation. (Which is enough for code golf)

Comment: It's not valid just because it compiles on a particular compiler. You're lacking the return type of your main function, which is the only thing that's a problem -- it is a valid C program though. You can shave off a byte by writing `uint8_t l[] =...`, instead of `uint8_t l[4]=...`

Comment: `#include<stdio.h>
int main(){puts("\103\53\53");}` only has the problem that it depends on being able to print ASCII compatible text. It's just 50 bytes long. If you allow c in the program, you can shave it to 49 and be equal to the Java 8 version but include a newline in the output :-)

Comment: Thanks for the shorter version. I'm still omitting the return type of main, since that is allowed by certain compilers, and in code golf, languages are defined by their implementation: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7832/whats-the-policy-on-interpreter-bugs/7833#7833

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>49</s> 41 bytes

Golfed:

```java
n->System.out.println("\112\141\166\141")
```

Ungolfed, full program:

```java
public class OutputProgrammingLanguageName {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(n->System.out.println("\112\141\166\141"));
  }

  private static void f(java.util.function.IntConsumer f) {
    f.accept(0);
  }
}
```

This is a simple `System.out.println()` wrapped in a functional interface to save some bytes, using octal escapes to avoid any of the character literals in "Java". Note that on some JVM implementations, `System.out.print()` does not necessarily flush output. In that case, the program will try to print but nothing is output before the program ends. Using `System.out.println()` requires two additional bytes, but guarantees the program actually prints something.

Comment: You can change `println` to `print`

Comment: @FlipTack I have had problems in previous challenges with flushing of `stdout`, where a program will print nothing and exit. I will take the two byte hit to the score for a guarantee that the program will actually output something.

Comment: `print` seems to work fine for me, but nvm

Comment: Since you're just printing a String you can use octal escapes instead of unicode escapes. Saves 8 bytes. `System.out.println("\112\141\166\141");`

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 1 byte

```
!
```

outputs:

```
error.swift:1:1: error: unary operator cannot be separated from its operand
!
^

error.swift:2:1: error: expected expression

^
```

This just has to be run from a source file with the preferred file extension, `.swift`. The repl reports `repl.swift` as the source file, so that works too.

Comment: Isn't `S` in both Swift and Set?

Comment: @boboquack Whoooops. I'll have to find another generic type with a short name

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 2 bytes

`gv`

Sample output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
$                              $gv
?                              True
^                              $gv
args                           {}
ChocolateyProfile              C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1
ChocolateyTabSettings          @{AllCommands=False}
ConfirmPreference              High
ConsoleFileName
DebugPreference                SilentlyContinue
Error                          {System.Management.Automation.ParseException: At line:1 char:11...
ErrorActionPreference          Continue
ErrorView                      NormalView
ExecutionContext               System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics
false                          False
FormatEnumerationLimit         4
HOME                           C:\Users\username
Host                           System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHost
input                          System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple
MaximumAliasCount              4096
MaximumDriveCount              4096
MaximumErrorCount              256
MaximumFunctionCount           4096
MaximumHistoryCount            4096
MaximumVariableCount           4096
MyInvocation                   System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
NestedPromptLevel              0
null
OutputEncoding                 System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
PID                            7912
PROFILE                        \\thing\user$\user_folders\username\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
ProgressPreference             Continue
PSBoundParameters              {}
PSCommandPath                  \\thing\user$\user_folders\username\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
PSCulture                      en-AU
PSDefaultParameterValues       {}
PSEmailServer
PSHOME                         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
PSScriptRoot                   \\thing\user$\user_folders\username\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell
PSSessionApplicationName       wsman
PSSessionConfigurationName     http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell
PSSessionOption                System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSSessionOption
PSUICulture                    en-US
PSVersionTable                 {PSVersion, WSManStackVersion, SerializationVersion, CLRVersion...}
PWD                            C:\Windows\system32
ShellId                        Microsoft.PowerShell
StackTrace                        at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )...
true                           True
VerbosePreference              SilentlyContinue
WarningPreference              Continue
WhatIfPreference               False
```

This is shorthand for the cmdlet `Get-Variable`, which displays the name and value of all variables in scope. Among these are a few environment variables which are also regular variables, like `$PSHOME` and `$PROFILE` which contains paths for powershell to run in, and where to find the script to run for every new session.

Answer (score 1):

### GNU M4, 5 bytes

```
dnl()
```

Output:

```
m4:stdin:1: Warning: excess arguments to builtin `dnl' ignored
```

### GNU M4, 10 bytes, clean output

```
m`'incr(3)
```

Output:

```
m4
```

### GNU M4, 40 bytes, clean output, correct case

```
translit(ulinzg,a-z,z-a)(%c,77)`'incr(3)
```

Output:

```
M4
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Quetzalcoatl, 0 + 1 for `-n` flag = 1 byte

```
<no code>
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Hoon](https://github.com/urbit/urbit), 13 bytes

```
`@t`0w1.KrSZ8
```

Hoon has an atom encoding `@uw`, which is base-64. This simply casts an `@uw` literal back to a cord (`@t`), which is the value `'Hoon'`

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 13 Bytes

I tried using error codes and  all sorts of little tricks, but it would appear that this is about as compact as I can get it, as boring as it is.

Anonymous Immediates window function that takes no input out outputs to the immediates window. Works with both Win and Mac Excel, Access, Word, PowerPoint, Outlook and Publisher

```vb
?ucase("vba")
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 1 byte

```
_
```

This leads to a parse error. Run like this:

```
php -r '_'
> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line code on line 1
```

## Version without resorting to STDERR (8 bytes)

Note: uses IBM-850 encoding

```
<?=~»À»;
```

Run like this:

```
echo '<?=~»À»;' | php 2>/dev/null
> PHP
```

This just uses the binary opposite of `PHP`, and negates it using the `~` operator.

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 6 bytes

```
A0P99P
```

Prints the ASCII values `100` and `99`, i.e. `dc`.

Answer (score 1):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata) - <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Code-page)

```
44c3×
```

As short as `","3×` and `",,,"`!

### Explanation

```
44c3×

44         push 44                        [44]
  c        convert 44 to ASCII character  [',']
   3×      repeat ',' 3 times             [',,,']
           implicit output                []
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rexx (Regina)](http://www.rexx.org/), 32 bytes

```
say d2c(82)d2c(69)d2c(88)d2c(88)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0qtqPj/vzixUiHFKFnDwkgTRJlZgikLCxj1/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, 6 bytes

**Solution:**

```
.Q.x10
```

**Example:**

```
q).Q.x10
@["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"]0x40\:
```

**Explanation:**

`.Q.x10` returns a function you could use for some base64 encoding, calling without parameters outputs the function body.

**Bonus:**

22 bytes gets us a purer answer. Here we cast (`"c"$`) integers (`113 47 107 100 98 43`) to ASCII chars:

```
q)"c"$43+70 4 64 57 55 0
"q/kdb+"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Noether, 15 bytes

```
"n"UP"OETHER"_P
```

[**Try it here!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=Im4iVVAiT0VUSEVSIl9Q&input=)

***Explanation:***

```
"n"      - Push the string "n"
U        - Convert the string on top of the stack to uppercase
P        - Print the top of the stack
"OETHER" - Push the string "OETHER"
_        - Convert the string on top of the stack to lowercase
P        - Print the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [4](http://esolangs.org/wiki/4), 1 byte

```
3
```

Using [this ruby implemtation](https://gist.github.com/0x0dea/db1b66344a7970a18373) from the esolangs' page, any program that doesn't matches `/^3\.\d*4$/` will print

```
SyntaxError: Program must begin '3.' and end '4'.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Chip-8, 22 bytes.

```
0xA212
0xD003
0xA215
0x6108
0xD103
0xF00A
0xD59D
0xD560
0x6C40
```

I hope this counts. Does not contain bytes corresponding to C, h, i, p, -, or 8 in ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (in Firefox), 627 bytes

Doesn't use JavaScript's letters upper or lowercase. Only works in Firefox because it uses eb() function as a method of getting a "p". It also needs the popup blocker to be disabled.

```
f=!1+[];n=1E309+[];h=!0+[];d=(eb+[])[3];o={b:1};g=d+"on"+f[3]+h[0]+h[1]+"u"+d+h[0]+"o"+h[1];q=(/b/[g]+[])[14];l=[][g][g];k=o[g]["key"+f[3]](l(h[1]+"e"+h[0]+"u"+h[1]+"n o"+q+'en("")')());u=k["f"+n[3]+"l"+h[0]+"e"+h[1]](l("b",h[1]+"e"+h[0]+"u"+h[1]+"n 0==b."+n[3]+'ndexOf("on'+n[3]+'n")&&"l"==b[6]'))[0];e=k["f"+n[3]+"l"+h[0]+"e"+h[1]](l("b",h[1]+"e"+h[0]+"u"+h[1]+"n-1!=b."+n[3]+'ndexOf("omm'+u[5]+"nd"+f[3]+'")'))[0][6];m=o[g]["n"+f[1]+"me"][2][h[0]+"oU"+q+q+"e"+h[1]+e+u[5]+f[3]+"e"]();l(h[1]+"e"+h[0]+"u"+h[1]+"n "+d+"on"+f[3]+"ole")().log(m+u[5]+u[4]+u[5]+f[3][h[0]+"oU"+q+q+"e"+h[1]+e+u[5]+f[3]+"e"]()+d+h[1]+n[3]+q+h[0]);
```

Ungolfed version:

```
f = !1+[];
n = 1E309+[];
h = !0+[];
d = (eb+[])[3];
o = {b:1};
g = d+"on"+f[3]+h[0]+h[1]+"u"+d+h[0]+"o"+h[1];
q = (/a/[g]+[])[14]
l = [][g][g];
k=o[g]["key"+f[3]](l(h[1]+'e'+h[0]+'u'+h[1]+'n o'+q+'en("")')());
u = k["f"+n[3]+"l"+h[0]+"e"+h[1]](l("b",h[1]+'e'+h[0]+'u'+h[1]+'n 0==b.'+n[3]+'ndexOf("on'+n[3]+'n")&&"l"==b[6]'))[0];

e = k["f"+n[3]+"l"+h[0]+"e"+h[1]](l("b",h[1]+'e'+h[0]+'u'+h[1]+'n-1!=b.'+n[3]+'ndexOf("omm'+u[5]+'nd'+f[3]+'")'))[0][6];
m = o[g]["n"+f[1]+"me"][2][h[0]+"oU"+q+q+"e"+h[1]+e+u[5]+f[3]+"e"]();;
l(h[1]+'e'+h[0]+'u'+h[1]+'n '+d+"on"+f[3]+"ole")().log(m+u[5]+u[4]+u[5]+f[3][h[0]+"oU"+q+q+"e"+h[1]+e+u[5]+f[3]+"e"]()+d+h[1]+n[3]+q+h[0]);
```

Comment: What is `eb`? I'm using Firefox and it doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 79 bytes

```
-[>++>++>++<<<-----]>----.>++++++++++++.<-.>>+++.+++++.<<+++++.>+++.<---.>>---.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pOWxuCbGxsdEEg1g5E6gFFEEDPBigAEtGDcm0gtB1EDqQcpEvv/38A)

It's not the shortest brainfuck submission, that would be [@Sp3000's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108062/78407), but frankly, I dont understand how his submission works anyways, and this was the best I could do.

**Explanation:**

The word "brainfuck" is 9 letters: b(98), r(114), a(97), i(105), n(110), f(102), u(117), c(99), and k(107)
Splitting these up into three groups by similar ascii values gives us our tape:

*`[Initial Count Cell] , [ABCF Cell] , [RU Cell] , [IKN Cell]`*

By using three cells instead of one to print the ascii characters, we cut down the number of bytes needed by nearly half.

```
-[>++>++>++<<<-----]     Wrapped loop sets all three ascii cells to 102
>----.                   print 'b'
>++++++++++++.           print 'r'
<-.                      print 'a'
>>+++.                   print 'i'
+++++.                   print 'n'
<<+++++.                 print 'f'
>+++.                    print 'u'
<---.                    print 'c'
>>---.                   print 'k'
```

**Output:**

```
brainfuck
```

**Credits:**
-2 bytes thanks to [@ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)

Comment: Very good simple answer, using a relatively short yet easy to understand algorithm. I believe you can save two bytes by using `ABCF` `IKN` `RU` instead: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fN9pOWxuCbGxsdEEg1g5E6gFFEEDPBigAEtGDcm0gtB1EDqQcpEvv/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ada (GNAT)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnat/), 164 bytes

```
function Test return Integer is
 function puts(C:out Integer)return Integer with Import,Convention=>C;Text:Integer:=16#00616441#;
begin return puts(Text); enD Test;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc6xCsIwFAXQvV/xoIsFhQZKhoS6xKV7fyDqM2bwpSQvtn8fabEOzvdc7rV3e3JkuZRHphv7QDBiYojIORIMxOgwgk8V/MCUOR2MCpn3vPnjs@cnDK8pRD6aQG@ktdifjR5xYfVlqheyblspZNeJWldXdJ725W1k1Y0GpMv2SpfyAQ)

It is hard not being able to use EITHER a. Especially since the I/O library is called `Ada.Text_IO` and there's no way around that. Since I can't access Ada's standard library, I have to go around and import some I/O from C. Luckily its easy to do that from within Ada, unfortunately the function that would work well is `putchar` with that pesky `a` again.

To work around I need to somehow send a pointer through to C. Unfortunately the types that will do this are `Interfaces.C.Pointers` which has an `a` and `access` types, also with A. Thus I'm left using Ada's implicit interpretation of `out` parameters in C interfaces as being a pointer. Now I just construct a 32-bit integer as my 'string' and it just so happens to fit "Ada" and the null terminator.

I was close to removing the only `d` too, but there's no way out of using `end`. Depending on how you style Ada you can toggle its case, as the language is completely case insensitive (but with the standard spelling the case insensitivity still bans the `a`).

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
V?
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=V%3F&a=1)

Outputs version info.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), Not 31 but 28 bytes

```ruby
p'Qtax'.chars.map(&:next)*""
```

Thanks @iamnotmaynard for the improvements

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0A9sCSxQl0vOSOxqFgvN7FAQ80qL7WiRFNLSen/fwA)

Comment: I noted that it does, I'm just trying out the older version of ruby, to see if I can get a solution which doesn't. It's not going well.

Comment: Maybe `.chars` instead of `.bytes`? `p 'Qtax'.chars.map{|x|x.next}.join`

Comment: @manatwork I'm afraid not. `String#chars` returns an array of strings, each one of which is 1 character long. `'R' + 1` returns `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`

Comment: That is why I used `.next`. (Same as `.succ`, but that is forbidden because “u”.) Or shorter: `p'Qtax'.chars.map(&:next)*''`

Comment: @manatwork AAARRRGGGHHH! I forgot about `succ`.  That's so much better! Thanks! :@)

Comment: @manatwork And then there's a `u`... Ugh!

Comment: Gimme de *succ*

Comment: `*""` saves 2 over `.join`

Comment: and `%w{Q t a x}` saves 1 over `'Qtax'.chars` (though then it needs a space after `p`, so I guess it's a wash)

Answer (score 1):

## x86, 8 bytes

Returns the string "x86" in `eax`.

```
0:  b8 3c 1c 1b 00          mov    $0x1b1c3c,%eax
5:  d1 e0                   shl    %eax
7:  c3                      retq
```

As ASCII:

```
�<���
```

The idea is to get  0x363878. It may be possible to shorten this with a clever multiply or other instruction.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 1 bytes

Includes `+1` for `-v`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9DwT/8gtKMvPziv/rlgEA)

(the body is empty). This includes both `perl` and `Perl`. But I'm going to assume the language name is `perl` from here on. It's what perl's own version string says the name is after all.

This is of course totally boring. Somewhat more interesting:

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 6 bytes

```perl
say$^X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIlLuL//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDfQMAA)

This assumes the name of the executable contains `perl`. I've yet to see an install where this is not so.

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 11 bytes

```perl
say"\LPERL"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIpxifANchH6f//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwN9AwA)

Uses the fact that case variations don't count. I couldn't use `lc` because it contains `l`. Still boring

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 12 bytes

```perl
say FSDZ^6x4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLBLdglKs6swuT//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDfQMAA)

This one clean but long

Answer (score 1):

### [@](https://esolangs.org/wiki/@), 4 bytes

Although the language name is 1 byte, outputting the name is astonishingly difficult.

```
-{}0
```

This subtracts the string a by 0, which is undefined behavior and thus throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "@", line 477, in <module>
    res  = root.eval()
  File "@", line 413, in eval
    return self.ins.func(*self.argv, *self.insargs)
  File "@", line 115, in insHYPHEN
    raise TypeError('-')
TypeError: -
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 1 byte

```
a
```

Output:

```
jq: error: a/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
a
jq: 1 compile error
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 2 bytes

```
ne
```

#### Explanation

```
n  Push n
 e Recurse with a(n-n); i.e. a(0), which is undefined
```

This tries to do recursion of itself where a(0) is undefined. Therefore, it recurses until the Python interpreter's call stack overflows:

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Current thread 0x00007f4457bba740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ast.py", line 67 in _convert
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/ast.py", line 91 in literal_eval
  File "/opt/oasis/oasis.py", line 27 in pop_stack
  File "/opt/oasis/oasis.py", line 261 in func_a
  File "/opt/oasis/oasis.py", line 268 in func_a
  ...
/srv/wrappers/oasis: line 3:  2892 Aborted                 (core dumped) python3 /opt/oasis/oasis.py .code.tio "$@" < .input.tio

Real time: 0.242 s
User time: 0.182 s
Sys. time: 0.036 s
CPU share: 90.02 %
Exit code: 134
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z8v9f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Turing Machine But Way Worse](https://github.com/MilkyWay90/Turing-Machine-But-Way-Worse), 3813 bytes

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 2 0 0
0 2 0 1 3 0 0
0 3 1 1 4 0 0
0 4 0 1 5 0 0
0 5 1 1 6 0 0
0 6 0 1 7 0 0
0 7 0 1 8 1 0
0 8 0 1 9 0 0
0 9 1 1 10 0 0
0 10 1 1 11 0 0
0 11 1 1 12 0 0
0 12 0 1 13 0 0
0 13 1 1 14 0 0
0 14 0 1 15 0 0
0 15 1 1 16 1 0
0 16 0 1 17 0 0
0 17 1 1 18 0 0
0 18 1 1 19 0 0
0 19 1 1 20 0 0
0 20 0 1 21 0 0
0 21 0 1 22 0 0
0 22 1 1 23 0 0
0 23 0 1 24 1 0
0 24 0 1 25 0 0
0 25 1 1 26 0 0
0 26 1 1 27 0 0
0 27 0 1 28 0 0
0 28 1 1 29 0 0
0 29 0 1 30 0 0
0 30 0 1 31 0 0
0 31 1 1 32 1 0
0 32 0 1 33 0 0
0 33 1 1 34 0 0
0 34 1 1 35 0 0
0 35 0 1 36 0 0
0 36 1 1 37 0 0
0 37 1 1 38 0 0
0 38 1 1 39 0 0
0 39 0 1 40 1 0
0 40 0 1 41 0 0
0 41 1 1 42 0 0
0 42 1 1 43 0 0
0 43 0 1 44 0 0
0 44 0 1 45 0 0
0 45 1 1 46 0 0
0 46 1 1 47 0 0
0 47 1 1 48 1 0
0 48 0 1 49 0 0
0 49 0 1 50 0 0
0 50 1 1 51 0 0
0 51 0 1 52 0 0
0 52 0 1 53 0 0
0 53 0 1 54 0 0
0 54 0 1 55 0 0
0 55 0 1 56 1 0
0 56 0 1 57 0 0
0 57 1 1 58 0 0
0 58 0 1 59 0 0
0 59 0 1 60 0 0
0 60 1 1 61 0 0
0 61 1 1 62 0 0
0 62 0 1 63 0 0
0 63 1 1 64 1 0
0 64 0 1 65 0 0
0 65 1 1 66 0 0
0 66 1 1 67 0 0
0 67 0 1 68 0 0
0 68 0 1 69 0 0
0 69 0 1 70 0 0
0 70 0 1 71 0 0
0 71 1 1 72 1 0
0 72 0 1 73 0 0
0 73 1 1 74 0 0
0 74 1 1 75 0 0
0 75 0 1 76 0 0
0 76 0 1 77 0 0
0 77 0 1 78 0 0
0 78 1 1 79 0 0
0 79 1 1 80 1 0
0 80 0 1 81 0 0
0 81 1 1 82 0 0
0 82 1 1 83 0 0
0 83 0 1 84 0 0
0 84 1 1 85 0 0
0 85 0 1 86 0 0
0 86 0 1 87 0 0
0 87 0 1 88 1 0
0 88 0 1 89 0 0
0 89 1 1 90 0 0
0 90 1 1 91 0 0
0 91 0 1 92 0 0
0 92 1 1 93 0 0
0 93 0 1 94 0 0
0 94 0 1 95 0 0
0 95 1 1 96 1 0
0 96 0 1 97 0 0
0 97 1 1 98 0 0
0 98 1 1 99 0 0
0 99 0 1 100 0 0
0 100 1 1 101 0 0
0 101 1 1 102 0 0
0 102 1 1 103 0 0
0 103 0 1 104 1 0
0 104 0 1 105 0 0
0 105 1 1 106 0 0
0 106 1 1 107 0 0
0 107 0 1 108 0 0
0 108 0 1 109 0 0
0 109 1 1 110 0 0
0 110 0 1 111 0 0
0 111 1 1 112 1 0
0 112 0 1 113 0 0
0 113 0 1 114 0 0
0 114 1 1 115 0 0
0 115 0 1 116 0 0
0 116 0 1 117 0 0
0 117 0 1 118 0 0
0 118 0 1 119 0 0
0 119 0 1 120 1 0
0 120 0 1 121 0 0
0 121 1 1 122 0 0
0 122 0 1 123 0 0
0 123 0 1 124 0 0
0 124 0 1 125 0 0
0 125 0 1 126 0 0
0 126 1 1 127 0 0
0 127 0 1 128 1 0
0 128 0 1 129 0 0
0 129 1 1 130 0 0
0 130 1 1 131 0 0
0 131 1 1 132 0 0
0 132 0 1 133 0 0
0 133 1 1 134 0 0
0 134 0 1 135 0 0
0 135 1 1 136 1 0
0 136 0 1 137 0 0
0 137 1 1 138 0 0
0 138 1 1 139 0 0
0 139 1 1 140 0 0
0 140 0 1 141 0 0
0 141 1 1 142 0 0
0 142 0 1 143 0 0
0 143 0 1 144 1 0
0 144 0 1 145 0 0
0 145 0 1 146 0 0
0 146 1 1 147 0 0
0 147 0 1 148 0 0
0 148 0 1 149 0 0
0 149 0 1 150 0 0
0 150 0 1 151 0 0
0 151 0 1 152 1 0
0 152 0 1 153 0 0
0 153 1 1 154 0 0
0 154 0 1 155 0 0
0 155 1 1 156 0 0
0 156 0 1 157 0 0
0 157 1 1 158 0 0
0 158 1 1 159 0 0
0 159 1 1 160 1 0
0 160 0 1 161 0 0
0 161 1 1 162 0 0
0 162 1 1 163 0 0
0 163 0 1 164 0 0
0 164 0 1 165 0 0
0 165 0 1 166 0 0
0 166 0 1 167 0 0
0 167 1 1 168 1 0
0 168 0 1 169 0 0
0 169 1 1 170 0 0
0 170 1 1 171 0 0
0 171 1 1 172 0 0
0 172 1 1 173 0 0
0 173 0 1 174 0 0
0 174 0 1 175 0 0
0 175 1 1 176 1 0
0 176 0 1 177 0 0
0 177 0 1 178 0 0
0 178 1 1 179 0 0
0 179 0 1 180 0 0
0 180 0 1 181 0 0
0 181 0 1 182 0 0
0 182 0 1 183 0 0
0 183 0 1 184 1 0
0 184 0 1 185 0 0
0 185 1 1 186 0 0
0 186 0 1 187 0 0
0 187 1 1 188 0 0
0 188 0 1 189 0 0
0 189 1 1 190 0 0
0 190 1 1 191 0 0
0 191 1 1 192 1 0
0 192 0 1 193 0 0
0 193 1 1 194 0 0
0 194 1 1 195 0 0
0 195 0 1 196 0 0
0 196 1 1 197 0 0
0 197 1 1 198 0 0
0 198 1 1 199 0 0
0 199 1 1 200 1 0
0 200 0 1 201 0 0
0 201 1 1 202 0 0
0 202 1 1 203 0 0
0 203 1 1 204 0 0
0 204 0 1 205 0 0
0 205 0 1 206 0 0
0 206 1 1 207 0 0
0 207 0 1 208 1 0
0 208 0 1 209 0 0
0 209 1 1 210 0 0
0 210 1 1 211 0 0
0 211 1 1 212 0 0
0 212 0 1 213 0 0
0 213 0 1 214 0 0
0 214 1 1 215 0 0
0 215 1 1 216 1 0
0 216 0 1 217 0 0
0 217 1 1 218 0 0
0 218 1 1 219 0 0
0 219 0 1 220 0 0
0 220 0 1 221 0 0
0 221 1 1 222 0 0
0 222 0 1 223 0 0
0 223 1 1 224 1 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZdJctwwDEX3OYWPoA9xvE722aXKx3ea@oNSXhiEuluvQIhP@Pvn9/f3z8/1df7w@fv8/8UIX6VVPddure7nWtOqPde6Vv25NrQaz7Wp1XxW69zjs1rPauva5h0v314EwSEPDAQSwUggEwwFUsFYIBeGbg6SwWif4Lm@vF5cGw/kK/MVq1Xme4LPOgUrft58T/BZN92/yFfmK/KVC1eDa/MVa1fmK/KV@Z7gs0Pmu8l3m@9m/e7S/W/taLaU9btdv7txbb4n@KzNd5PvNt/N@t3mu8l3m@8mX7t0/0a@Zr5Gvub6Ndavma@xfi1Nx/o18zXWr5mvka@Zr5Gvufkau6@Zr5Gvu36d/dfN17m/3Xyd9evm6@Tr5ut6KvJYsH7d/dfZf918nXzd9evk6@br5BvmG@Qb5hus3zDfIN8w3@D@DvffIN8w39BzmweX9RvmG@y/Yb5BvmG@Qb5pvsn9neab5Jvuv0m@ab5Jvun6TfbfNN9k/ab5pk6WHC3km@ab7L9pvsnnd7n/FvmW@Rb5luu32H/LfIv7u8y3yLfMt8i3zLfIt8y3dPbl8GP9lvkW@bbrt7m/23yb/bfNt8m3zbfJt823ub/bfJv7u91/m3zbfJv9t12/zfrtHM/cX1zvAa0T@soRfemMvnJIX6VMjunr1u@4EU/ETI7qS2f1NZIZyuS4vqa@lQP7WsrkyL7klFcqkOP@04qY4caEzfKqBWJ@5YKmb4UZXZ8Jsw3zKgZifiUDMb@agepcblTINIhqTkQXvjIUc3QD@QYVZhkHUQ6jkwmzrINoB/IOaoVHzFHPiZ5vRT4nYibM8g/uMN82@KtwOTwSYnQyYb7VG3dEfqvOURHkIkRGkI0QHZ2I7wthlpEQJUFOQqTE6GTCLC@hpZ9lJkRNjE4mdZadED0xOpkwy1CIoiBHIZJidDJhlqfQ088yFaKqEz13j6zQ/bb0vi6pzj3MMhaiLMhZiLROxEyYu@o80s9DzFEX5C5EXidiJsxDdR5hlsEQhTE6mTAPMUdjJ@Ivp59lMkRlJ3o@E5mdiJkwy2eYYZ5ijtIYnUyYp5ijtRPxW@nn6TfT99VUvRG5QXZD9MbovL@GWYZDFMfoZMK81BvRHOQ5rPTzEnNUdyK@K6fOsh2iuxPxM@8Lteoc5UHOQ6QHWQ/R3omYST9vMUd9J@JnUuet8zn6Y3QyYd56BqNAyIGIBLE9BbxjgOcA93NdmgTiwZIHKx4sebDiwRMx05LRRBAPMjqZDAXyYMWDJQ/WtcKzlMloIA9WPFiargrv@CLmDFglD1Y8WPJgxYMlD1Y8WJqzKoNWyYMVD5ZmrYoHS9NWxYMlD9Y7cHniekcuebD@G7rE/I5dpTo/gxd@fv4B)

Little surprised I didn't see this here already.

Answer (score 1):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), 212 bytes

```
+>+>+>+>+>->->-
+"+"+"+"+"-"-"-
+++++++++-----.
+++++++.+-.-.-
+++++++-+-+-+-
+++++++-+-+-+-
+++++++-+-+-+-
+++++++-+-+-+.
++++++.-+.+-++
++++++--+++-++
++++++--++..++
++++++--++--++
+!+!+!-!+!-!+!
=#=#=#=#=#=#=#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9f2w4GdUGQS1sJBnVBkEsbBnRBQA/G19PW1QNCGFcXAknhwozS0wUZpq3NBbMGrAKZq6eHwtUFyyqCoC4Uc9kqI8P//wE)

This answer quite simply increments and decrements the value in one cell. I'm pretty sure this is the shortest you can get without loops - I might look at an answer using loops later.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rail](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rail), 35 bytes

```
$ 'main'
 -[q]?3c(!!)2co\
  #oc1?n(!!)oc5?-&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0rMzPmvoqCem5iZp/5fQTe6MNbeOFlDUVHTKDk/hktBQTk/2dA@DySQn2xqr6v2/z8A)

Here's an expanded version:

```
 $ 'expanded'
 \
  --[any string]-?-3c-(!discard!)-2c-o\
                                       \
          #-o-c1-?n---(!discard!)-o-c5?--&
```

Rail works like a train track, with special 'stations' (functions) represented by characters that operate on values from the stack.

This pushes a string (`"q"` in the short one, `"any string"` in the long one), and then gets its type (`"string"`), which has an **`r`** in. It then cuts the string up to just get the r, and prints that to stdout.

It then creates an empty lambda, gets its type (`"lambda"`), which has an **`a`** in it, cuts the first 5 letters out, and prints the last a.

It then pushes `nil` (the empty list) to the stack, with `n`, gets its type (`"nil"`), gets the **`il`** and prints that.

The special character stations used are as follows:

- `[q]`, `[any string]`: push a literal string
- `?`: pop a value, push its type
- `3`: the literal value "3"
- `c`: pop a, b; cut the string at the ath position and push back both halves
- `(!!)`: pop a value and store it in the variable with name in between the `!`s.
- `o`: pop the stack and print its value to Standard Output
- `\`, `-`: rails
- `&`: push a lambda to the stack, and turn the train around a half turn
- `n`: push nil to the stack.
- `#`: terminate the program

Fun fact, in the expanded version, the second instance of the variable assignment to `discard` is actually assigning to `dracsid`, because the order you go through a station matters. The characters are read individually by the train as it goes through. This doesn't matter, because it's just being used to pop values off the stack and never use them again.

Answer (score 1):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w), 3 bytes

I'll see which is compressable, I am not permitted to use the compressor yet.

Convery 87 to a character.

```
87C
```

### W, 3 bytes

Output every character between 'a' and 0x00. It maps over the (implicit input) 0 converted to a character to the letter 'a'.

```
CaM
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-v` 0 bytes

Prints:

```
Keg Last Updated On: Wednesday 15 January 2020
```

Well, at least using commit [`8b6ad216c1fc60e59bd143ba2ee0571df29db2f6`](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg/commit/8b6ad216c1fc60e59bd143ba2ee0571df29db2f6) it does. The date part changes between commits. Why? Because `-v` prints out the current interpreter version.

A 3 byte answer:

```
ǨƐƓ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////@IpjE45N/v8fAA)

Prints:

```
keg
```

A 6 byte answer:

```
L;f;h;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fxzrNOsP6/38A)

Prints:

```
Keg
```

The 3 byter uses the push'n'print part of Keg, and the 6 byter pushes each letter and decrements it to get the correct letter.

Comment: of course the obligatory -version comment

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 0 bytes (compile time) / 18 bytes (run time)

### Compile time, 0 bytes

Complier output:

```
error[E0601]: `main` function not found in crate `empty`
  |
  = note: consider adding a `main` function to `empty.rs`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0601`.
```

### Run time, 18 bytes

```
fn main(){todo!()}
```

Output:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'not yet implemented', panic.rs:1:11
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Unfortunately, panicking via array indices

```
fn main(){[][1]}
```

doesn't work, because `rustc` catches the error at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 1 byte

```forth
]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//x/7/DwA)

`]` switches to compile state, causing following words to be executed with their compilation semantics... and apparently, if the program never returns to interpret state, also causing it to output

```
Gforth 0.7.3, Copyright (C) 1995-2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Gforth comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `license'
Type `bye' to exit
```

I thought maybe there was some chance I could get around having to create a definition to use loops for another challenge, but this works too.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net), 0 bytes

*Ties [OrangeDog's Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107992), [nigel222's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108067), [Cees Timmerman's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108068), [Loovjo's Vim answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108070), [Noodle9's Vim answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108090), [James Holderness's Befunge answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108110), [Alex Howansky's PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108117), [Flambino's huh? answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108201), [NoOneIsHere's Quetzalcoatl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/108438), [Matthew Roh's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109168), [G B's Erlang answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113004), [cp.fe.cp's TeX answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129099), [BlackCap's UPL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145197), [Rajan Kumar's Go answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189874), [lyxal's Keg answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198039), [user92069's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204845), [madlaina's Rust answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209176), and [tail spark rabbit ear's Pxem answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220892) for #1.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@DwQA)

## Output (`stderr`)

```
Error: could not find or load class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org), 0 bytes

Takes a command-line option **not** in this list:

```
-B
-b
-c
-d
-E
-I
-i
-O
-q
-S
-s
-u
-W
-X
-x
```

Answer (score 1):

### [<>^v](https://github.com/Astroide/---v), 14 bytes

```
60\62\94\118\`
```

Pushes to stack the character's index in ASCII, then prints them, and prints a newline.

[run online](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#e8375262999047875fedea2b577bb563826a8f9e66ebde7dafd1a561863b9d88)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `h`, 0 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=h&code=&inputs=&header=&footer=)

-3 thanks to Lyxal

Answer (score 1):

## [APOL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/APOL), 1 byte

`↹`

The ↹ constant contains the interpreter's name and language version, which with PyPOL evaluates to "PyPOL APOL interpreter vXXXXXX by GingerIndustries 2021". APOL will then implicitly print the constant's value.

Answer (score 1):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), 74 bytes

```
('%$:^"!~}{3Wyxvv-Qsrq('&Jlj(!~}CAA@~>`ut:rq66GsVTj0hQ,kd*u('r%$5"!C^@@.>,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/19DXVXFKk5Jsa622ji8sqKsTDewuKhQQ13NKydLAyjq7OjoUGeXUFpiVVRoZuZeHBaSZZARqJOdolWqoV6kqmKqpOgc5@CgZ6fz/z8A)

Generated with [ZB3's Malbolge Tools](https://zb3.me/malbolge-tools)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `h`, 0 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJoIiwiIiwiIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Any character that is an invalid flag will work. Outputs a list of all flags and their descriptions; the `v` flag says "Use Vyxal encoding for input file" which contains the name.

Edit: This actually doesn't output to Debug (which is like STDERR), instead it prints to regular Output

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore C64, 40 PETSCII characters with BASIC keyword abbreviations

```
?"{CTRL+N}":fOr=40964to40971:?cH(pE(r)+128);:nE
```

This prints out the ROM bytes from 0xa004 to 0xa00b, and adds 128 to convert the case.

### How it works

Firstly, printing the control character N (CTRL + N on the C64 keyboard) switches Commodore C64 BASIC to upper/lower case characters, equivalent of pressing SHIFT + C= key. Like many 8-bit BASIC interpreters, the `?` is abbreviation for `PRINT`.

The `fO` is F then SHIFT + O on the keyboard, which is the abbreviation for the `FOR` command. So, we are iterating over 40964 to 40971 inclusive of the ROM, passing the values of these bytes to the variable `r`.

`?cH(pE(r)+128);` is printing the contents of each byte per iteration and adding 128. As we're not in the PETSCII graphics mode, these characters will appear as upper case. `nE` is the abbreviation for `NEXT`, which will iterate again until `r` is equal to `40971`.

[image: Output programming language name, Commodore C64]

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 9 bytes

```
"hASKELL"
```

You don't even need to know Haskell to see that this works.

Answer (score 0):

## Pascal, 47 bytes

```
BEGIN WRITE(UpCASE('p'),LOWERCASE('ASCAL'))END.
```

Output:

```
$ ./g
Pascal$
```

## Alternative boring way, 25 bytes:

```
BEGIN WRITE('pASCAL')END.
```

Output:

```
$ ./g
pASCAL$
```

Comment: You can't use P, A, S, C, A or L in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

**Python, 0 bytes (cheating?)**

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 13 2017, 10:15:16) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

`python` is a shell command not a language command. It could equally be `xyzzy` if I have previously done

```
$ ln -s $( which python) xyzzy
```

Or just `x` (one byte, if you insist on counting the shell command as well).

Comment: I think you have to mark this as "Python (REPL)", because we've decided that a REPL is a different language from the language itself. Apart from that, though, I don't see why it wouldn't work; "REPL" is not part of the language's name.

Comment: You're not allowed to use the characters contained in the language's name.

Comment: `x` or `xyzzy` don't use characters contained in the languages name. I thought a little explanation was in order. Maybe cheating though, in that the python interpreter prints its own name by default.

Comment: This is what I considered to submit, but decided for something else. IMHO this is valid, because invoking the programming language itself does not mean you are using the name as part of the code - (almost) any other answer needs to call the interpreter or compiler anyway if you want to actually run the program!

Answer (score 0):

## Scala. 11 bytes

```
1##
```

Run with `scala -feature /path/to/file.scala` (+8 bytes for `-feature`).

Outputs:

```
/path/to/file.scala:1: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; multiline expressions may require enclosing parentheses
1##
 ^
/path/to/file.scala:1: warning: postfix operator ## should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.postfixOps visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps'
or by setting the compiler option -language:postfixOps.
See the Scaladoc for value scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
1##
 ^
two warnings found
```

Answer (score 0):

## Del|m|t, 25 bytes

[TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/delimit#@2@rYKXgmJRZmVVZqKCvYKRgp2CvoKygpaD4/z8A)

```
= : Abiyjyq / 2 > ? # * !
```

No command line arguments, so the starting delimiter is  .

Explanation:
<sub>Format: (token) command effect</sub>

```
(=) 29        jump command - no-op the first time through, skips 1 command the other times
(:) 26        Pushes the following String backwards. Only happens once
(A...) 25     "Del|m|t" shifted down by 3. Also the "print char" command
(/) 15        Duplicates top value
(2) 18        Nots the top, used in order to check if we printed everything
(> ?) 30, 31  If we did, end the program
(# *) 3, 10   Add 3 to the value, setting each character back to the desired "Del|m|t"
(!) 1         Pushes 1, which makes the first command skip the pushing of the string.
              This then causes the string "Abiyjyq" to print the top value when we repeat.
```

The trick here is using the String `Abiyjyq` to both encode the string `Del|m|t`, and print the top of the stack as a character. Thankfully, no character in `Del|m|t` is also in `Abiyjyq`, because the `i`s in the language name are replaced with `|`s

Answer (score 0):

## [Brainelly](https://github.com/lachniet/Brainelly), 36 bytes

```
ƑA$ƒṃƁẸḷ-ṚżƁẸH/ƑKƁƊṄ$Ƒ9$⁾ṃmṚỤ$Ƒ7EṢṘ{
```

---

Original Brainfuck code:

`++++[++++>---<]>-.---[----->+<]>-.+++[->+++<]>++.++++++++.+++++.---------.+++++++..-[--->+<]>.`

With a no-op inserted to avoid the character restriction:

`++++[++++>---<]>-.---[----->+<]>-.+++[->++++-<]>++.++++++++.+++++.---------.+++++++..-[--->+<]>.`

Answer (score 0):

## Stacked, 30 + 1 = 31 bytes

+1 for `p` extension. Call like:

```
node stacked.js -pe "(115:1+97:2+107:6-:1-)#:''join"
```

(where `e` is the execute flag.) The `p` prints the top of the stack at program end. The output is `'stacked'`.

### Explanation

```
(115:1+97:2+107:6-:1-)#:''join
(                    )           array containing these
 115                             [115, 
    :1+                                115+1,
       97                                     97,
         :2+                                      97+2,
            107                                         107,
               :6-                                           107-6,
                  :1-                                               107-6+1]
                      #:         cast each number to a character
                        ''join   join by empty strings
```

### Example usage

```
λ node stacked.js -pe "(115:1+97:2+107:6-:1-)#:''join"
'stacked'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 4 bytes

```
.ver
```

Output is as follows:

```
8th 16.14 WIN64 Free (6362ab32) custid: ########
```

I blanked my custid with `########`

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (REPL), 42 bytes

```
'\x6a\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74'
```

Answer (score 0):

## JAVA, 21 byte

`throw new Exception();`

print

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception

Full program :

```
public class OutputProgrammingLanguageName {

  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a complete program or function.

Comment: Also the complete program contains `a` and `v`

Comment: @Metoniem then that would means it's impossible in java since you always have `main`

Answer (score 0):

**Pyth 8 bytes**

```
r"pYTH"2
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=r%22pYTH%222&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

### dc, 6 bytes

```
Eo194p
```

Outputs `DC`. Alternatively, so does this:

```
Fo207p
```

The only bases in which `dc` can output the letter `D` as part of a number are 14, 15 and 16, but I don't know if it's possible to express 16 using a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 0 bytes

```
<Yep, you read it right, 0 bytes.>
```

According to TIO, it outputs:

```
usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.3.1/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/srv/wrappers/c-gcc: line 5: ./.bin.tio: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Good use of gcc arguing when theres absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 21 bytes

```
parse version a
say a
```

Will give something like

```
REXX-Regina_3.9.1(MT) 5.00 5 Apr 2015
```

or

```
ARexx V1.15 68070 68881 PAL 50HZ
```

Answer (score 0):

## Erlang, 0 bytes

As many other languages, starting the interactive interpreter shows the language name and version.

Answer (score 0):

## TeX and variants (0 bytes)

Inputting an empty file or just running `tex` on the command line leads to an output on the console screen starting with

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265
```

This also works for pdfTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX, but not for the LaTeX-variants (the "La" doesn't get printed).

Since this is TeX, I would like to also be able to produce a DVI or PDF with the TeX logo in it, but I have not yet been able to find a way around the restrictions. Simply `\TeX\bye` for plain TeX does work, but contains all letters in the name at least once. The LaTeX variant is even worse with `\documentclass{book}\begin{document}\LaTeX\end{document}`, which contains the `e` 6 times. For both, commands containing an `e` are obligatory to have a valid document. Maybe there's a way around this with some smart redefinitions, but since many macros in TeX contain the letter `e` I doubt it will be easy.

Comment: You can use TeX's `^^` replacing mechanism to insert characters without explicitly typing them (see full explanation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64848/23765)). This leads to `\^^54^^%^^58\^^%nd` as the shortest full TeX document solution, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

### Julia 0.6.0 (13 bytes)

```
versioninfo()
```

Pretty boring answer, but Julia had to be represented! ;)

of course just opening Julia tells you the name... But I don't know if that's a valid answer

Comment: `i` is a part of `Julia`. you can't use it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 8 bytes

#### xxd-style hexdump

```
00000000: 2381 00e2 e5e1 ee20                      #..âåáî
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNzPv/3wAKrBSMjC0MFQwMUo0UUk1TDRVSU40MFBT@/wcA)

#### Equivalent JavaScript

```
"bean "
```

Strings (and non-standard identifiers) in `bean` are encoded by using the high bit to determine whether to continue reading the packed bytes as part of the string, since the only supported strings in `bean` are ASCII and the high bit would otherwise be unused.

Since the **last character** in the packed bytes for a string does not have the high bit set, it **must not be one of the characters in the language name** because it is equivalent to the last character in the correlating string in the source and characters from the language name are restricted from the source.

Therefore, the last 5 characters in the [ISO/IEC_8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoded `bean` source are `âåáî` followed by a space. You can confirm that these characters correlate to `bean` by checking this script:

```js
let string = Array.from("âåáî").map(character => {
  const code = character.charCodeAt(0)
  return String.fromCharCode(code & 0x7F)
}).join("")

console.log(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [33](https://github.com/TheOnlyMrCat/33), 1 byte

```
~
```

Any character not recognised by the interpreter will print the message `33 (<location>): Unrecognised token`. In this case, the location would be `1:1`.

## Non-stderr version, 3 bytes

```
btp
```

The mutable list is initially filled in with argv, with the first element of that normalised to be "33". This takes 33 from the list, puts it in the source string, then prints it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 8 bytes

Probably the only time Rockstar will ever come close to being competitive!

```
rOCKSTAR
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## [CSASM v2.1.2.3](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.1.2.3), <s>108</s> 19 bytes

```
func main:
abs
ret
end
```

The `abs` instruction throws the following error if no values were on the stack:

```
StackException thrown in compiled code:
   Stack underflow detected. Cannot pop more objects from the stack.
   at CSASM.Core.CSASMStack.Pop()
   at CSASM.Core.Ops.func_abs()
```

Any of the 3-character instructions that pop a value from the stack would also work for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/), 21 bytes

```
66.114.97.110.99.104.
```

Try it on the [online Branch interpreter](https://branch.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyI2Ni4xMTQuOTcuMTEwLjk5LjEwNC4iLCIiLCIiXQ==)!

Not the most exciting answer. An answer with no numbers though:

## [Branch](https://github.com/hyper-neutrino/branch-lang/), 74 bytes

```
/^\^'/;c;^+/;c;^'/;c;^*N/;^*}}./;c;^+/;cn^-{{.O/;cn^-{./o{{{{.^}}./{{{{{{.
```

Try it on the [online Branch interpreter](https://branch.hyper-neutrino.xyz/#WyIvXlxcXicvO2M7XisvO2M7XicvO2M7XipOLzteKn19Li87YzteKy87Y25eLXt7Lk8vO2NuXi17Li9ve3t7ey5efX0uL3t7e3t7ey4iLCIiLCIiXQ==)!

Answer (score 0):

### x86 machinde code - 12 bytes

Borrowed code from [qwr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/107964/output-programming-language-name/160445#160445)'s answer.

```
 8048054:   b8 1a dd 2c 11          mov    eax,0x112cdd1a
 8048059:   2d de c0 11 11          sub    eax,0x1111c0de
 804805e:   d1 e0                   shl    eax,1
```

Answer (score 0):

## A0A0, 15 bytes

```
P65
P48
P65
P48
```

`P` prints the character corresponding to the ASCII value next to it. Luckily for me, none of the ASCII values needed have a zero in them. If the requirement of not containing the characters of your language wasn't there, this could be improved by two bytes by swapping out the `P48` for `O0` which prints the numeric value after it, so zero.

One column is the most optimal layout for this text. Two columns would add 2 bytes to the total.

Answer (score 0):

## [JSFuck](https://jsfuck.com) ([JScrewIt](https://jscrew.it/) Firefox), 1053 bytes

```javascript
(+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[+[]]+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!![]+!![]+!![])+(!![]+!![])))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]][([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[+!![]]+([]+(+[])[([]+[][(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!![]]+(![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!![]+!![]+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!![]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]])[+!![]+[+!![]]]+(!![]+[])[!![]+!![]+!![]]]](!![]+!![]+!![]+[!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VO9CsIwEN59itMpodpZFAUXX8DxzBBqlYokJZ4FEZ@9pjbaGFSK4maGkvt@7qdHtrKQ@8RkOQ2KYTkzRh7j3GjSdMzTWBJM4ASJVnsyh4S0GcH8oBLKtPJkHt8H0gsymdqMgHGYTKG3dgaQZJHTUoE9qCRlRWpTr1KxVOcenMedKo/epfFOb1jJItbtoojafjBCISJ2DXjo5a@IFhIf4JxjHdm7q@hCi9/gCmmIWnfD6z4t6zjW0vzY0zdlsVI9GJz@VYlg0Mbo58L7TJ/P8uUfDfoT@G7YZga79/8ifrqIhq9jTxF0IET4PvHJUxW85OPyAg)

Requires Firefox nightly for [`Array.prototype.at`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at), or you can use the following polyfill on any browser:

```javascript
Array.prototype.at = { constructor: Function.prototype.constructor, toString: () => "function at() {\n    [native code]\n}" };
```

Answer (score 0):

## PICO-8, 22 bytes

```
?"\112\73\67\79\45\56"
```

Outputs "Pico-8"; I feel that this should be fine, as it is acknowledged as an alternative in the PICO-8 [FAQ](https://www.lexaloffle.com/pico-8.php?page=faq):

> #### How should the name be written and pronounced?
>
> The preferred style is all caps with a dash: PICO-8. If you feel like you're shouting in the middle of a sentence, Pico-8 or pico-8 is also fine.

And here's the all-caps version (24 bytes), if needed:

```
?"\112\105\99\111\45\56"
```

---

Fun fact: I didn't realize that `?`, escape characters, or lowercase letters were useable going into this, and due to just how much the restriction limited my options, I had to resort to modifying the memory directly in order to produce the same result as `cls() print("PICO-8")`.  That ended up looking like this:

```
memset(24576,0,0x2000)
b=0x66
l=0x06
r=0x60

//line 1
memset(0x6000,b,1)
memset(0x6001,l,7)
memset(0x6002,b,1) // +8
memset(0x6004,r,1) // +8
memset(0x6006,r,1) // +8
memset(0x600a,b,1) // +8
memset(0x600b,l,1) // +8

//line 2
memset(0x6040,l,2)
memset(0x6042,r,1)
memset(0x6044,l,1)
memset(0x6046,l,2)
memset(0x604a,l,2)

//line 3
memset(0x6080,b,1) //8
memset(0x6081,l,1)
memset(0x6082,r,1)
memset(0x6084,l,1) // 8+8
memset(0x6086,l,2)
memset(0x6088,b,1)
memset(0x6089,l,1)
memset(0x608a,b,1)
memset(0x608b,l,1)

//line 4
memset(0x60c0,l,1) //c+8
memset(0x60c2,r,1)
memset(0x60c4,l,1)
memset(0x60c6,l,2)
memset(0x60ca,l,2) //c+8

//line 5
memset(0x6100,l,1)
memset(0x6102,b,5)
memset(0x6103,l,3)
memset(0x6104,r,1)
memset(0x610a,b,1)
memset(0x610b,l,1)
```

A compliant/golfed version of this would be ~500 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/h/38A)
This just throws an error that outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jelly", line 74, in <module>
    raise SystemExit(main(code, args, end))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jelly/__init__.py", line 10, in main
    output(jelly_eval(code, args[:2]), end)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jelly/interpreter.py", line 422, in jelly_eval
    return variadic_chain(parse_code(code)[-1] if code else '', arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jelly/interpreter.py", line 1247, in variadic_chain
    return niladic_chain(chain)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jelly/interpreter.py", line 683, in niladic_chain
    return monadic_chain(chain, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jelly/interpreter.py", line 622, in monadic_chain
    ret = monadic_link(chain[0], ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jelly/interpreter.py", line 637, in monadic_link
    return link.call(arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jelly/interpreter.py", line 2988, in <lambda>
    call = lambda z: dyadic_link(links[0], (z, z))
IndexError: list index out of range

Real time: 0.080 s
User time: 0.063 s
Sys. time: 0.014 s
CPU share: 96.62 %
Exit code: 1
```

The name of the language, jelly, being contained in the second line of the error.

Answer (score 0):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 52 bytes

Since Fortran is case insensitive and the case of the output doesn't matter we can abuse this and just code the program in sArCaSm CaSE.

```
pROgRAm fORTRAN
pRiNT*,"fORTRAN"
eNd pROgRAm fORTRAN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vCPJPD3LMVUjzDwoJcvTjKgjK9AvR0lGC8pW4Uv1SFNAU/f8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 54 bytes, prints to STDERR

Prints `GO`.

```go
package main
func main(){print(string([]rune{71,79}))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjfNChKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuNJK85LBLA3N6oKizLwSjeISIJWuER1bVJqXWm1uqGNuWaupWQvRDTUEZhgA)

## [Go](https://go.dev), 67 bytes, prints to STDOUT

Also prints `GO`.

```go
package main
import."fmt"
func main(){Print(string([]rune{71,79}))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjedCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSvSU0nJLlLjSSvOSwcIamtUBRZl5JRrFJUAqXSM6tqg0L7Xa3FDH3LJWU7MWYhTURJjJAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Aheui (esotope)](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), 61 bytes

```
받바밢타밝밤밝밝따붒
밦밦받따땨히파타먛타
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xILc38///1htmvN0x5vWHR2@aG1xvmvt6wBEzOfT1lw@ttk7heb1gGRrNB/Kkr3s7reNvTA1K6YjaQ/P8fAA)

Prints "Aheui".

```
>>>>>>>>>v
.........>  Push 3, -9 (0 - 9), 7, 4, 43 (7 * 7 - 6) to the stack

>>>>».>>».  Loop: Push 108 (6 * 6 * 3), swap, subtract, print as char

.....X<...  On swap, movement is reversed if not enough items on the stack;
            go to halt instruction
```

## [Aheui (esotope)](https://github.com/aheui/pyaheui), 87 bytes

```
받발따빠따빠따빠발발발따따타맣밝밣밢밢따따따다밦타밝타맣히
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xILc38///1htmvN8x5PWXD650LUEigIAQBuVM2vG1ueL188esNc19vAJKLQAgsDkLdS15vWAZSsGEuRNnbeR3//wMA)

Prints "아희", the original Korean name of this language.

```
>>>>>>>......................  Push 15^4=50625
       >                       Dup
        >>>>>>>                Subtract 5^3=125 and print 50500 as char (아)
               >>>>>>>>        Add 7*8*9*9=4536 to 50625 = 55161
                       >>>>>X  Subtract 6 and 7 and print 55148 as char (희)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>18</s> 12 bytes

I skipped over the "case insensitive" part of the challenge description initially.

```
"gOLFsCRIPT"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/Xynd38et2DnIMyBE6f9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 8.23 bytes

```
"tHUNNO"zV
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharlEo8Qv38_JWqwiACUHGYPAA)

```python
"tHUNNO"    # Push the string "tHUNNO"
        zV  # Convert to title case
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## JSFuck, 6369 bytes

```
[][((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]]((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))+([]+ +([]+[][+[]]))[(+!+[])]+((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]]((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))][([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]](([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])])()[([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]](([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]]((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])))
```

**Explanation**

```
_0 = +[];
_1 = +!_0;
_2 = _1 + _1;
_4 = _2 + _2;
_8 = _4 + _4;
_16 = _8 + _8;
_32 = _16 + _16;
_35 = _32 + _2 + _1;

_objectObject = [] + {}; // Here [object Object]
_undefined = [] + [][_0];
_NaN = [] + +_undefined;
_false = [] + ![];
_true = [] + !![];

a = _NaN[_1];
c = _objectObject[_4 + _1];
e = _undefined[_2 + _1];
f = _false[_0];
i = _undefined[_4 + _1];
j = _objectObject[_2 + _1];
l = _false[_2];
n = _undefined[_1];
o = _objectObject[_1];
r = _true[_1];
s = _false[_2 + _1];
t = _objectObject[_4 + _2];
u = _undefined[_0];

_space = _objectObject[_4 + _2 + _1];
_functionString = [] + ([]+[])[c+o+n+s+t+r+u+c+t+o+r];

S = _functionString[_8 + _1];
g = _functionString[_8 + _4 + _2];

h = (_16 + _1)[t+o+S+t+r+i+n+g](_35);
k = (_16 + _4)[t+o+S+t+r+i+n+g](_35);
m = (_16 + _4 + _2)[t+o+S+t+r+i+n+g](_35);
p = (_16 + _8 + _1)[t+o+S+t+r+i+n+g](_35);

[][m+a+p][c+o+n+s+t+r+u+c+t+o+r](r+e+t+u+r+n+_space+c+o+n+s+o+l+e)()[l+o+g](j+s+f+u+c+k)
```

Try it:

```js
[][((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]]((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))+([]+ +([]+[][+[]]))[(+!+[])]+((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]]((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))][([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]](([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])])()[([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]](([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+![])[+[]]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]))[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+([]+[])[([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[(+!+[])]+([]+![])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]+([]+[][+[]])[+[]]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]+([]+{})[(+!+[])]+([]+!![])[(+!+[])]])[(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])]]((+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[])))
```

Answer (score 0):

## ZX81 BASIC, ~60 Tokenised BASIC bytes

```
1 PRINT CHR$ 191; CHR$ 189; CHR$ 164; CHR$ 157; CHR$ 128; CHR$ 167; CHR$ 166; CHR$ 184; CHR$ 174; CHR$ 168
```

Some notes: the ZX81 default character set does not have upper and lower case characters, in fact, all of the BASIC tokens, such as `PRINT` are included in the character set. It does however have normal and reversed characters in which all of the bits are flipped per character (except for keywords). So this prints `ZX81 BASIC` with the reversed characters.

I've included the machine name as ZX BASIC is pretty distinct amongst 8-BIT basics, of which there are three revisions, ZX80, ZX81 and ZX Spectrum (the latter being commonly called ZX BASIC).

I will properly work out the byte count later. This may be entered online into the JtyOne ZX81 emulator [here](http://www.zx81stuff.org.uk/zx81/jtyone.html)

[image: Output programming language name, program for the Sinclair ZX81]

[image: Output programming language name, the result of running the program on the ZX81]