# Given an int input n, print out n*reversed(n)

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

Given an integer `n`, print out `n * reversed(n)`

`reversed(n)` is the number you get when you `reverse` the digits of `n`.

---

```
reverse(512) = 215

reverse(1) = 1

reverse(101) = 101

>>>>>>>>
```

---

```
func(5) = 5*5 = 25

func(12) = 12*21 = 252

func(11) = 11*11 = 121

func(659) = 659*956 = 630004
```

Shortest code wins!

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=144816,OVERRIDE_USER=71625;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: What is the reverse of `100`?

Comment: `001`, but in any case, its fine if you have additional zeros in front

Comment: Why downvote? Because this challenge is too trivial (compare to some other challenges, it is not!) or because it is badly-formatted / unclear?

Comment: @user202729 I downvoted because I didn't see or anticipate a lot of variety or depth to answers.  This question is boring, I tried it.  Part of the reason it is boring is because its trivial, which I think is a perfectly just cause to downvote a question on its own.

Comment: What if the input is negative?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
R*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/SOv/fzNTSwA)

In 05AB1E, integers and strings are treated as equivalent types, so reversal (`R`) converts to string and reverses, whilst multiplication (`*`) treats the reverse and the input as integers.

Comment: `Â*` is valid too :D.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (SpiderMonkey)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Releases/45), <s>45</s> <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 28 bytes

```javascript
n=>n*[...n].reverse().join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQu/ilQYP6t4tEoNgMzTZxIXR6ey/77iW0VN9ZajqxPUw3fiPaQXajaQcAOqBhxyaoDWRO5NwITMIFofClo1bLqowZPw)

- Saved 2 bytes thanks to [dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/Dennis)
- Saved 8 bytes thanks to [kamoroso94](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/57013/kamoroso94)
- Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ATaco](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58375/ataco)
- Saved 5 bytes thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You don't have to count `f=`; anonymous functions are allowed by default.

Comment: Switch out `(n+"").split("")` for `[...(n+"")]` to save a few bytes.  You don't need the unary plus, and the parentheses around the reversed string are extraneous.  All in all, that saves you 10 bytes.

Comment: You can replace `.join("")` with `.join\`\`` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: Save 5 bytes by taking input as a string: https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQu/ilQYP6t4tEoNgMzTZxIXR6ey/77iW0VN9ZajqxPUw3fiPaQXajaQcAOqBhxyaoDWRO5NwITMIFofClo1bLqowZPw

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
×ṚḌ
```

I'm new to Jelly, so please let me know if there is a way to do this in 1 or 2 bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9Ic7Zz3c0fP//38jQwA)

#### Explanation

```
×ṚḌ    (Input: 12)

 Ṛ     Reversed decimal digits (Stack: [2, 1])
×      Multiply by input       (Stack: [24, 12])
  Ḍ    Convert to decimal      (Stack: 252)
       Implicit print
```

Comment: Actually `ṚḌ×` would be a better version. Of course this would still work, due to how bases work.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I originally wrote that first, but moved the `×` for fanciness ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
->n{n*eval(n.digits*'')}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##PYtNDoIwGET3nOILG35SCa1Cogl6ENJFpUWakNrQ1mjEs9eihN2beTOTu7583/jdWb1VLh5sTFXB5U1akydJ9vFtBNBWCEhF0YKYLEzWgBFggv@hro4I6n1Zlgca0UKwbgB@h1kq7SwC8dSis4LPYTsJ40YLDfTtz9LQ6Ukqu5lm28MF4lQzYzKI4RS4Z3IMvFycNesjEor7Lw).

`Integer#digits` returns a list of reversed digits, so further reversing is not necessary.

Thanks to [@benj2240](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77973/benj2240) for golfing a byte!

Comment: [You can save a byte with eval](https://tio.run/##PYtNDoIwGET3nOILG35SCa1Cogl6ENJFpUWakNrQ1mjEs9eihN2beTOTu7583/jdWb1VLh5sTFXB5U1akydJ9vFtBNBWCEhF0YKYLEzWgBFggv@hro4I6n1Zlgca0UKwbgB@h1kq7SwC8dSis4LPYTsJ40YLDfTtz9LQ6Ukqu5lm28MF4lQzYzKI4RS4Z3IMvFycNesjEor7Lw)

Comment: @benj2240 thanks! :)

Comment: The eval route doesn't actually work, as it will cause the program to fail on 900 with error `Invalid octal digit (SyntaxError)` instead of returning the expected 8100...

Answer (score 3):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 2 bytes

```
œΠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//@jkcwv@/zcztQQA)

Explanation:

```
œΠ   Main wire, arguments: n

œ    Pushes [n, n.reverse]
 Π   Multiplies that array together
     Implicit output
```

Comment: *stays on the phone for 4 months* :P

Comment: You must be put on hold for a long time for there to be no explanation

Comment: @MilkyWay90 We've all been stuck on hold for a year and a half before, right?

Comment: @NickClifford Not all of us have

Answer (score 3):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 12 bytes

Takes input as an int.

```
a*reverse(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z9Rqyi1LLWoOFUjUfP///9GhgA)

Comment: Thats why I said integer input ;), does int still work?

Comment: @KSplitX Oh, I didn't notice that. I'd think that restriction a bit unnecessary, but it's up to you.

Comment: @KSplitX Fixed.

Comment: Should use `n * reverse(n)` so it matches the question's specification word for word (Given an integer `n`, print out `n * reversed(n)`)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 11 + 1 (`-p`) = 12 bytes

```perl
$_*=reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXsu2KLUstag49f9/E9N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Comment: [Command-line flags are free now!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/78123)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>35</s> 28 bytes

```python
lambda m:m*int(str(m)[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIdcqVyszr0SjuKRII1cz2spK1zBW839BEUgsTQNEZuYVlJZoaALBfwsDAA)

<sup>Saved 7 bytes by fixing a bug pointed out by Dennis.</sup>

Comment: Nah its clear, you convert to string, the `[::-1]` reverses it, then we eval xD

Comment: This doesn't work for input **80**, as `08` is an invalid (octal) literal.

Comment: *Saved 7 bytes by fixing a bug* Don't you just love it when that happens...

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>27</s> 23 bytes

*4 bytes saved thanks to Lynn and Laikoni*

```hs
(*)=<<read.reverse.show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0NL09bGpig1MUWvKLUstag4Va84I7/8f25iZp5tQVFmXolKmoKJxf9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA)

Comment: 23 bytes without import: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0NL00bLrig1MUWvKLUstag4Va84I7/8f25iZp5tQVFmXolKmoKJxf9/yWk5ienF/3WTCwoA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: With `Control.Monad` it is also 23 bytes: `ap(*)$read.reverse.show`.

Comment: No need for `Control.Monad`. `(*)=<<read.reverse.show` works fine.

Comment: @Lynn Thanks! I feel like I should have seen that.

Answer (score 3):

## J, 7 bytes

```
*|.&.":
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03BVk9Bq0ZPTU/Jiis1OSNfIU3BFMYwNIKzDGEsM1PL//8B)

Couldn't think of a shorter way, though I feel like this is pretty elegant.

#### Explanation

```
*|.&.":
   &.":  Convert to string, apply next function, then undo conversion
 |.      Reverse
*        Multiply by input
```

Answer (score 3):

## bash, <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```
for((i=n=$1;r=r*10+i%10*n,i/=10;));{ :;};echo $r
```

Comment: You can replace `do...done` with curly braces to save some bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEMj0zbPVsXQusi2SMvQQDtT1dBAK08nU9/W0MBaU9O6WsHKutY6NTkjX0Gl6P///2amlgA). This is from the [tips for Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25802/69583) post.

Comment: thank-you, I'm glad to learn it, I had never seen this syntax, updating my post

Comment: Isn’t that shellshock?

Answer (score 3):

## C# .NET, 55 bytes

```cs
n=>{int i=n,j=0;for(;i>0;i/=10)j=j*10+i%10;return n*j;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jc0xC8IwFATgvb/iLUJaa02EChLTRXCyk4NziRFeqS@QpIKU/vZYEXG0y8HBx532K22dibprvId6SAB8aAJqOD99MPfi2JPeI4UcpqhAg4qkqmEqgIryVnF5s45JrLjEtRI8bVWbCb7EheDSmdA7AspaOUaZ/NYfFq9QN0gsfX/C9@5gydvOFBeHwZyQDNOsTFP5z4jNHCRmoG25mzPFxSzFP2pMxvgC)

```cs
n=>{           // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  int i=n,     //  Integer `i` (starting at the input)
      j=0;     //  Integer `j` (starting at 0)
  for(;i>0;    //  Loop as long as `i` is not 0
      i/=10)   //    After every iteration: Remove the last digit of `i`
    j=j*10     //   Add a trailing zero to `j`,
      +i%10;   //   and then sum this new `j` with the last digit of `i`
               //  End of loop (implicit / single-line body)
  return n*j;  //  Return the input multiplied with `j`
}              // End of method
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 10 bytes

```perl6
{$_*.flip}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZWmpesYPu/WiVeSy8tJ7Og9n9xYqUCSFTDVNOaiwvOMzRC5RqicM1MLTWt/wMA)

### Expanded

```perl6
{       # bare block lambda with implicit parameter $_
  $_
  *
  .flip # implicit method call on $_
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Batch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490869.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), <s>150</s> <s>125</s> 121 bytes (+ 5 bytes? `cmd/q`)

```batch
set l=%1
set n=0
set r=
:L
call set t=%%l:~%n%,1%%%
set/an+=1
if [%t%] neq [] set r=%t%%r%&goto L
set/ar=%r%*%l%
echo %r%
```

Saved 25 bytes thanks to [user202729](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69850/user202729)!

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Matheus Avellar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66000/matheus-avellar)!

Comment: [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVLJbtswED1XX/EuQhY4id3eAuiU5NBDAnRDzyNpbBGWSIIcOfWlv@4OZYW2K0AQh3rLvCFrit3h8Emf7y@v@ElbhrF@FKyDGxClNVY3ojC1cGs0bhjItne9sVx8sDwFGlg4QBwi7Rgr1HvhIrI8eKoyUGvUCSQdY0f9yEmT7vErMh4I1xSMdCplGgyu5ZvMvBQ@Nid7b@wGdN5fSeXkSnVFmfxDbXcqTXXPmJokCx687DVgUI1EQaiKxz5zSnr8u1ysSpg4dbs2IQqaTqM2KenslQfXKW4eDsh71k@WmAOnPaWF@9nu438Zygvbk2nggYxNIbNxPEsJqo74TH/quNnCTIgkcgx5LR2JlgtcLa@0S9uQsNW3PZ/vTIli@j4BbwrVWabdt5dvWGLjFHQa0Nc1zFFUBcVYPUv@w82oy80C3OuJ/sd4c@8LaNhTup3mma5AKqdrl8FpjmU9YQk1NdvRXwKnUw63VZ0pv41t3XvE0@sz4ui9C4LbquCmc8n2cFh9/vIP)

Comment: Or, [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##VVLLbtswEDxXXzEIIPhRt5ZaoIcAOrSxUPQQA2nzOAQ5rKRNREQiCZKykf68u5RapeFtFzOzs7OsyLen0zt5P8tLXNMzQ2k7BDw608OHRmlp@MDUwDyiNn1PuvnQKc3JP5YlRz0HdggGng6MHNVL4MRz2FoqZqDUqCIotIwDdQNHTfqIG8/YEpbkVGhFStXoTcOrmflWeDIXXqzST6D//aWUjlOpKmgm34osVR3DQXkMWgVFnfrNzUaoYts68UUemYjjV3mN7deZ@2NGQwUEycfjy2jCY3kWF3LF2So572bGXcsaboixwddO2bCJywydwSJdQDM3cZ2KpUwXk1tXuHWevac0zbNRiOvW4P4eu/LbzXeci/MCqUvx8DDP2amDajhuHG3nGZaTdUAi2RbSWU3itC3@qkbahdFBaUm@M8bi2CrJhWIuexNQXg3URXdZosYwsS@vJJcnI73XFffmuBntCC2e0vGBnR@PGcvxA81g@S5IqxFLqKh@Huxb4JTAuqheI1S6MUePi8sd/GCtcQHrIhlDkbGnU/7p8x8)

Comment: Isn't this Batch, not Bash? The TIO for bash does not work for this.

Comment: Yes, yes it is; sorry about that

Comment: You can inline that `if` to be at 121 bytes:  `if [%t%] neq [] set r=%t%%r%&goto L`. However, I think you gotta include 1 byte for the `/Q` flag passed to`cmd` so it runs with implicit `@echo off`

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 87 bytes

```
@set s=%1
@set r=
:l
@set/ar=r*10+s%%10,s/=10
@if %s% gtr 0 goto l
@cmd/cset/a%1*r
```

Need to take the arithmetic route here as string reversal fails for some numbers such as 80.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

```c
i,a;f(n){for(i=0,a=n;a>0;a/=10)i=i*10+a%10;n*=i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BCoMwEETP@hVBEBJdMSlYKGn8kdZDiNruobGo9FDJt6eJ9fZmZ2fGVA9jvEfQcqSWbeM0U1QctLJSt1zqWgnOUGEheKlzwaUtFErn0a7kpdHSCHp@GDBPPRdF5A/b0iTe12FZl1tHFNkacQIBggtoIKKAc3NxMk32xfAbViVeF/wO00j3IKsPFWwmsSxjbfKegxxplvekakne320G/x3s4EgGZCx0u9T5Hw)

Comment: Suggest replacing `a>0` with just `a`

Answer (score 2):

## LISP, <s>91</s> *64* bytes

<s>(defun R (N)(defvar M (write-to-string N)) (parse-integer (reverse M))) (write (* x (R x)))</s>

```
(defun R(N)(write(* N(parse-integer(reverse(write-to-string N))))))
```

Where <s>x</s> N is your integer you want to work with, of course.

I'm pretty new to programming, but I've found that trying these Code Golf problems has been nice practice. Is there something I'm missing that could help with this?

EDIT: Thanks to some tips from ceilingcat, I was able to shave off a few bytes. Old program preserved in strikethrough for reference.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! You can eliminate some whitespace and maybe ditch a variable assignment. Also, by convention you may be able to just return the output instead of `(write ...)`

Comment: You can save a byte using a `lambda` instead of `defun`. Also, read [tips for golfing in lisp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79719/tips-for-golfing-in-lisp)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 18

```bash
bc<<<$1*`rev<<<$1`
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kUJJaXJKcWJyqkJmnYKpgaKRgaKhgZmpprZCSz1WcWqKgq6ugAlPzPynZxsZGxVAroSi1DMxK@J@Sn5f6HwA).

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, <s>41</s> 39 Bytes

```
:&>:a%:}-\
/~\?)0:,a/
>l1-?\&*n;
\ +*a/
```

### How it works:

```
:&
```

Assume input has been pushed to the stack (https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8493/76025). Duplicate it and store a copy in the register.

```
   >:a%:}-\
   \?)0:,a/
```

Converts this to its individual digits, leaving them on the stack.

```
/~
>l1-?\
\ +*a/
```

The top value will always be a zero due to the number-to-digit conversion process; drop it from the stack. Now, while the length is >1, multiply the first item by ten and add it to the item below it. This results in the number reversed.

```
      &*n;
```

Multiply the original number by the reverse, print the answer, and stop.

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/30rNzipR1apWN4ZLKzHGXtPASidRn0tLLc5eQdcwR9sm7////7plhkYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
Ṙ*
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuZgqIiwiIiwiMTIiXQ==), or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4bmYKiIsIiIsIjVcbjEyXG4xMVxuNjU5Il0=).

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 28 bytes

```
~n=parse(Int,reverse("$n"))n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6Fnvq8mwLEouKUzU880p0ilLLUkFsJZU8JU3NPIiSm8Fp-UUKGnk6qRUFqcklqSmathoapjpGppo6GoZGQNoIxDDUMTQyBDLMTC11zIwNDAxMNDW5OAuKMvNKcvI0gLbYwrVzpealQIyGuQIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Leaf Lang](https://gitlab.com/breadleaf/leaf-lang), 41 bytes

Note: The interpreter does not have a stable release. If I introduce a breaking change I will update this post.

```
import"string.lf"argv:o o reverse o*print
```

Explained:

```
import "string.lf" - import stdlib's string.lf
argv               - push all of argv onto stack
:o                 - set o to top value from stack (pops top)
o                  - push o to top of stack
reverse            - reverse the string
o                  - push o to top of stack
*                  - leaf lang will implicitly convert strings to numbers when applicable
print              - print top value of stack with no newline
```

Ungolfed:

```
import "string.lf"
argv : num
num reverse num * 
print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
# IntegerReverse@#&
```

Takes an integer input.

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents 0](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents/tree/cquents-0), 8 bytes

```
#|1:A\rA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X7nG0Moxpsjx/38zU0sA)

### Explanation

```
#|1:      Output first term in sequence
    A\rA  Each term in the sequence equals:
           A * \reverse(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 7 bytes

```
nsSrJl*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@vOLjIK0fr/38TYwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Casio-Basic (fx-CP400), 44 bytes

```
ExpToStr n,a
StrInv a,a
Print n*strToExp(a)
```

There's no built-in for reversing an integer, but there is one for reversing a string.

`ExpToStr n,a` turns n into a string and stores it in `a`, then `StrInv a,a` overwrites `a` with the reversed version of itself. The last line turns `a` into a number, and prints `n*a`.

43 bytes for the code, +1 to input `n` into the parameters box.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 2 bytes

Takes input as a string, outputs an integer.

```
*w
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Knc=&input=IjEyIg==)

Comment: Wow, I thought it would have to be 4 bytes at least... I suppose it's only 3 even if taking input as an integer `*sw`

Comment: @ETHproductions: yeah, that's what I had originally.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```matlab
@(n)str2num(flip(int2str(n)))*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPs7ikyCivNFcjLSezQCMzr8QIKAAU1tTUyvufmFesYWZqqfkfAA)

Octave/MATLAB anonymous function. This is a pretty naïve approach - converts the integer to a string, flips the string, converts the result back to an integer and multiplies it by the original.

---

- Save 2 bytes by using `flip` instead of `fliplr`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda n:n*int(`n`[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk8rM69EIyEvIdrKStcwVvN/moaCgqmmgq2tAggYmXIBBQyNYAJGpkZgAUOYgKGRIVDAzNQSLGBmbGBgYMJVUAQ0VElP6T8A)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 23+1 bytes

```php
<?=$argn*strrev($argn);
```

Save to file and run as pipe with `-nF`.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 42 bytes

```
function f(n)print(n*(""..n):reverse())end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/rTQvuSQzP08hTSNPs6AoM69EI09LQ0lJTy9P06ootSy1qDhVQ1MzNS/lf5qGoZHmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
VPUG*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/Pywg1F3r/38zU0sA)

Explanation: `V` converts to string, `P` flips, `U` converts back to numeric, `G` copies the original input again, and `*` multiplies them together.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 33 bytes

```
:&v>&*nr
a,>:a(?^:a%:@-
2(?va*+>l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/30qtzE5NK6@IK1HHzipRwz7OKlHVykGXy0jDvixRS9su5////7plCmamlgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
i:0qr͍n*@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TyqCw6GxvnpbD//9mppYA)

Takes input, duplicates it, coerces one copy to a string, reverses it, coerces it back to a numerical value, multiplies, and outputs the result.

`0q` performs the coercion to a string by concatenating a zero onto the end. There is no explicit `ToString()` operator, so this is the shortest method in this specific case where the 0 swapped to the beginning doesn't alter the resulting numerical value. *Thanks to ASCII-only for this -1 byte.*

Comment: [10](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TyqCw6GxvnpbD//9mppYA)

Comment: @ASCII-only Fair enough. I end up fiddling with most of these at work and don't always revisit when I go to post them at home.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), 61 bytes

```
REeErEEEEErREEEeEerRREEEEEEEREEEEeEeerRREEEEEeEErRREEEEeEReEE
```

[Try it online!](//soaku.github.io/Pepe/#R-i@_t@-E7Rt@-S7@-_zN)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 5 bytes

```
J<-|*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fy0a3Ruv/f2NDAA)

```
J  # Duplicate
<- # Reverse string
|* # string-to-val & multiply
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 72 bytes

Doesn't use strings. At all.

-10 by [steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)

```js
n=>(a=[],r=n=>(n>9&&r(n/10|0),a=[n%10,...a]))(n).reduce((a,v)=>a*10+v)*n
```

Comment: You can replace `Math.floor(n/10)` with `n/10|0`.

Comment: seems I have a lot to learn...

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 97 bytes,

```
f=\left\{x>0:floor(log(x))+1,0\right\}
g(x)=x∑_{n=0}^f10^{f-n}floor(mod(\frac{x}{10^{n-1}},10))
```

[Try it on Desmos.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6zpkyqhcvn)

Not sure if this is legal as a Desmos answer, uses the fact that variables can be defined in terms of x, but functions of x can use those variables as functions? I'm not sure what actually is happening, but it seems to be... working. If I'm not allowed to use that, change `f=` to `f(x)=` for +3 bytes

Only works for nonnegative integers, which I think is fine since OP doesn't include any test cases for them, and they're not well defined for this problem (what is `-1` backwards? `1-`? That's not a number IMO). If I'm allowed to assume *positive* integers, the first line can become

```
f=floor(log(x))+1
```

for -21 bytes. Very nice, but the challenge says "integers", so it's iffy.

In general though, I know this is further golfable but I tried some of the [Desmos tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230100) and I must be doing something wrong because they weren't working. I'll come back and golf this eventually.

Code breakdown:

```
f=\left\{x>0:floor(log(x))+1,0\right\} definition of... function(?) f
f=                                     define f as
         x>0:                          if x is positive
             floor(log(x))+1             length(x)
                            ,0         else 0
                                       i dont remember why but this works to make g(0)=0

g(x)=x∑_{n=0}^f10^{f-n}floor(mod(\frac{x}{10^{n-1}},10)) definition of main function
g(x)=                                                    define g(x) as
     x                                                   x times
      ∑                                                  the sum of
       _{n=0}^f                                          for each n from 0 to f(x)
               10^{f-n}                                    10^(f-n) times
                       floor(mod(\frac{x}{10^{n-1}},10))   the nth digit from the right of x
                                                         essentially: sum of
                                                           (nth digit of x)
                                                           multiplied by
                                                           (place value of 
                                                           (length(x)-n)th digit of x
                                                         aka: reverse(x)
```

Comment: [66 bytes](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/57cjchbkyg). Btw, variables that are defined in terms of function arguments are called wackscope variables, and is allowed and golfier to use them. In fact, one of my [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230106/96039) goes over this exact thing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
~n=foldl((x,y)->10x+y,digits(n))n
```

- 1 more byte saved by @MarcMush:

```
a^b=10a+b
~n=foldl(^,digits(n))n
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjcVEuOSbA0NErWTuOrybNPyc1JyNOJ0UjLTM0uKNfI0NfOg6oLT8osUNPJ0UisKUpNLUlM0bTU0THWMTDV1NAyNgLQRiGGoY2hkCGSYmVrqmBkbGBiYaGpycRYUZeaV5ORpAM23hWvnSs1LgRgNcwoA)

Comment: -1 byte https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjcVEuOSbA0NErWTuOrybNPyc1JyNOJ0UjLTM0uKNfI0NfOg6oLT8osUNPJ0UisKUpNLUlM0bTU0THWMTDV1NAyNgLQRiGGoY2hkCGSYmVrqmBkbGBiYaGpycRYUZeaV5ORpAM23hWvnSs1LgRgNcwoA

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes

```
l_W%i\i*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Pyc@XDUzJlPr/38zUwA)

Comment: -2:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f/T@@OFw1U@t/rVWEdbSpgqGRgqGhgpmppYIpiGlgqGAQWx0foZRWmpesoeSgraSppK2kYGunoKQdo12r6qf1HwA "CJam – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## brev, 28 bytes

```
(fn(*((as-list reverse)x)x))
```

Crashes on negative

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 4 bytes

```
a*Ra
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJhKlJhIiwiIiwiNjU5IiwiIl0=)

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 6 bytes

```
]Ø.in*

]Ø.in*
]       # Duplicate the input to the stack
 Ø.     # Append a blank string, stringifying the input.
   i    # Reverse it.
    n   # Cast to a number.
     *  # Multiply with the orignal input, implicitely output.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/z/28Ay9zDyt////GxoBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
*s_`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X6s4PuH/fzNTSwA)

Comment: Wow, I had the same answer

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 66 bytes

```
n=m=input('');j=0;while(m!=0) j=10*j+rem(m,10);m=fix(m/10);end
n*j
```

Since Octave doesn't have a function to reverse integers, I had to write one myself. That's what the while loop does. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
S*(d↔d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1hLI@VR25SU////GxkCAA)

**Explanation**

```
S*(    Multiply the input with the result of the following function applied to the input
     d convert number to list of digits 
    ↔  reverse list
   d   interpret list of digits as number
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 60 + 18 bytes

+18 bytes for `using System.Linq;`.

Reversing strings in C# is a pain.

```cs
n=>n*int.Parse(new string(n.ToString().Reverse().ToArray()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BCgIxDETP26/IsRXtTUFWBRE8KSwqeBAPpWaXgqaY1BURv32tKHgZkkneMF4GPjJ2NwnUwPYhCS92FehaKn92IlBxbNhd4KkKSS4FD20MJ1i7QFoSZ@pwBMeNmM9L8UtY3shPAqU@ZJlBDdOOpjPq5c1WjgU14R2@vCa7i9vvaOwGW/zcTTbnzO6hjTFdqf7Zi0gSz2j3HBLmqqhrPRqOjSlV8VKv7g0)

Comment: Arithmetic approach is shorter in C# .NET: [`n=>{int i=n,j=0;for(;i>0;i/=10)j=j*10+i%10;return n*j;}`](https://tio.run/##RY4xa8MwEIVn61fcErBT15GHFooqL4VOCRQ6dCgdhCKbM/aJ3MmFYPzbXRcCWR48eN/H8/LoI4d1EqQOPq@SwlgdkS5G@cGJwAfHjt0Is8okuYQefiOe4eSQckm8Ud8/4LiT4n@S3QzvE/lXpFTCFg20YFeyzbwVQEtlb7VpI@cGG23wYGtd9Lbf1/oBd7U2HNLEBLTvzbIadde@RZI4hOqLMYXtZcjb/PnppSiMyha1rH8) (**55 bytes**)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Go ahead, post it as your own answer, it's a completely different approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [LOGO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fmslogo), 13 bytes

```
[?*reverse ?]
```

Currently there is no TIO for Logo, but you can try it online at http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb . However that's UCBLogo where there is a feature that prints

```
Thank you for using Logo.
Have a nice day.
```

on program exit; if this is considered as a function invocation it does not count. (that is, the function does not prints the message)

Usage:

```
print invoke [?*reverse ?] 123
```

or

```
print apply [?*reverse ?] [123]
```

prints

```
39483
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), 6 bytes

```
*aI_Va
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pNLi0qzixL/P9fK9EzPgxIm5laAgA)

## Explanation:

```
*aI_Va
*a      - multiply by a(input)
  I     - Integerify
   _    - Reverse   
    V   - Stringify 
     a  - a (Input)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 50 bytes

```java
n->n*new Long(new StringBuffer(n+"").reverse()+"")
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hVDBCsIwDL37FcFTq1g2QUGGHjyrF4/iodZsVLd0tN1EZN8@u82rDBKSl7w8HnnIWi5MifS4P1uVS@fgKDV9JgCaPNpUKoRTBwFyQxko1hfiSZg1IUM4L71WcAKCLbS02NGM8AWHQGRdc/ZWU7av0hQto/l0yoXFGq1DxjvUJoNOWd3yoPOTq42@QxHMsOH@cgXJByfnt/NYCFN5UYaVz4mRUGzFe1d/9/FyjBCPENarzZhEFI8yIv77XtN@AQ)

Pretty straightforward.

- `n->`: Lambda-function with 64bit-number as input
- `n+""`: Convert the input-number to String
- `new StringBuffer(...)`: Convert this String to a `StringBuffer`
- `.reverse()`: Reverse it
- `...+""`: Convert the `StringBuffer` back to String
- `new Long(...)`: Convert this String back to a 64bit-number
- `n*...`: Multiply it with the original input, and return it

---

Arithmetic approach would be slightly longer (**55 bytes**):

```java
n->{int i=n,j=0;for(;i>0;i/=10)j=j*10+i%10;return j*n;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hZDPCsIwDMbvPkUuQuuf2QoKUuob6MWjeKi1SuqWja4TRPbss1OvMkgCyffx4yPePMy8rBz5y72zualr2Bmk1wgAKbpwNdbBvl8/B7Csn8RVurSpU9XRRLSwBwINHc23r96CmmZeC3UtA1O4FQoXWgrutZ9IMcWxFCq42AQCPyHVduoLq5pznmA/5qPECxQpDzvEgHQ7nsDwb5jDs46uyMomZlWSYk6MMstW/BPtry6XQwY5YFivNkMIIQcdgv9e2HZv)

Explanation can be found in [my C# .NET port](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144860/52210).

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 9 bytes

```
//.*
oR@i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19fX0@LKz/IIfP/fzNTSwA)

#### Explanation

```
/    Switch to Ordinal. Move SE.
R.   Reverse and duplicate an implicit empty string. Does nothing.
i    Read all input as a string.
.    Duplicate.
R    Reverse.
/    Switch to Cardinal. Move W.
*    Implicitly convert the two strings to integers and multiply them.
.    Duplicate the result. Irrelevant.
/    Switch to Ordinal. Move NW. Immediately bounces off the wall to move SW instead.
o    Implicitly convert the result back to a string and print it.
/    Switch to Cardinal. Move S.
R    Reverse the other copy of te result. Irrelevant.
/    Switch to Ordinal. Move NE. Immediately bounces off the wall to move SE instead.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

### SAS, 54 bytes

```
%macro f(n);%put%eval(&n*%sysfunc(reverse(&n)));%mend;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 34 bytes

```
proc F n {expr $n*[string rev $n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFNIU@hOrWioEhBJU8rurikKDMvXaEotQzIja39n5ObWABSYKpgaKRgaKhgZmpZq1DNVVBaUqwQ7QZSw1X7HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html), 37 bytes

```
{$0*Int(String("\($0)".reversed()))!}
```

**[Try it here!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/59dd22c15b5779594c2f1654)**

Just my mandatory gigantic Swift entry.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 58 bytes

```r
cat((n=scan())*sum(n%/%10^(d=1:nchar(n)-1)%%10*10^rev(d)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxREMjz7Y4OTFPQ1NTq7g0VyNPVV/V0CBOI8XW0CovOSOxSCNPU9dQUxUoqAUUL0ot00jR1NT8b2po9B8A)

reads from stdin, writes to stdout. `n%/%10^(d=1:nchar(n)-1)%%10` is how we get the digits, and reversing them is as simple as taking that vector, multiplying by `10^rev(d)`, and summing.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + stringi, 47 bytes

```r
cat(strtoi(stringi::stri_reverse(n<-scan()))*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO4pKgkPxNEZealZ1pZgRjxRallqUXFqRp5NrrFyYl5Gpqamlp5mv9NDY3@AwA)

`stringi` (not `stringr`) has a `stri_reverse` command.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>27</s></sub> 22 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediate window function that takes input from `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vba
?[A1]*StrReverse([A1])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <del>5</del> 4 bytes

```
*v_`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X6ssXjv7/38zU0sA)

**Explanation:**

```
*v_`QQ : accepts a number as input
   `Q  : represent input as string
  _    : reverses string
 v     : evaluates the string as a number again
*    Q : multiply by the input
       : implicit output
(remove Q's as Pyth adds them for you)
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 31 Bytes

```
param($a)$a*-join("$a"[-1..-9])
```

Powershell is more than happy to multiply a number by a valid numerical string which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 105 bytes

```
@set c=
@set a=%1
:J
@set c=%c%%a:~-1%
@set a=%a:~0,-1%
@if NOT "%a%" == "" goto J
@set/ac=%1*%c%
```

The reverse is performed in a loop which appends the last character `@set c=%c%%a:~-1%` from the input to `c`, and then removes the last character from the input string `@set a=%a:~0,-1%` - rinse and repeat until there are no characters left on the input string. A quick multiplication `@set/ac=%1*%c%` and done.

Answer (score 0):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 5 bytes

```
:ì\ì*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87MLchJLS5JTM7@/9/q8JqYw2u0/v83NAIA)

```
        « implicit integer input   »;
:       « duplicate                »;
 ì      « convert to string        »;
  \     « reverse                  »;
   ì    « back to int              »;
    *   « multiply                 »;
        « implicit integer output  »;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 12 bytes

```
_F!:$|?a*!A!
```

### Explanation

```
   :    Get the input number from the cmd line and assign to 'a'
  ! $     Cast it to string
_F   |    and flip[ that, assigning it into A$
?a*     PRINT 'a' times
   !A!    A$ cast back to int
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto), 8 bytes

```
rd~isi*p
```

```
r  reads input
d  duplicates it
~  reverses the top value
i  convertes it to an integer
s  swaps the two top values
i  convertes the other value to an integer
*  multiplies the top two
p  prints the result
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//78opS6zOFOr4P9/U0MjAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>9</s> 5 bytes

```apl
⍎×⍎∘⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHvX2HpwOJRx0zHvXsBYopqJuqcwFJQyMIZQimzEwt1QE)

Tacit prefix function. Takes input as a string of digits.

Thanks to Adám for 4 bytes.

#### How it works:

```apl
⍎×⍎∘⌽ ⍝ Anonymous, tacit function.
    ⌽ ⍝ Reverse the input
  ⍎∘  ⍝ Convert to number
 ×    ⍝ and multiply
⍎     ⍝ by input converted to number
```

Comment: [`⍎×⍎∘⌽`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHvX2HpwOJRx0zHvXsBYopqJuqcwFJQyMIZQimzEwt1QE "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám wow, I think this is one of my first APL answers. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: What's up with the spurious `Input ⍵.`?

Comment: No idea, probably a hanger-on from an old edit or something :p It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 14 bytes

```
D,f,@,EDE@EdA*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQcfVxdXBNcVR6////4ZGAA)

### How it works

With example input of `12`

```
D,f,@,   - Create a monadic function, f
      ED - To digits;   STACK = [[1 2]]
      E@ - Reverse;     STACK = [[2 1]]
      Ed - From digits; STACK = [21]
      A  - Argument;    STACK = [21 12]
      *  - Product;     STACK = [252]
```

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 22 bytes

```
arg n
say n*reverse(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
DUV×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98lNOzw9P///5uZWgIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
Đ₫*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRHTau1/v83M7UEAA)

```
Đ    Duplicate
 ₫   reverse digits
  *  duh
     implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 21 bytes

```
I:WaSD$|r}l3-Fa*+|+*h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39MqPDHYRaWmqDbHWNctUUu7RlsLKGxmagkA)

### An example > A million words

```
I :D WaSD$D| Dr}l3-D Fa*+D| D+*h
^659
   [659 659]
          [659 9 65]
          [659 9 5 6]
          [659 9 5 6 0]
             [659 9 5 6 0]
                   [659 0 6 5 9 2] <- 2 = operations to do
                         [659 0 6 95]
                         [659 0 956]
                            [659 0 956]
```

Alternate

```
I:WaSD$|~r}l2-Fa*+|*h
```

```
I:&WaSD$|~rlMFa*+|&*h
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 52 bytes

```
n->new Long(new StringBuilder(n+"").reverse()+"")*n;
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##JYuxDoIwFEX3fsULU6uh0Zno4MCkE6NxqPBKiuVB2oIxhG@vRadzb3JOp2aVd80r1lZ5DzdlaGGGAjqtaoRysQO1oPkPJIqVjdPTmhp8UCFhHkwDfap4FZyh9v4AJRZWgj5Fys@Eb7imlG/jb1wmYxt0nPZZJqTDGZ1HLra3oyJWHx@wl8MU5Jj0YIlrqfnxIETB1jV@AQ)
This will give every linter/IDE/compiler a stroke, but hey, it works

Comment: Hi there. This is the same as [my Java answer from 1.5 years ago](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144850/52210), except that you won't have to count the trailing semicolon in lambda submissions, and `StringBuilder` is golfed to `StringBuffer`. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen oh nice.

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 8 char, 16 bytes

```
{⍵×⍎⌽⍕⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{⍵×⍎⌽⍕⍵}
  f 23
736
  23×32
736
  f 11
121
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 3 bytes

```
:⑶*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f6tHEbVr//5uZWv7XzSgCAA)

A port of the 05AB1E answer but longer.

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 47 bytes

```
N-O:-name(N,C),reverse(R,C),name(I,R),O is I*N.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/30/X30o3LzE3VcNPx1lTpyi1LLWoOFUjCMQBC3vqBGnq@CtkFit4avnp/bfSVTAztVTQVfDXUSgoyswr0fDX1PsPAA)

-16 thanks to Jo King

Comment: Both `number_codes` can be replaced by `name`

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt)

```
x*
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/79C6/9/Uy5DIy5DQy4zU0sA)

**Explanation:**

```python
x   # Reverse the (implicit) input-integer
 *  # Multiply it by the (implicit) input-integer
    # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
*$
```

[See the README to see how to run this](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig/blob/master/README.md)

```
*$ # Full program
*  # Multiply
 $ # The reversed number
   # By the implicit input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [CellTail](https://github.com/mousetail/CellTail/blob/main/README.md), 89 bytes

```
1,_,_:1,N,N;N,(a,0,c),_:N,a*c,1;N,(a,b,c),_:N,(a,b/10,c*10+b%10),1;N,a&N..,N:N,(a,a,0),1;
```

[Try the demo](https://mousetail.github.io/CellTail/#ST1DIE47Ck89TjsKMSxfLF86MSxOLE47TiwoYSwwLGMpLF86TixhKmMsMTtOLChhLGIsYyksXzpOLChhLGIvMTAsYyoxMCtiJTEwKSwxO04sYSZOLi4sTjpOLChhLGEsMCksMTs=)

CellTail has no way to turn a number into a string so we have to use modulus and integer division. Uses the cell to the right to provide recursion resistance.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 11 bytes

```ruby
:*%(S|:~|Z)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWq620VDWCa6zqaqI0ISL7CxTcok1juUCUoRGUNoTQZqaWsRBVCxZAaAA)

### Explanation

````
:* % (S | :~ | Z)

      S | :~ | Z   # Convert input to string, reverse, then convert to int
:* % (          )  # Multiply by input

```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 7 bytes

```
.`-1%~*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlf/V8vQddQtU7rf61VWmlesjVXtKmCoZGCoaGCmamlgimIaWCoYBBbrQeSVgIRGkoO2kqaStpKCrZ2CkraMdq1qnla/wE)

Link includes test cases

## Explanation

```
code    # explanation                             | stack
.`-1%~* # function which takes an input integer n | n
.       # duplicate n                             | n n
 `      # stringify                               | n str(n)
  -1%   # reverse                                 | n reverse(str(n))
     ~  # eval                                    | n reverse(n)
      * # multiply                                | n*reverse(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 36 bytes

```
	OUTPUT =(I =INPUT) * REVERSE(I)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NCQgNETBVsNTwdbTD8jUVNBSCHINcw0KdtXw1ORy9XP5/9/QCAA)