# Tips for golfing in Fennel

Tags: code-golf, tips

[Fennel](https://fennel-lang.org/) is a lispy language which compiles to Lua.

From its page:

> Fennel is a programming language that brings together the speed, simplicity, and reach of Lua with the flexibility of a lisp syntax and macro system.

I am looking for general tips for golfing in this language. Tips should be specific to Fennel, "Remove comments and whitespace" is not an answer. If you are giving a general lisp tip then [post it here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79719/tips-for-golfing-in-lisp)