# Reverse a string while maintaining the capitalization in the same places

Tags: code-golf, string

The goal here is to simply reverse a string, with one twist:
Keep the capitalization in the same places.

Example Input 1: `Hello, Midnightas`
Example Output 1: `SathginDim ,olleh`

Example Input 2: `.Q`
Exmaple Output 2: `q.`

**Rules**:

- Output to STDOUT, input from STDIN
- The winner will be picked 13th of July on GMT+3 12:00 (One week)
- The input may only consist of ASCII symbols, making it easier for programs that do not use any encoding that contains non-ASCII characters.
- Any punctuation ending up in a position where there was an upper-case letter must be ignored.

Comment: Is that with or without the outprinting? Is that with or without the string?

Comment: _"Any punctuation ending up in a position where there was an upper-case letter must be ignored."_, isn't the second example inconsistent with this rule?

Comment: It is consistent with the rule because punctuations do not have an uppercase variation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TCC - 4 bytes

```
<>ci
```

[Try it online!](https://www.ccode.gq/projects/tcc.html?code=%3C%3Eci&input=Hello%2C%20Midnightas)

Explanation:

```
     - output is implicit in TCC
<>   - reverse string
  c  - preserve capitalization
   i - get input
```

Comment: The link to the online interpreter is dead. I don't even know where this language is anymore

Answer (score 16):

### Python, 71 bytes

```py
lambda s:''.join((z*2).title()[c.isupper()-1]for c,z in zip(s,s[::-1]))
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/py1Kjj)

-3 bytes from Ruud, plus the inspiration for 2 more.

-4 more bytes from FryAmTheEggman

Comment: `lambda s:''.join([z.lower(),z.upper()][c.isupper()]for c,z in zip(s,s[::-1]))` is three bytes shorter

Comment: @Ruud Thanks! Moving the function call to outside of the list selection saves 2 more!

Comment: `(z*2).title()[c.isupper()-1]` should work.

Comment: You could win another byte with `~c.isupper()` instead of `c.isupper()-1`

Comment: This doesn't get input from stdin or output to stdout...

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare [Functions are allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/45941).

Answer (score 13):

### Perl, 31 + 2 (`-lp`) = 33 bytes

*This solution is from [@Ton Hospel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51507/ton-hospel) (13 bytes shorter thant mine).*

```
s%.%(lc$&gt$&?u:l)."c chop"%eeg
```

But you'll need `l` and `p` switches on. To run it :

```
perl -lpe 's%.%(lc$&gt$&?u:l)."c chop"%eeg'
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This is great!

Comment: Very nice indeed! I've never used`-a` autosplit, I feel I could have used this many times in the past! I need to remember that! I think you can save another byte using `map...,...` instead of `map{...}...` as you have `$F` at the start though! :)

Comment: Shorter code (31+2 bytes): `perl -lpe 's%.%(lc$&gt$&?u:l)."c chop"%eeg`

Comment: Notice that `-a` is implied by `-F`

Comment: @TonHospel wow, thank you very much and well done, that's some quite nice code! About `-a` (and `-n`) being implied by `-F`, I read it a while ago on perlrun, tried it, but it didn't work; but I tried it again now and it works fine so I'm guessing I did something wrong back then. Thanks.

Comment: The `-n` and `-a` options were not always implied by `-F`. You probably tested on an older perl version

Comment: @TonHospel oh right, probably, since I changed my perl version since, that's probably it. Thanks again

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2, 73 bytes

Since the rules specify the input is ascii:

```python
lambda s:''.join([z.lower,z.upper]['@'<c<'[']()for c,z in zip(s,s[::-1]))
```

All the credit goes to @Mego though, but I had not the reputation to just comment on his answer.

Comment: Can you use the ascii value of '@' and '[' to gain 2 bytes?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'd have to use ord(c), integer and string comparison do not cope very well in Python

Comment: Pretty much what I got, but you were first +1

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, <s>13</s> <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

*Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for reminding me about `V` and @LeakyNun for another byte.*

```
srV_Qm!/G
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.tryitonline.net/#code=c3JWX1F9UnJHMQ&input=IkhlbGxvLCBNaWRuaWdodGFzIg)
<sub>now on mobile, updating link in a bit</sub>

Comment: `srV_Qm!rId0` is 11, but I think it might be possible to shorten that map...

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Remove the `d` and you saved a byte.

Comment: `srV_Qm!/G` should save a byte

Answer (score 8):

### Python, 66 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,i=0:s[i:]and(s[~i]*2).title()[~('@'<s[i]<'[')]+f(s,i+1)
```

Recurses through the indices `i`, taking the character `s[~i]` from the back and the case of `s[i]` from the front. Being capital is checked as lying in the contiguous range `@ABC...XYZ[`.
Credit to FryAmTheEggman from the `(_*2).title()` trick.

Answer (score 5):

### Pyke, <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
_FQo@UhAl
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=_FQo%40UhAl&input=Hello%2C+Midnightas)

```
_         -   reversed(input)
 F        -  for i in ^
   o      -      o+=1
  Q @     -     input[^]
     Uh   -    ^.is_upper()+1
       Al -   [len, str.lower, str.upper, ...][^](i)
          - "".join(^)
```

Comment: It first gave me an error, then at the same time the correct answer. http://i.imgur.com/uTcH27F.png

Comment: That always happens, you can click disable warnings to turn that off.

Comment: Aha, okay. Sorry, I'm not good with Pyke

Comment: Might be because I'm the only guy using it

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>95</s> 83 bytes

```
s=>[...t=s.toLowerCase()].reverse().map((c,i)=>s[i]==t[i]?c:c.toUpperCase()).join``
```

Edit: Saved a massive 12 bytes thanks to @edc65.

Comment: s=>r=[...l=s.toLowerCase()].reverse().map((c,i)=>s[i]!=l[i]?c.toUpperCase():c).join`` -10

Comment: @edc65 Thanks! (Note: the `r=` is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>75</s> <s>67</s> 65 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
$
±·$`
O$^`\G[^·]

s{T`L`l`±.
T01`l`L`±.*·[A-Z]
±·

±(.)
$1±
·.
·
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAokCsKxwrckYApPJF5gXEdbXsK3XQoKc3tUYExgbGDCsS4KVDAxYGxgTGDCsS4qwrdbQS1aXQrCscK3CgrCsSguKQokMcKxCsK3LgrCtw&input=SGVsbG8sIE1pZG5pZ2h0YXMKLlEKLnE) (The first line enables a test suite with multiple linefeed-separated test cases.)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

Thanks to **Emigna** for saving a 3 bytes!

Probably gonna get beat by Jelly... Code:

```
Âuvy¹Nè.lil}?
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4J1dnnCuU7DqC5saWx9Pw&input=SGVsbG8sIE1pZG5pZ2h0YXM).

Comment: `S.l_v¹lRNèyiu}?` is 1 byte shorter

Comment: @Emigna Wow thanks! That is very clever.

Comment: `Âuvy¹Nè.lilë}?` is 14. Just happy I can help you for once :)

Comment: @Emigna That is amazing! Very nice use of bifurcate :).

Comment: `Ruvy¹Nè.lil}?` actually. I didn't use the bifurcation and forgot to remove the else. So 13.

Comment: @Emigna At least we're tied with Pyth. Now we just need to defeat APL :p.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com), 30 bytes

```
(={"_1 toupper@]|.@,.])tolower
```

Doesn't support non-ASCII

Comment: "toupper" "tolower" can't you use code points to shorten it?

Comment: @LeakyNun Maybe but I can't really say for sure

Comment: @LeakyNun It's surprising, but I think it's very unlikely this should could be shortened in J.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 28 bytes

```
@lr:?z:1ac.
h@u.,@A@um~t?|h.
```

#### Explanation

- Main Predicate:

  ```
  @lr                 Reverse the lowercase version of the Input
     :?z              Zip that reversed string with the Input
        :1a           Apply predicate 1 to each couple [char i of reverse, char i of Input]
           c.         Output is the concatenation of the result
  ```
- Predicate 1:

  ```
  h@u.,               Output is the uppercase version of the first char of Input
       @A@um~t?       The second char of Input is an uppercase letter
               |      Or
                h.    Output is the first char of Input
  ```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
PktGtk<)Xk5M(
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UGt0R3RrPClYazVNKA&input=J0hlbGxvLCBNaWRuaWdodGFzJw)

```
Pk      % Implicit inpput. Flip, lowercase
t       % Duplicate
Gtk<    % Logical index of uppercase letters in the input string
)       % Get letters at those positions in the flipped string
Xk      % Make them uppercase
5M(     % Assign them to the indicated positions. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

### Actually, 25 bytes

```
;`úíuY"ùû"E£`M@ùRZ`i@ƒ`MΣ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O2DDusOtdVkiw7nDuyJFwqNgTUDDuVJaYGlAxpJgTc6j&input=ImFiQ2Qi)

Explanation:

```
;`úíuY"ùû"E£`M@ùRZ`i@ƒ`MΣ
;                          create a copy of the input
 `úíuY"ùû"E£`M             for each character in input:
  úíuY                       0-based index in lowercase English letters, or -1 if not found, increment, boolean negate (1 if uppercase else 0)
      "ùû"E£                 `û` if the character is lowercase else `ù` (str.lower vs str.upper)
              @ùRZ         make the other copy of the input lowercase, reverse it, and zip it with the map result
                  `i@ƒ`M   for each (string, function) pair:
                   i@ƒ       flatten, swap, apply (apply the function to the string)
                        Σ  concatenate the strings
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>83</s> <s>80</s> <s>75</s> 71 bytes

The most straightforward way I could think of.

```
import Data.Char
f a|isUpper a=toUpper|1>0=toLower
zipWith f<*>reverse
```

Comment: If you swap the parameters of `(#)`, `k` can be rewritten in point-free style: `k=reverse>>=zipWith(#)`, that saves a couple bytes :)

Comment: The second line can be point-free in `b` as `f a|isUpper a=toUpper|1>0=toLower`, though this conflicts with Flonk's improvement.

Comment: You can use xnor's version of `f` and rewrite Flonk's `k` to `zipWith f<*>reverse`.

Comment: Don’t you need to eliminate the parameter `s`?

Comment: Yes, and you're also allowed to cut the `k=`.

Comment: Sure, I copied the wrong verision,thanks

Answer (score 3):

## TSQL, 175 bytes

Golfed:

```
DECLARE @ varchar(99)='Hello, Midnightas'

,@o varchar(99)='',@i INT=0WHILE @i<LEN(@)SELECT
@i+=1,@o+=IIF(ascii(x)=ascii(lower(x)),lower(y),upper(y))FROM(SELECT
SUBSTRING(@,@i+1,1)x,SUBSTRING(@,len(@)-@i,1)y)z
PRINT @o
```

Ungolfed

```
DECLARE @ varchar(99)='Hello, Midnightas'

,@o varchar(99)=''
,@i INT=0

WHILE @i<LEN(@)
  SELECT @i+=1,@o+=IIF(ascii(x)=ascii(lower(x)),lower(y),upper(y))
  FROM
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(@,@i+1,1)x,SUBSTRING(@,len(@)-@i,1)y)z

PRINT @o
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508510/reverse-a-string-while-maintaining-the-capitalization-in-the-same-places)**

Comment: hardcoding the input ?

Comment: @cat that is the only way. In sql, there is no STDIN or input command. If you look at stackoverflow that is how all the questions are solved - you can also look at my other answers on codegolf

Comment: Oh, yeah, I definitely remember having this conversation wih a SQL user before (you, maybe). That's weird, but should be fine.

Comment: @cat we have not had this conversation before, but you did help me with a byte count earlier

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <s>154</s>, <s>152</s>, <s>99</s>, 86 bytes

Thank you @TimmyD for saving me a whopping 47 bytes (I also saved an additional 6)

Thank you @TessellatingHeckler for saving an additional 13 bytes.

Latest:

```
param($a)-join($a[$a.length..0]|%{("$_".ToLower(),"$_".ToUpper())[$a[$i++]-in65..90]})
```

Original:

```
param($a);$x=0;(($a[-1..-$a.length])|%{$_=$_.tostring().tolower();if([regex]::matches($a,"[A-Z]").index-contains$x){$_.toupper()}else{$_};$x++})-join''
```

Normal formatting:

Latest (looks best as two lines in my opinion):

```
param($a)
-join($a[$a.length..0] | %{("$_".ToLower(), "$_".ToUpper())[$a[$i++] -in 65..90]})
```

Explanation:

```
param($a)-join($a[$a.length..0]|%{("$_".ToLower(),"$_".ToUpper())[$a[$i++]-in65..90]})
param($a)
# Sets the first passed parameter to variable $a
         -join(                                                                      )
# Converts a char array to a string
               $a[$a.length..0]
# Reverses $a as a char array
                               |%{                                                  }
# Shorthand pipe to foreach loop
                                  ("$_".ToLower(),"$_".ToUpper())
# Creates an array of the looped char in lower and upper cases
                                                                 [$a[$i++]-in65..90]
# Resolves to 1 if the current index of $a is upper, which would output "$_".ToUpper() which is index 1 of the previous array
```

Original:

```
param($a)
$x = 0
(($a[-1..-$a.length]) | %{
    $_ = $_.tostring().tolower()
    if([regex]::matches($a,"[A-Z]").index -contains $x){
            $_.toupper()
        }else{
            $_
        }
        $x++
    }
) -join ''
```

First time poster here, was motivated because I rarely see PowerShell, <s>but at <s>154</s> 152 bytes on this one... I can see why!</s> Any suggestions appreciated.

I have learned that I must completely change my way of thinking to golf in code and its fun!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! This is great!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice to see another PowerShell user around here. You can cut out quite a bit by replacing the `.tostring()` with quotes, and by using ASCII integer manipulation rather than regex. Try the following, for **105 bytes** -- `param($a)-join($a[$a.length..0]|%{if(($x=$a[$i++])-le90-and$x-ge65){"$_".ToUpper()}else{"$_".ToLower()}})`.

Comment: Brilliant! We can make that even shorter by using a range instead of -le and -ge: `param($a)-join($a[$a.length..0]|%{if(65..90-contains$a[$i++]){"$_".ToUpper()}else{"$_".ToLower()}})`

Comment: `X-inY` is shorter than `Y-containsX`, and you can change your `if` for the [fake ternary operator](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79895/571) to get **86 bytes** - `param($a)-join($a[$a.length..0]|%{("$_".ToLower(),"$_".ToUpper())[$a[$i++]-in65..90]})`

Comment: Man, I feel like I've missed out on a lot of tricks having never code golfed before. Its almost like learning to code all over again!

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 12 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
⌽f¨⍨⊢≠f←819⌶
```

`819⌶` is the case folding function

`f←` because its name is long, we assign it to *f*

`⊢≠f` Boolean where text differs from lower-cased text

`f¨⍨` use that (1 means uppercase, 0 means lowercase) to fold each letter...

`⌽` ... of the reversed text

Handles non-ASCII according to the Unicode Consortium's rules.

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 22 bytes

```
q_W%.{el\'[,65>&{eu}&}
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q_W%25.%7Bel%5C'%5B%2C65%3E%26%7Beu%7D%26%7D&input=Hello%2C%20Midnightas)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>86</s> 85 bytes

```cs
s=>string.Concat(s.Reverse().Select((c,i)=>s[i]>96?char.ToLower(c):char.ToUpper(c)));
```

A C# lambda where the input and the output is a string. You can try it on [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0NjPq2).

---

<s>I am struggling to understand why I cant achieve to convert `char.ToLower(c)` to `c+32`. I hope to fix it!</s>

12 bytes saved thanks to @PeterTaylor (`c|32` to add 32 to the ascii value of `c` and `c&~32` to substract 32). The result would be 72 bytes (but can fail on non alpha char).

```cs
s=>string.Join("",s.Reverse().Select((c,i)=>(char)(s[i]>96?c|32:c&~32)));
```

Comment: It would be `c|32` instead of `c+32`, but it won't work with non-alpha characters.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 146 bytes

```
(λ(s)(build-string(string-length s)(λ(n)((if(char-upper-case?(string-ref s n))char-upcase char-downcase)(list-ref(reverse(string->list s))n)))))
```

Racket is bad at this whole "golfing" thing.

*Shrug*  As always, any help with shortening this would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Tips for golfing in Racket / Scheme](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77129/tips-for-golfing-in-racket-scheme)

Answer (score 2):

## Jolf, 21 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=zpxpZD8mzrMuX3BYaVM9cHhISHB4zrPOsw&input=SGVsbG8sIE1pZG5pZ2h0YXMKCi5R)

```
Μid?&γ._pXiS=pxHHpxγγ
```

### Explanation

```
Μid?&γ._pXiS=pxHHpxγγ
Μid                   (Μ)ap (i)nput with (d)is fucntion:
   ?        =pxHH     (H is current element) if H = lowercase(H)
    &γ._pXiS          and set γ to the uppercase entity in the reversed string
                 pxγ  lowercase γ
                    γ else, return γ
```

Comment: `(d)is function`... Sacrifice spelling for the sake of golf!

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 29 bytes

```perl6
$_=get;put .flip.samecase($_)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
ŒlðUŒuT}¦n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opJzDG0KPTioNqT20LO////8eQPF8HQXfzJS8zPSMksRiAA)

Did I say this was extremely golfable by someone who understands `¦`? Turns out it's just understanding anything at all about chaining in general.

```
Œl            Lowercase the input,
   U          reverse it,
    Œu        then uppercase it
      T}¦     at indices where
  ð      n    the lowercase input doesn't equal the original input.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, <s>9</s> 2 bytes

```
Ṙ•
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwi4bmY4oCiIiwiIiwiSGVsbG8iXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>114</s> <s>92</s> 78 bytes

```julia
~x=(b=reverse(lowercase(x));prod(i->b[i]-32('@'<x[i]<'['<b[i]-5<'v'),keys(b)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CViPJtii1LLWoOFUjJ788tSg5Eciq0NS0LijKT9HI1LVLis6M1TU20lB3ULepALJt1KPVbcCCpjbqZeqaOtmplcUaSZqamv8dijPyyxXqlDxSc3LydRR8M1PyMtMzShKLlbhgUnqBCHZilWMUgucIBA7RCdVK/wE)

- -22 bytes thanks to amelies: use `prod`
- -10 bytes thanks to MarcMush: avoid `uppercase` and `isuppercase`
- -4 bytes thanks to MarcMush: use `keys(b)` instead of `1:length(b)`

Comment: Various tweaks to get to 93 bytes

https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CViPJNie/PLUoObE4VU@jKLUstag4VaNCU9O6oCg/RSNT1y6zuLSgAKJAoyI6M1ZTwV4BIZIEFrFSANE6hlY5qXnpJRkaSZqamv8dijPyyxXqlDxSc3LydRR8M1PyMtMzShKLlbhgUnqBSv8B

Comment: 78 bytes by avoiding `(is)uppercase` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CViPJtii1LLWoOFUjJ788tSg5Eciq0NS0LijKT9HI1LVLis6M1TU20lB3ULepALJt1KPVbcCCpjbqZeqaOtmplcUaSZqamv8dijPyyxXqlDxSc3LydRR8M1PyMtMzShKLlbhgUnqBCHZilWMUgucIBA7RCdVK/wE "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>73, 65</s>  64 bytes

```julia
!s=prod(titlecase(s[end-i+1]^2)[2-('@'<s[i]<'[')] for i=keys(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcqxDsIgEADQ3a@44gDE1qSd26SDg4uDcSSYEIvl9ATTw6hfj5NvfrcXoWs/pVQ8PJc0qYyZ/MWxV2x8nBrctPbcadM1So6yZ4O2l0ZqC9e0AA53/2XFWpeRQ3pDJfaeKNVwwCniHLJjAWs4uRxmjDt8QJ2IfFj9@/Yoyg8)

-9 MarcMush

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcqxDsIgEADQ3a@44gDE1qSd26SDg4uDcSSYEIvl9ATTw6hfj5NvfrcXoWs/pVQ8PJc0qYyZ/MWxV2x8nBrctPbcadM1So6yZ4O2l0ZqC9e0AA53/2XFWpeRQ3pDJfaeKNVwwCniHLJjAWs4uRxmjDt8QJ2IfFj9@/Yoyg8 "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 139 bytes

```c
#define B v[c+~i]
#define C(x,y)isupper(x)?toupper(y):tolower(y)
i,t,c;f(char*v){for(c=strlen(v);i<c/2;i++)t=C(B,v[i]),v[i]=C(v[i],B),B=t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NasMwEITveoqFXKRYbWmPVdyCc8kb9GB8cPXjLCiSkWUlIaSv7spOA6F7mJ35GJaVT52U07RS2qDTUEGqZfGDDbmTLT3xM8Nh7Hsd6Il9Rn@zZ/YevfXHxRLkkUthqNy3YZ3YxfhAZTnEYLWjiQncyJc3gUXBYrmlFU81NmzRHOfFK8arMorrtEIn7ag0bIaoLH4/7z/IIwvouv9MoZ8RugiHFh2dTRs6yWF@CNbZp7ph5EIgz43lS1BCVjX2dCm8NkyQpWFo5vfQj3F4zCZo/ZevME07ba2HLx@s@gU)

Comment: [134 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY5Ba4QwEIXv@RUDC5JsY0v1ttYW3Ev/QQ/iwSZRB9IoMYqy3f3rNtl2Yekc3rz38RhGxK0Q27aTqkGjoIC5FA8XrMiNHOnCV4ZjrYeupguLoiVKk7f1O00Oa3RJE06QOy6yhoqutvuZnZreUpGPzmpl6Mw45uIpyTCOM@byIy34XGLFgvgUFi9YkbvsvO3QCD1JBS@jkxo/H7tXcs8smvY/k9gHhMbBV42GBlPbVnAI/8De@7msGDkR8PPL/CXIwaucBnotPFcsI9dGQz2/hWFy431urFJ/@Qzb9q607uGjt1r@AA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <s>51</s> 50 bytes

<s>`@(s)merge(isupper(s),b=flip(toupper(s)),tolower(b))`</s>

```matlab
@(s)merge(s>64&s<91,b=flip(toupper(s)),tolower(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 128 bytes

```
$s=$argv[1];$l=strrev($s);for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);++$i){echo(strtolower($s[$i])!==$s[$i]?strtoupper($l[$i]):strtolower($l[$i]));}
```

I may attempt to optimize this further but I'll just leave it as is for now.

Comment: As notices are allowed, there are a few parts you can optimize at. Instead of a for loop, you can do a while loop and set the char to test directly: `while($a=ord($s[$i++]))`. With that, as we use `ord()` you can test based on the char number: `$a<90&&$a>65`. However, for the strtoupper and lower you need to correct the index number as in the loop it was already increased, this means: `strtolower($l[$i-1])`. This should save quite some bytes

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (using external library) (224 bytes)

```
(s)=>{t=_.From(s);var cnt=t.Count();var caps=t.Select(x=>{return x.toUpperCase()===x&&x.toLowerCase()!==x}).ToArray(),i=-1;return t.AggregateRight((a,b)=>{i++;var c=caps[i];return c?a+b.toUpperCase():a+b.toLowerCase()},"");}
```

Disclaimer: Using a library I wrote to bring C#'s LINQ to Javascript

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Calling out the person who downvoted this without an explanation. Any reason for that?

Comment: It's likely that they wanted you to count the library as well, although using an external library is fully within the boundaries of standard policy.

Comment: I'm not downvoter, but If you are using an external library, at least mention the name in your answer, and for an obscure library, please provide a link to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

## VIM, 46 bytes

It'd be three bytes `g~G` if we didn't need to read from stdin or write to stdout, but oh well...

```
vim -es '+normal! g~G' '+%print|q!' /dev/stdin
```

To test this, run

```
echo "testString" | vim -es '+normal! g~G' '+%print|q!' /dev/stdin
```

This is my first submission on here, not sure if this kind of submission is acceptable.

Comment: Nice, I love golfing in vim! However, this program doesn't actually reverse the string, it just toggles the capitalization. You can reverse the string with `:se ri<cr>C<C-r>"` but then you'll have to figure how to capitalize the right letters.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan Oh man I completely missed that! Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>221</s> <s>217</s> 180 bytes

```
void c(char[]s){int x=0,y=s.length-1;for(char t;x<y;s[x]=s(t,s[y]),s[y]=s(s[y],t),x++,y--)t=s[x];}char s(char a,char b){return(char)(64<a&a<91?96<b&b<123?b-32:b:64<b&b<91?b+32:b);}
```

Loads of bytes saved thanks to *@LeakuNun*'s approach.

**Ungolfed & test cases:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/oqyLIU)

```
class Main{
  void c(char[] s){
    int x = 0,
        y = s.length-1;
    for(char t; x < y; s[x] = s(t, s[y]),
                       s[y] = s(s[y], t),
                       x++,
                       y--){
       t = s[x];
    }
  }

  char s(char a, char b){
    return (char)(64 < a & a < 91
                    ? 96 < b & b < 123
                        ? b-32
                        : b
                    : 64 < b & b < 91
                        ? b+32
                        : b);
  }

  public static void main(String[] a){
    print("Hello, Midnightas");
    print("TEST");
    print("test");
    print("Test");
    print(".,..,,!@");
    print("ABCDefgHijklMNOPqrsTuVWxyz");
    print("AbCdEfGHIJKlmnop123");
  }
  
  static void print(String s){
    char[] t = s.toCharArray();
    c(t);
    System.out.println(t);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
SathginDim ,olleh
q.
TSET
tset
Tset
@!,,..,.
ZYXWvutSrqpoNMLKjihGfEDcba
321pOnMLKJIhgfedcba
```

Comment: You can input and output `char[]`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Actually I (believe I) can't in less amount of bytes. It would allow the removal of `String a="";` and changed `o+=` to `0[i]=` to save bytes, but Java doesn't have a character `.toUpperCase()` / `.toLowerCase()` method, and converting from char to String, use upper/lower method, and then back to char again would require (a lot) more bytes. But feel free to fork the linked ideone and come up with something to make `char[]` work in less bytes.

Comment: [180 bytes](http://ideone.com/2FRdyc) that can be golfed further (by not modifying it in place).

Answer (score 1):

## Sed, 113 + 1 = 114 bytes

Why? Because it's fun to use the *wrong* tool to do things :P

Usage: Run `sed -rf file`, enter text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (send EOF).

Golfed:

```
s/[A-Z]/\a\l&/g;s/^.*$/\f&\v/;:x;s/\f\a/\a\f/;s/\a\v/\v\a/;s/\f(.)(.*)(.)\v/\3\f\2\v\1/;tx;s/\f|\v//g;s/\a./\U&/g
```

Ungolfed:

```
s/[A-Z]/\a\l&/g #Prepend all upper-case letters with a 
                #BEL ASCII character and make them lowercase
s/^.*$/\f&\v/   #Wrap text between a from feed (\f) and a vertical tab (\v)
                #These are used as markers

:x #Define a label named x

s/\f\a/\a\f/;s/\a\v/\v\a/ #Move BEL characters outside of the boundary, so they're not moved later
s/\f(.)(.*)(.)\v/\3\2\1/  #This part does the switching itself
                          #It grabs a character preceded by a form feed and another 
                          #one followed by a vertical tab and swaps them, while keeping the text in-between
                          #and replaces the marker \f and \v

tx             #Conditional jump (t) to label x
               #Jumps to the label x if the last substitution (s command) was successful 
s/\f|\v//g     #Delete markers
s/\a(.)/\u\1/g #Make letters preceded by a BEL upper-case
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 132 Bytes

```
function(s)o=""i=0 for m in s:gmatch(".")do n=s:sub(#s-i,#s-i)l=m:lower()o=o..(m==l and n:lower()or n:upper())i=i+1 end print(o)end
```

There might be a better way to do this in lua, but I think this works.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 64 bytes

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Coos)

```
->s{i=0;s.gsub(/./){c=s[i-=1];$&=~/[A-Z]/?c.upcase: c.downcase}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 24 bytes

```
{b?UCaa}MZLCRVa(_NAZ Ma)
```

Gets a binary array for the uppercase indices and uppercases those places in the reversed lowercase string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/Osk@1DkxsdY3ysc5KCxRI97PMUrBN1Hz////Hqk5Ofk6Cr6ZKXmZ6RklicUA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
Âls€.uÅÏu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cFNO8aOmNXqlh1sP95f@/@@RmpOTr6Pgm5mSl5meUZJYDAA)

**Commented:**

```
Â          # Push input and input reversed
 l         # lowercase reversed input
  s        # swap to normal input
   €.u     # map is_upper
      ÅÏ   # where this is true,
           # apply to the reversed input:
        u  # uppercase
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
£ÔgY mvc-X¦v
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=o9RnWSBtdmMtWKZ2&input=IkhlbGxvLCBNaWRuaWdodGFzIg)

```
£ÔgY mvc-X¦v     :Implicit input of string U
£                :Map each character X at 0-based index Y
 Ô               :  Reverse U
  gY             :  Get the character at index Y
     m           :  Map
      v          :    Literal "v"
       c-        :    Reduce charcode by
         X¦      :      X does not equal
           v     :      Its lowercase
                 :(This results in mapping the character by either "v",
                 : which is Japt's lowercase method or "u",
                 : which is Japt's uppercase method)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 62 bytes

```arturo
$->s[i:0map reverse lower s'c[if<=>s\[i]`A``Z`->upper'c'i+1c]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Ye1pKi)

Takes a string, returns a list of characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore C64 (just for fun/non-competing), 194 Tokenised BASIC Bytes

To enter this on a real C64, you must use [BASIC keyword abbreviations](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/BASIC_keyword_abbreviation), as you are not able to enter more than 80 characters onto a C64 BASIC line though once entered the interpreter will show the keywords in full. The listing is shown as abbreviations with switched character modes to upper/lower case. You may do this by pressing SHIFT + C=. The program will switch modes anyway on line 0 with the control character N (achieved by pressing `CTRL+N` after the opening quote).

```
0input"{CTRL+N}";a$:ifa$=""tHeN
1l=len(a$):dIp(l),b(l):fOx=1tol:p(x)=aS(mI(a$,x,1))>127:nE:i=1:fOx=lto1stE-1
2b(i)=aS(mI(a$,x,1))aN127:i=i+1:nE:fOx=1tol
3ifb(x)>64tH?cH(b(x)-128*p(x));
4ifb(x)<65tH?cH(b(x));
5nE
```

**Note** I've marked this as non-competing because whilst the character encoding on the Commodore C64 (PETSCII) is compatible with ASCII, it is not ASCII. As this question is six years old at the time of writing, and the questioner has left, I'm sure no one will mind.

Some caveats, string handling with the `INPUT` command has some limitations. For instance, if you wanted to enter `Hello, World!` as a test, you would need to enter it starting with a double quotation mark, so `"Hello, World!"`.

A quick explanation:

- Line 0 switches the character set to upper/lower case, rather than PETSCII graphics mode, and waits for a user input; if there is an empty string entered then the program terminates. I added this otherwise it will error, as the `FOR/NEXT` loops are expecting at least one character to iterate over.
- Line 1 will set l to the length of the string, and set up two numeric arrays, called `p(l)` and `b(l)`. `p(l)` is used for determines whether the positional character is upper case or not, by checking if the character code is 128 or more. If so, a `-1` is added to the array at position `x`, otherwise it is `0`. When that loop ends, we set variable `i` to `1`, and start a new loop counting down from the string length to 1.
- Line 2 sets the array `b(l)` at position `i` to the PETSCII character code; this value is `AND`ed with 127 so that each position will be the lower-case character code. `i` is then incremented by `1` and the loop ends. We then set up a final `FOR/NEXT` loop, again counting up from 1 to `l`.
- Line 3 checks if array position `b(x)` is 65 or greater (this is for characters `a` - `z` inclusive). If so, it prints the character -128 multiplied by the contents of `p(x)`, which is `-1` for upper-case at that position, or `0` if not. `-128*-1` will add `128` so converting the character at that position to upper case.
- Line 4 checks if array position `b(x)` has a value below 64; if so, we don't want to convert this to upper case or we will get some odd results for numbers and punctuation etc.
- Line 5 iterates the loop again until it is done. When the loop is finished, the program will end gracefully.

The screen shot below shows the BASIC program as the interpreter lists it.

This was a fun challenge and took a little while to get the logic right, so it's quite likely that there are some further optimisations to save some BASIC bytes.

[image: Reverse a string while maintaining the capitalization in the same places, Commodore C64]

Comment: I've just noticed in the screen shot, I took out the sanity check on line `0` with a `REM` statement. Comment that back in by removing this statement (if you want).

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 256 bytes

```
Function z(d)
r = Len(d)
ReDim E(1 To r)
For i = 1 To r
b = Mid(d, i, 1)
If Asc(b) > 64 And Asc(b) < 91 Then E(i) = 1
Next i
i = 1
For p = r To 1 Step -1
v = Mid(d, p, 1)
If E(i) = 1 Then z = z & UCase(v) Else z = z & LCase(v)
i = i + 1
Next p
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 133

Closing parens already discounted.

Input: `A1`

- `A2`: `=LEN(A1)`
- `B1`: `=ArrayFormula(MID(A1,1+A2-SEQUENCE(A2),1))`

  - Reverse string
- `C1`: `=JOIN(,ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(A2),1),"[A-Z]"),UPPER(B:B),LOWER(B:B))))`

  - Compare capital positions, capitalize if originally upper, lower if not. Then join. `EXACT(UPPER(...),...)` is worse because we're dealing with a range here.
  - It's a little sluggish because we don't chop off the `B:B` at the blanks.

Answer (score -1):

C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *a,*b,*c;

  a=c=strdup(argv[1]);
  b=&argv[1][strlen(a)-1];
  for(;*a;a++,b--){
    *a=(*a>='A'&&*a<='Z')?((*b>='a'&&*b<='z')?*b-32:*b):((*b>='A'&&*b<='Z')?*b+32:*b);
  }
  puts(c);
  free(c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Input should be taken from stdin.

Comment: As this is code-golf please put in the number of bytes this program would cost.

Comment: I could reduce it significantly depending on the rules, but I can't find any rules.