# Tell me my screen resolution!

Tags: code-golf

Output the device's screen resolution in the **specific** format of `[width]x[height]`(without the brackets). For example, an output could be `1440x900`.

[Here's an online tester that you can use to check your own screen resolution.](http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/)

Comment: So for all screens or only the primary screen?

Comment: @MetaColon only the primary. I forgot that secondary screens existed.

Comment: The specific output format is no fun, but it's probably too late to change now

Comment: What should the behaviour be if multiple displays are connected?

Comment: I suppose we're not allowed to first change your resolution and then tell you those values, right?

Comment: APL\360 (can only be run on IBM/360 typewriter environment), 5 bytes: `'0x0'`

Comment: What if you code for a device that only supports one screen resolution?

Comment: The edit by @Riker removed the wording *To clarify, If it's equivalent to the output from What is my screen resolution, It's valid.* That website reports `1920 x 1080` rather than `1920x1080`. Can answers separate width, height, and the **x** by spaces?

Comment: Commodore 64 Basic: `PRINT "40x25"`

Comment: I like that this one disqualifies most golfing languages and encourages people to explore the limits of practical ones.

Comment: go to http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ . now zoom out a few times (ex if on windows and firefox: ctrl+mouse_wheel_down), and press F5 : you will now "have" a much higher resolution ! ;)   I went from 1024x768 to 4267x3413 by this simple easy trick ... I wonder if that site is not tricking me into believing this

Comment: @Mark that's the text size, not resolution in pixels...

Comment: The resolution checker link from the question gives wrong resolution. 412x732 on my Nexus 5X with 1080x1920...

Answer (score 38):

## JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes

```
(_=screen)=>_.width+"x"+_.height
```

Outputs as function `return`. Add `f=` at the beginning and invoke like `f()`. Uses parameter-initializing to initialize the parameter `_` to `screen` object. The rest is self-explanatory.

```js
f=(_=screen)=>_.width+"x"+_.height
console.log(f())
```

**Note:** Passing an argument to this function will cause it to fail.

---

## JavaScript (Previous Solution), 35 bytes

```js
with(screen)alert(width+"x"+height)
```

Never thought I will one day use `with`! I don't think this can be golfed further.

Comment: If REPLs are allowed, `s=screen,s.width+"x"+s.height` (29 characters) also works.

Comment: Oooh. Good use of default argument value.

Comment: The 35-byte solution can save five bytes by not bothering to `alert`: `with(screen)(width+'x'+height)` just returns the appropriate string.

Comment: @SIGSEGV Thank you! :)

Comment: This answer is fundamentally flawed. I can cheat it by zooming my browser in and out!

Comment: @Arjun I just did. Are you calling me a liar?

Comment: @Arjun I'm using the zoom feature in the browser itself and getting anywhere from a few hundred to 4000 in width. Intriguingly the ratio seems to stay the same.

Comment: @Arjun your answer isn't giving the resolution of the PC monitor. It's giving the ratio of the browser window based on the current zoom level. At least, that's what Mozilla Firefox is doing.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It must be a bug in Firefox. The specification defines `screen.width` as the width of user's screen, and the same goes for `screen.height`. (And I was not calling you a liar, I was just saying that there  must be a misunderstanding :) ) (I advise you to check the solution in some another browser as this works perfect form me)

Comment: @Arjun nope. It seems to be a bug all over the place: https://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2013/11/screenwidth_is.html Here's the chart backing that article https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html

Comment: @TheGreatDuck That's an old post. New browsers tend to work fine. Try upgrading your browser and then running this. Probably, that will fix the problem! :)

Comment: @Arjun my browser is already upgraded to the current version. If you read that post, you'd see that the variable you are describing is being phased out as the role you expect it to be. Newer browsers are trying to make it be the resolution of the window when in full screen mode rather than the pixel count of the monitor viewing it. The point behind that is to make websites scale properly when zooming in and out.

Comment: from the article "screen.width should return the dimensions of the ideal viewport. The older implementation returns the number of physical device pixels, but that’s now seen as wrong.". Note: you are relying upon the "older implementation". Also, the charts page has this note: "Last major update on 16 October 2016.". That's only 6 months ago.

Comment: Can confirm, zooming messes things up in current versions of Firefox.

Comment: Eyy dudes use chrome firefox sux

Comment: Come on, are you guys even trying: `_=screen,_.width+"x"+_.height`, 29 bytes

Comment: `_=>outerWidth+'x'+outerHeight` for 29 bytes, only works in browser JS environments

Comment: @BassdropCumberwubwubwub That returns the browser width and height, not the monitor resolution.

Answer (score 34):

## TI-BASIC, <s>30</s> <s>32</s> 29 bytes (non-competing?)

*sigh* TI-BASIC takes an extra byte for every lowercase letter.

+2 thanks to [@Timtech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10740/timtech)

-3 thanks to [@Timtech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10740/timtech)

```
:If ΔX>.1
:Then
:Disp "96x64
:Else
:Disp "320x240
```

This only works because TI-BASIC can only be run on calculators with two different screen resolutions: 96 by 64 and 320 by 240. I just test to see which screen I have by setting the Zoom to something that is different depending on screen resolution then outputting the correct resolution.

I'm marking this as non-competing for now, since it is hard coded.

Comment: Thats a clever abuse ;)

Comment: You can save by not using `ZDecimal` and then using a different `Xmax` comparison, at least one byte. Also, I think you need to use lowercase `x` which is two bytes (x2) instead of the one-byte uppercase equivalent.

Comment: @Timtech I have to use a two byte Zoom (like `ZDecimal`) because the default zoom (`ZStandard`) is the same on both calculators. I'll fix the capitalization, though.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. If you use `ZStandard` though, would `ΔX` be different then between the calculators? Also, `ZDecimal` is only one byte, so this is 31 bytes.

Comment: Ah. You're right. `ΔX` is different on the calculators. Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, my instant reaction is "that's valid, but wouldn't be valid if there were only one possible screen resolution", but that point of view seems internally inconsistent. So I'm really unsure as to whether this is cheating or not.

Comment: You don't have to use the lowercase 'x' since lowercase letters aren't usable out of the box (at least for TI-83/84, which I assume this answer applies to).

Comment: @Jakob Lowercase letters are possible on TI 84 CE's, they're just two bytes apiece. OP specified that this challenge is case sensitive.

Answer (score 20):

## JavaScript (ES6), 32 bytes

```
_=>(s=screen).width+'x'+s.height
```

```js
console.log((_=>(s=screen).width+'x'+s.height)())
```

Comment: the lambda version is acceptable

Comment: `_=>(s=screen).width+'x'+s.height` saves a byte

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Thanks, the thought just occurred to me as well :)

Comment: Good job! +1 :)

Comment: I love how all the JS entries have been consistently shorter than a large number of the other answers. Almost never happens.

Answer (score 11):

## macOS, bash, awk, <s>grep, tr, 51</s> 52 bytes

```
/*/*/sy*r SPDisplaysDataType|awk '/so/{print$2$3$4}'
```

Runs `system_profiler`, gets the `SPDisplaysDataType` information, searches for the first `so` in `Resolution`, and prints the screen resolution. For multiple screens, this prints all resolutions.

[image: Example of the command running.]

---

The prior, malcompliant variant:

```
/*/*/sy*r SPDisplaysDataType|grep so|tr -d 'R :a-w'
```

Comment: I just ran this on my MacBook Pro with a second display attached. I got `2880x1800\n1920x1080@60Hz` (two lines). I don't know if that disqualifies this... or?

Comment: @Floris did OP specify how to behave when there are multiple screens?

Comment: No - but the format `@60Hz` is clearly not in spec.

Comment: I guess you could tack on a `|sed 1q`, bringing the byte count up to 58 bytes.

Comment: I fixed the non-compliance by switching to `awk` and having one extra byte. :)

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript, 36 bytes

```js
s=screen;alert(s.width+"x"+s.height)
```

Answer (score 9):

## Processing 3, 37 bytes

```java
fullScreen();print(width+"x"+height);
```

`fullScreen()` causes the app to launch with the maximum dimensions - the display resolution.
One byte less than the obvious

```java
print(displayWidth+"x"+displayHeight);
```

Answer (score 9):

## AutoHotKey, 34 bytes

```
SysGet,w,0
SysGet,h,1
Send,%w%x%h%
```

Save this in a file with extension .AHK and run it from a command prompt

Comment: Why not use `Send` rather than `MsgBox`?

Comment: @EngineerToast thanks! That saved two bytes

Answer (score 7):

## PowerShell, <s>67</s> <s>60</s> 55 Bytes

-7 thanks to [Martin Ender](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37106916#37106916)

-5 (actually 12!) from [Leaky Nun](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37107030#37107030) , Regex wizardry is beyond me.

This is long but not longer than the horrendous `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize` solution

```
(gwmi win32_videocontroller|% v*n)-replace" |x \d+\D+$"
```

first we `Get-WmiObject`(`gwmi`) to retrieve the `Win32_VideoController` object, which contains a member named `VideoModeDescription`, which is a string in the format of `1920 x 1080 x 4294967296 colors`, then I run a regex replace to get correct format.

```
PS H:\> (gwmi win32_videocontroller|% v*n)-replace" |x \d+\D+$"
1920x1080
```

Comment: I think `(gwmi win32_videocontroller|% v*n)-replace" |x[^x]+$"` shaves a couple of bytes by tweaking the regex.

Answer (score 7):

## C (Windows), <s>79</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

*Thanks to @Johan du Toit for saving a byte!*

```
#import<windows.h>
#define G GetSystemMetrics
f(){printf("%dx%d",G(0),G(1));}
```

Comment: I was still messing around with 'GetDeviceCaps' until I saw your answer :-) You can still save 1 byte by using the following: `#define G GetSystemMetrics
f(){printf("%dx%d",G(0),G(1));}`

Answer (score 6):

## Bash + xrandr, 44 characters

```
read -aa<<<`xrandr`
echo ${a[7]}x${a[9]::-1}
```

`xrandr` belongs to the X server, on Ubuntu is provided by [*x11-xserver-utils*](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/x11-xserver-utils/filelist) package.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ read -aa<<<`xrandr`;echo ${a[7]}x${a[9]::-1}
1920x1080
```

### xrandr + grep + util-linux, 30 characters

```
xrandr|grep -oP '\d+x\d+'|line
```

Thanks to:

- [Markasoftware](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/10973/markasoftware) for the regular expression (-11 characters)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ xrandr|grep -oP '\d+x\d+'|line
1920x1080
```

Comment: I have no bash with a display, would `xrandr|grep *` work?

Comment: Sure. But for now the my `grep` and `sed` attempts to parse `xrandr`'s output (https://pastebin.com/uTVcjWCq) were longer.

Comment: Maybe `xrandr|grep *|cut -d' ' -f1`? (using the matching line from your paste @[TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@19hq66goGBoaWRQYWhgYaAAAmYGegYGWtoKCqYgBkjE1FLP0kRBQZ0rNTkjX0Gloia9KLVAQasmubREQTdFXUFdQTfN8P9/AA))

Comment: Ah, you mean to pick the resolution from the list by the “*” mark? Thought to that possibility, but I am not sure whether would work with multiple displays connected. As I remember, that would list each connected display's current resolution.

Comment: Ah yes it would, not sure what the OP wants in such a scenario though!

Comment: @JonathanAllan No, it wouldn't. An unescaped `*` is a glob that the shell expands to all files in the CWD.

Comment: ...update `xrandr|grep *` will "work" if the  CWD is empty.

Comment: 34 chars: `xrandr|grep -oP '\d+x\d+(?=.+\*)'` or `xrandr|grep -oP '\d+x\d+'|head -1`

Comment: Thank you, @Markasoftware, but actually those are 33 characters. ☺

Comment: And thank you, @manatwork, for letting me learn about `line` :)

Answer (score 6):

## Java 7, <s>123</s> 114 bytes

```
String f(){java.awt.Dimension s=java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();return s.width+"x"+s.height;}
```

This method will not work in a headless installation of Java (like on TIO) because it uses the awt libraries. Under the hood, calling `getScreenSize` uses the Java Native Interface to call out (typically into a C library) for the screen width and screen height.

-9 bytes thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire) for reminding me that I can return the string instead of printing it.

Comment: I was just about to post...

Comment: @LeakyNun You and me both. +1 _Poke_.

Comment: Too bad the output is restricted to `...x...`, because `void f(){System.out.print((java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()+"").replaceAll("[^\\d,]",""));}` which outputs `1920,1200` is shorter..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yeah I did try playing with that as well. The real "too bad" is that using regex in java is so heavy in terms of byte count.

Comment: @Poke You're indeed right. I have been able to use that what I show above with an `x` instead of `,` by using some regex replacement, but it's five bytes more than your current answer: `void f(){System.out.print((java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()+"").replaceAll("[^\\d,]","").replace(",","x"));}` or `void f(){System.out.print((java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()+"").replaceAll(".*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+).*","$1x$2"));}` Ah well, what isn't heavy in Java.. ;p

Comment: If you return a `String` instead of printing it, you could reduce it to 114 bytes. Going Java 8? The regex solution is the shortest with 103 bytes. I don't get why you limit yourself to Java 7 and printing on standard output: the challenges accept both Java 8's lambdas and value-returning functions. You should embrace them instead of gimping yourself with older versions.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Good point on returning... Not sure why I went with printing. Also I did forget to include the version!

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I'm not a big fan of Java lambdas in golfing because it's not something you can drop into any old class and have it work. It's similar to imports which we as a community agree are required to be explicitly stated. I know there are meta posts on the subject but if I just stick to Java 7 then I can avoid the situation all together.

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>101</s> <s>95</s> 89 bytes

```
_=>{var s=System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;return s.Width+"x"+s.Height;};
```

-6 bytes thanks to *@TheLethalCoder* by reminding me OP didn't mention about printing, so returning a string is also fine. And an additional -6 bytes by changing it to a lambda.

Comment: You can save 11 bytes by compiling to a `Func<string>`: `()=>{var s=System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;return s.Width+"x"+s.Height;};`. However, you have a return of `void` but you are returning a `string` so you need to add 2 bytes for that.

Comment: The challenge also doesn't state that you can't take input so you could add an unused input to save another byte i.e. `_=>{var s=System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;return s.Width+"x"+s.Height;};`

Comment: Oh ignore the return comment you're writing the result out, you can save 6 bytes by returning it.

Comment: And unless you can think of a way to get it shorter `var s=System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;` would also be the same count but you could golf it with that idea in mind.

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, 51 bytes

```
SystemInformation[][[1,5,2,1,2,1,2,2,;;,2]]~Infix~x
```

This may not work for you depending on what devices you have connected (I don't know). This should always work (assuming you have at least one screen hooked up):

```
Infix[Last/@("FullScreenArea"/.SystemInformation["Devices","ScreenInformation"][[1]]),x]
```

### Explanation

`SystemInformation[]` returns an expression of the form

```
SystemInformationData[{
  "Kernel" -> {__},
  "FrontEnd" -> {__},
  "Links" -> {__},
  "Parallel" -> {__},
  "Devices" -> {__},
  "Network" -> {__},
}]
```

We are interested in `"Devices"`, which can be accessed directly as `SystemInformation["Devices"]` or as `SystemInformation[][[1,5,2]]`. The result will be a list of the form

```
{
  "ScreenInformation" -> {__},
  "GraphicsDevices" -> {__},
  "ControllerDevices" -> {__}
}
```

We want `"ScreenInformation"`, which can be accessed either as `SystemInformation["Devices","ScreenInformation"]` or more succinctly as `SystemInformation[][[1,5,2,1,2]]`. The result will be of the form

```
{
  {
  "ScreenArea" -> {__},
  "FullScreenArea" -> {{0,w_},{0,h_}},
  "BitDepth" -> _,
  "Resolution" -> _
  },
  ___
}
```

The length of the list will be the number of screens you have connected. The first screen is `SystemInformation[][[1,5,2,1,2,1]]` and the width and height can be extracted as `SystemInformation[][[1,5,2,1,2,1,2,2,;;,2]]` Then we just insert an `Infix` `x` for the output format.

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 41 bytes

*Thanks to [@Arjun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45105/arjun) and [@StephenS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65836/stephen-s) for corrections.*

```
fprintf('%ix%i',get(0,'ScreenSize')(3:4))
```

`0` is a handle to the root graphics object. Its property `'ScreenSize'` contains the coordinates of the screen in pixels. The third and fourth entries give the desired information.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 bytes

```apl
' '⎕R'x'⍕⌽⊃⎕WG'DevCaps'
```

`⎕WG'DevCaps'` **W**indow **G**et **Dev**ice **Cap**abilitie**s**

`⊃` pick the first property (height, width)

`⌽` reverse

`⍕` format as text

`' '⎕R'x'` **R**eplace spaces with "x"s

Comment: "substitute with an "x" at position 5 (the space)" this would cause problems on a small screen, e.g. 640x480 (which VMs use)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 73 bytes

```
from ctypes import*
u=windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics;
print u(0),'x',u(1)
```

Comment: `print u(0),'x',u(1)` is smaller and his example ([link](http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/)) allows it

Comment: `To clarify, If it's equivalent to the output from What is my screen resolution, It's valid.` in that website, there is space between each part

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Updated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 24 bytes

```
Ox`ØP(s×Çn)±d+"x"+ight
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=T3hg2FAoc9fHbimxZJArIngiK5RpZ2h0&input=)

The compressed string represents `with(screen)width+"x"+height`. `Ox` evaluates this as JavaScript, and the result is implicitly printed.

Answer (score 4):

## C (SDL2 library) <s>113</s> <s>88</s> 84

(-4 chars due to @AppleShell 's help)

Yes. it compiles.

```
m[3];main(){SDL_Init(32);SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode(0,m);printf("%dx%d",m[1],m[2]);}
```

Run with : `gcc snippet.c -lSDL2 && ./a.out`

Comment: I think you can shorten this by making `m` global and omitting `int`: `m[3];main(){...`

Comment: accessing by `m+1` should be shorter than `m[1]` right? or isn't that possible in C but only in C++? surely printf has some dereference token

Comment: @gizmo unfortunately AFAIK there is no printf specifier that does such thing ..

Answer (score 4):

[`xrandr`](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html) + awk, 25 bytes

```
xrandr|awk /\*/{print\$1}
```

---

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. `grep *` expands the asterisk to all files in the directory.

Comment: @Jens Corrected. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Thanks; another hint: the proper spelling for `grep|cut` is `awk`.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It outputs `*0`. My xrandr output is `*0   3360 x 1050   ( 889mm x 278mm )  *0`.

Comment: @Jens then you need `-f2` Btw, Can you check `xrandr|awk '/\*/{print $2}'`?

Comment: That only outputs `3360`. It works only with `xrandr|awk '/*/{print $2 $3 $4}'`.

Comment: @Jens That's because your `xrandr` output `3360x1050` contains white spaces.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>61</s> 49 bytes

Thanks @Jonathan-allan, @felipe-nardi-batista

```
from Tkinter import*
print'%sx%s'%Tk().maxsize()
```

For single display setups, this matches the output from the site. This gives entire resolution for multiple displays.

Comment: `print'x'....` saves a byte

Comment: `v=Tk().maxsize()`, `print'%sx%s'%v` saves 9 bytes.

Comment: oops, and then `print'%sx%s'%Tk().maxsize()` saves another 4 >_<

Answer (score 4):

## ZX Spectrum Basic, 10 bytes

just for completeness:

```
PRINT "256x192"
```

outputs `256x192`. The Spectrum has a fixed hardwired screen resolution.

Comment: ...and uses a single byte for keywords like PRINT.

Answer (score 3):

### bash + xdpyinfo  <s>42</s>  31 bytes

```
xdpyinfo|grep dim|cut -d' ' -f7
```

From man page:

```
xdpyinfo - is  a utility for displaying information about an X server.
```

@Floris @manatwork Thanks for saving a few bytes!

Comment: Crossed out 4 is still 4 :(

Comment: There is no need for spaces around the pipes; I think is safe to search for “dim” only; you can write `-d\ ` instead of `-d' '`. Then when it comes to both `grep` for a line and `cut` a part of that line, usually is shorter with a single `awk` call: `xdpyinfo|awk '/dim/&&$0=$2'`.

Comment: I suspect you can grep something shorter than `dimensions` but I don't have `xdpyinfo` on my system...

Answer (score 2):

## Processing, 51 bytes

```
void setup(){fullScreen();print(width+"x"+height);}
```

This outputs in this format: `width height`. Also, the program creates a window that is the size of the screen you are using (because every Processing program creates a window by default) and this program just outputs the height and the width of this window/sketch.

Comment: Oh, the format is `WIDTHxHEIGHT`.

Comment: @SIGSEGV Just noticed it

Answer (score 2):

#### `xdpyinfo` + `awk`, 28 bytes

```
$ xdpyinfo|awk /dim/{print\$2}
3360x1050
```

Tested on Cygwin with dual heads.

Comment: `xdpyinfo|awk /dim/{print\$2}` takes 28 bytes not 24

Comment: @Pandya I need new glasses :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 73 bytes

```rkt
#!racket/gui
(let-values([(x y)(get-display-size #t)])(printf"~ax~a"x y))
```

Just discovered the [(discouraged) shorthand for `#lang`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._parse-reader%29). Saves a few bytes! [Documentation for `get-display-size`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Windowing_Functions.html?q=gui#%28def._%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._get-display-size%29%29).

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl/Tk, 40

```
puts [winfo screenw .]x[winfo screenh .]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, <s>218 208</s> 206 bytes

I can't golf....

```
@for /f %%# in ('"@wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution /format:value"')do @set %%#>nul
@echo %CurrentHorizontalResolution%x%CurrentVerticalResolution%
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby + xrandr, 37 bytes

```
puts `xrandr`.split[7..9].join[0..-2]
```

Alternate solution (52 bytes):

```
puts `xrandr`.match(/t (\d+) (x) (\d+),/)[1..3].join
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 116 bytes

```
((import html-toolkit)
(htmlOnLoad #::((var S(index(getWindow)screen))
(print(+(index S width)"x"(index S height))))))
```

(Line breaks added for readability)

[Try it online!](https://andrakis.github.io/ide2/index.html?code=KChpbXBvcnQgaHRtbC10b29sa2l0KShodG1sT25Mb2FkICM6OigodmFyIFMoaW5kZXgoZ2V0V2luZG93KXNjcmVlbikpKHByaW50KCsoaW5kZXggUyB3aWR0aCkieCIoaW5kZXggUyBoZWlnaHQpKSkpKSk=)

Finally, my html-toolkit module gets some use! Only works in the Try it Online link, will not work from command line.

A few bytes could be saved if `1024 x 768` could be valid output. We just use `(+ .. "x" .. )` to avoid `print`'s implicit spacing.

Comment: Hmm. I tried it online, but it says `2048x1080` for a true 4K screen that's actually `4096x2160`. Any idea why? Firefox 52.0 on FreeBSD 11.

Comment: No idea. I'm merely grabbing `window.screen` and getting the `width` and `height` attributes from it. I imagine if you opened up the Firefox console and typed in `window.screen` you'll see the apparently incorrect `2048x1080`.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua (löve framework),116 bytes

```
f,g=love.window.setFullscreen,love.graphics function love.draw()f(1)w,h=g.getDimensions()f(0>1)g.print(w.."x"..h)end
```

The programm changes first to fullscreen then it gets the width and height and prints it then :)

Answer (score 1):

#### xrandr and sh, 23 bytes

```
$ set `xrandr`;echo $6x$8
3360x1050
```

Tested on a CentOS 5 box with display redirected to a Cygwin machine with two monitors. Here the full `xrandr` output is

```
$ xrandr
 SZ:    Pixels          Physical       Refresh
*0   3360 x 1050   ( 889mm x 278mm )  *0
Current rotation - normal
Current reflection - none
Rotations possible - normal
Reflections possible - none
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash + xdotool + tr, 35 bytes

*-1 thanks to @manatwork*

```
xdotool getdisplaygeometry|tr \  x
```

There are two spaces after the `\`

Gets geometry, then uses `tr` to replace spaces with `x`

Comment: Is enough to just escape the space, is shorter than quoting it: `tr␠\␠␠x`. (Used ␠ to mark spaces here just because HTML rendering collapses consecutive whitespaces.)

Answer (score 1):

## <strike>Python 3, 54 bytes</strike>

## Python 2, <strike>52</strike> 51 bytes

```
from PIL.ImageGrab import*;print'%dx%d'%grab().size
```

Saved 2 bytes by executing in Python 2

Saved 1 byte by changing import

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't have PIL installed, so I can't test, but could you just do `i.grab().size` instead of the string formatting? I don't think it has to be *exactly* in the `WxH` format

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Hello! I thought the same thing, but OP says *specific format of [width]x[height]*. `i.grab().size` prints out a tuple as `(1920, 1080)`. Granite that would save me 8 bytes, I'd rather go for accuracy to OPs requirements

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 42 bytes

```
console.log((k=screen).width+'x'+k.height)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to our site! Make sure to include a byte count in your title for [tag:code-golf] questions.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Sorry, I didn't know it was a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/), 26 Bytes

```
system/view/screens/1/size
```

Outputs for example:

```
1920x1080
```

The code is pretty self explanatory. The `1` refers to the first screen

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, <strike>128</strike> <strike>125</strike> <strike>124</strike> 123 bytes

```
@for /f "tokens=1,2delims=x " %%A in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription^|find "l"')do @echo %%Ax%%B
```

Basically the same thing as [SteveFest's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118577/57033), except I grab a slightly shorter chunk of Wim32_VideoController and then I use something vaguely resembling regex to get the one line that contains the data that I want.

<strike>I have no idea why the `wmic` string needs to be inside of double quotes to work</strike> I needed the quotes so that I didn't need to escape the pipe, but `^` is shorter than `""`, and I can't believe that I can't shorten the wmic command at all.

### How It Works

Ordinarily, `wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription` will display something like this:

```
VideoModeDescription
3440 x 1440 x 4294967296 colors
```

I can use <strike>`findstr`'s super rudimentary attempt at regex</strike> `find` to find the letter "l," which only matches the line with the word "colors." From there, that line is delimited on spaces and the letter "x." `%%A` contains the first token and `%%B` contains the second token. After that, I just display the values.

Comment: Aw.. I've been looking for ways to shorten my code... Nice answer anyways

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 60 bytes

```
from win32api import*
u=GetSystemMetrics
print u(0),'x',u(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 90 Bytes

```cs
()=>{var b=System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;return b.Width+"x"+b.Height;};
```

This actually is quite a similiar answer to that one, which already exists, however, I'd like to add a few things. This solution acutally needs a reference to *System.Windows.Forms* and one to *System.Drawing*. Those references are not normally added for a console application, so I'm not sure wether it's valid. Therefore I wrote a solution **without references**, however this has **<strike>580</strike> 287 Bytes**:

```cs
using System;using System.Runtime.InteropServices;class P{static void Main()=>Console.Write(G().Item1+"x"+G().Item2);static(int,int)G()=>(GetSystemMetrics(0),GetSystemMetrics(1));[DllImport("User32.dll",ExactSpelling=true,CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int n);}
```

Here's the solution with line breaks:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class P
{
    static void Main() => Console.Write(G().Item1 + "x" + G().Item2);
    static (int, int) G() => (GetSystemMetrics(0), GetSystemMetrics(1));

    [DllImport("User32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int n);
}
```

This solution was created with the huge help of AdamSchiavone on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739898/c-sharp-screen-size-without-references-in-interactive/43793468#43793468).

I also wrote a **C# Interactive** programm with **123 Bytes**, which automatically adds the references, so it can be executed on every machine without problems and without having the reference problems:

```cs
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
#r "System.Drawing"
var b=System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;b.Width+"x"+b.Height
```

This basically is the same as the first one, but it adds the reference automatically and as it is executed in the interactive, you don't need the return statement, you can simply leave away the semicolon.

Comment: Your missing the `;` on the end of your func.

Comment: Side note: Those references aren't added normally for a `Console` application, they are for a `Windows Forms` one. Either way they don't need adding into the byte count.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder You're right, edited my answer.

Comment: In your large solution you can change `internal static class Program` to just `class P`, you could probably remove `static` from the methods and use `new P()`, you can change `IntPtr` to `int` I believe, Move the `i()` out of the `struct` probably, change the `struct` to a `class` and probably a couple of other things.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I'll update my answer. Unfortunately, I won't have time to do this till tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 89 bytes

```
_=>{var s=System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;return s.Width+"x"+s.Height;};
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP + GTK 2.0, 69 bytes

This whole answer was written based on http://php-gtk.eu/en/code-hints/grabbing-a-screenshot-with-gdk

```
<?list($W,$H)=Gdk::get_default_root_window()->get_size();echo$W,x,$H;
```

Basically, fetches the "root" window (entire screen) and gets it's size.

---

Another way (based on http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/sample-codes/get-the-size-of-display-screen.php):

```
<?$w=(new GtkWindow())->get_screen();echo$w->get_width(),x,$w->get_height();
```

Gets the screen where the window was created, displaying it's dimentions.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 46 bytes

```
var s=screen;console.log(s.width+'x'+s.height)
```

I wanted to write it in the comment but I don't have reputation yet. Can someone explain to me why other solutions don't count bytes for `console.log()`? If they were counted then this solution would be the shortest.

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB, 42 byte

```
a=get(0,'ScreenS');fprintf('%dx%d',a(3:4))
```

Uses [property shortening](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48268/32352). Other than that, this is a nice showcase of the inflexibility of MATLAB indexing, requiring a temporary variable `a`. `fprintf` prints to `stdout` by default.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 86 bytes

Shameless port of [this Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118411/64850)

```
(#(str(.width %1)"x"(.height %1))(.getScreenSize(java.awt.Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 32 bytes

```
0 hw:displaysize? swap . "x" . .
```

Returns the device's screen resolution of the first display (0) in pixels in the required format.

Output:

```
1536x864
```

Answer (score 0):

## VBA (32-Bit), 110 Bytes

Locally declared windows function and anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE Immediate window.

<sub>*Note: The below may be made into a 64-bit compatible function by the addition of `PtrSafe`  following `Declare`*</sub>

```vb
Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib"user32.dll"(ByVal i&)As Long
```

```vba
?GetSystemMetrics(0)&"x"&GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## VBScript, 201 bytes

```
For Each x in CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator").ConnectServer(".","root\cimv2").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM WIN32_VIDEOCONTROLLER")
a=Split(x.VideoModeDescription," x ")
msgbox a(0)&"x"&a(1)
Next
```

Connection to Local WMI is eating up all the bytes.....

Answer (score 0):

## VB6, 57 bytes

```
Sub a:Msgbox Screen.Width/15&"x"&Screen.Height/15:End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

## Bash, 21 bytes

```
tr , x</*/*/*/fb0/v*
```

If the device has frame buffer you can query `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/virtual_size` to get resolution.
Width and Height are delimited by `,` so tr translates to `x`.
Path to the file is shortened by using * to the point there are no ambiguities.

Comment: On my machine that glob also matches 4 files + 1 symlink in /usr/share/games/fortunes/vi, so I have to specify …/*0/… instead of …/f*/… (not sure whether you can count on that “0”, I'm not framebuffer fan).

Comment: That depends upon directories.

Comment: several upvoted answers do it as well, edited for a less likely to hapen option

Comment: Note that this gives the size of the console frame buffer, which for X11 is often quite different from the size of the screen you are sitting in front of when logged in over the network.

Comment: console framebuffer is fbcon, not fb0. This outputs resolution of screen connected as framebuffer device fb0.