# Tell me my console dimensions!

Tags: code-golf

Output terminal dimensions (columns and rows) [in any two-number decimal format](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118402/tell-me-my-screen-resolution#comment290065_118402)*. For example, an output could be `80x25`.

---

<sup>[Inspiration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/118402/43319). [Prompt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118402/tell-me-my-screen-resolution?noredirect=1#comment290557_118402).

<sub>* Output must have both measures on a single or two consecutive lines, and there may be no more than one leading and/or trailing line of output (optionally followed by a newline). The (up to four) lines must be no longer than max(cols,1+len(str(cols))+len(str(ro‌​ws))).</sub></sup>

Comment: I have never seen a shorter upvoted challenge. Congrats!

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I specialise in one-liners…

Comment: You are about to get a degree in one-lining posts! You are indeed good, no, very good at that :))...

Comment: what does 'consistent format' exactly means?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Same style no matter what. E.g. you cannot output `[1024,768]` on one machine, and `600x400` on another.

Comment: can there be other information along side the answer?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista No, because then one could just do a complete memory dump (the answer must be in there).

Comment: that would not be consistent tho :D

Comment: what i mean is, does `os.terminal_size(columns=80, lines=24)` counts as a constintent format (that's the output)?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista I'll say yes for now, but revert if this leads to absurdities.

Comment: @Adám I guess just answering `mode` for `cmd` is one of these absurdities? Its output is localized thought, so you might consider it not to be consistent.

Comment: @Aaron Exactly. But if you just output lines 4 and 5, you're ok.

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Maybe like this: Output must have both measures on a single or two consecutive lines, and there may be no more than one leading and/or trailing line of output. The (up to four) lines must be no longer than the terminal width.

Comment: @Adám 'The lines must not be longer than the terminal width' what if one was to shrunk the terminal to width 4 as an example? were you refering to the default terminal width?

Comment: @Adám Doesn't `len(str(cols))` already do `log_10`? Doesn't this mean that you're logging twice?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Nicely spotted. Fixed.

Answer (score 27):

## *sh, 9

```
stty size
```

Output:

```
97 364
```

Comment: Also works in bash.

Comment: Or any other shell on a posix-like system.

Comment: Given the names of some languages seen on this site, it takes longer to figure out that *sh here refers to "bash, zsh, csh, dash, etc." rather than a language whose name consists of an asterisk followed by the letters s and h :-)

Comment: Technically you don't even need a shell to run a program. So the `sh` designation doesn't really make sense anyway.

Answer (score 20):

## 8086 machine code, 11 bytes (as a function, non-competing)

Not really competing since it doesn't have visible output. This is just showing the shortest way to find the current screen dimensions, without the boilerplate code required for printing.

```
00000000  6a 40 1f a0 84 00 40 8a  26 4a 00                 |j@....@.&J.|
0000000b
```

#### How it works:

```
6a 40           |   push 0x40       ; bios data segment
1f              |   pop ds
a0 84 00        |   mov al, [0x84]  ; console rows - 1
40              |   inc ax
8a 26 4a 00     |   mov ah, [0x4a]  ; console columns
```

---

## 8086 machine code, 48 bytes (as a complete program)

```
00000000  1f bf 30 01 a0 84 04 40  e8 1a 00 b0 78 aa a0 4a  |..0....@....x..J|
00000010  04 e8 11 00 8d 8d d0 fe  8d 75 ff 06 1f fd ac cd  |.........u......|
00000020  29 e2 fb cd 20 d4 0a 0c  30 aa c1 e8 08 75 f6 c3  |)... ...0....u..|
00000030
```

#### How it works:

```
                |   org 0x100
                |   use16
1f              |       pop ds              ; clear ds (the stack always contains 0 on entry)
bf 30 01        |       mov di, d           ; set destination ptr
a0 84 04        |       mov al, [0x484]     ; console rows - 1
40              |       inc ax
e8 1a 00        |       call to_ascii       ; convert to ascii
b0 78           |       mov al, 'x'
aa              |       stosb
a0 4a 04        |       mov al, [0x44a]     ; console columns
e8 11 00        |       call to_ascii
8d 8d d0 fe     |       lea cx, [di-d]      ; number of characters to print
8d 75 ff        |       lea si, [di-1]      ; set source ptr
06              |       push es
1f              |       pop ds
fd              |       std                 ; reverse direction flag
ac              |   @@: lodsb               ; load (al = *si--)
cd 29           |       int 0x29            ; print al to console, bypassing stdout
e2 fb           |       loop @b             ; repeat while (--cx != 0)
cd 20           |       int 0x20            ; terminate
                |   
                |   to_ascii:
d4 0a           |       aam 10              ; ah = (al / 10), al = (al % 10)
0c 30           |       or al, 0x30         ; convert al to ascii number
aa              |       stosb               ; store (*di++ = al)
c1 e8 08        |       shr ax, 8           ; shift ah to al
75 f6           |       jnz to_ascii        ; repeat if non-zero
c3              |       ret
                |   
                |   d rb 0
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure a function submission would need a `ret`? Also, I'm not sure that you're allowed to clobber `ds`. This might need to be taken to Meta, as the function does work more than once, it just has unwanted side effects.

Comment: Why does "the stack always contain 0 on entry"? I don't know of any rule that the stack gets zeroed. I guess you're talking about popping the return value and thinking that's going to be 0? Is that guaranteed for a COM binary?

Comment: @CodyGray: in a COM program, the stack initially contains a near pointer to the start of the PSP (offset 0), so RET will jump back to PSP:0, which contains a call to EXIT. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12593311/371250

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification, @ninjalj. (Great answer you linked, BTW. I'd forgotten virtually all of the details about the PSP, despite having reverse-engineered its implementation many years ago.) But if you pop that pointer off the stack without pushing it back, don't you break the `RET` instruction at the end of the function?

Comment: @CodyGray: you'll note that the program exits via `INT 20h`, not via `RET`, exactly because after POPing exiting via `RET` no longer works.

Comment: @ais523, The function entry isn't really competing (and I should probably mark it as such...) since I think OP's question implies printing the result. In any case you could think of it as an inline function which doesn't need a `ret` :). About clobbering `ds`, I'm not aware of any rules that prohibit such side-effects, but feel free to discuss it on meta if you think this should be clarified.

Answer (score 18):

## Bash, <s>22</s> 20 characters

```bash
echo $COLUMNS $LINES
```

Thanks to:

- [Doorknob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3808/doorknob) for optimal output format (2 characters)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ echo $COLUMNS $LINES
80 24
```

Comment: With just 1 more byte, `echo $COLUMNS\x$LINES` can o/p `80x24`

Comment: @Pandya True, but not necessary.

Comment: Not sure if this complies with the new output format requirements, but you could just have $COLUMNS\x$LINES to output "bash: 90x50: command not found". Suppose that doesn't work with localisation though, or if that command actually exists!.

Answer (score 14):

### xterm, 6 bytes

As you don't need specific formate, you can simply use the **`resize`** (6 character) command of `xterm`:

```
$ resize
COLUMNS=120;
LINES=31;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```

Comment: Nice. But you may want to write a standard header, like `#xterm, 6 bytes`.

Comment: @Adám Is this type of output acceptable according to question?

Comment: Yes; https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118636/tell-me-my-console-dimensions/118673?noredirect=1#comment290692_118636.

Comment: @Adám ok. Just added header :)

Comment: This is not xterm-specific. Note also that the output depends on your shell.

Answer (score 13):

## sh, 20 bytes

```
tput lines;tput cols
```

.. Too obvious, maybe..

Comment: tput cols; !:0 cols saves one byte in bash

Comment: @marcos you mean `tput lines;!:0 cols`, right ?

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

```python
import os
os.get_terminal_size
```

As it does not work in TIO, an alternative is used there:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@5@ZW5BfVKJQnFFakpnDlWYLYeilp5bEl6QW5WbmJebEF2dWpf4vKMrMK9FI09DU/A8A)

Comment: Why not just `os`?

Comment: ...it wont work on TIO, due to the operating system, so need to specify. It *does* work on Windows. Also `import os` and `os.` is shorter than `from...`.

Comment: I can confirm it works on Window 10 without any modifications

Comment: Works on mac too

Comment: Technically Python 3.3+

Comment: @matsjoyce There's no need to specify that, since the current version is fine.

Comment: `os.get_terminal_size` is a function; you need to add `()` to get the actual output.

Comment: @jwodder https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7615/66418

Comment: Saying there's no need to specify version is silly - in the future this might not work with Python4, and future readers would like to know what version they need to make it work.

Comment: @JonathanHartley it's the current version of python 3, as it says in the title

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista, I guess it does say 3 in the title, I kinda spaced on that.

Answer (score 11):

## C (linux only), <s>63</s> 61

```
short m[4];main(){ioctl(0,21523,m);printf("%dx%d",*m,m[1]);}
```

Comment: You could win two bytes by replacing `m[0]` by `*m`.

Comment: You can save one byte by making `m` an argument of main: `main(short m){ioctl(0,21523,&m);printf("%dx%d",m,(&m)[1]);}`

Comment: `main(int m){ioctl(0,21523,&m);printf("%x",m);}` would be 46 bytes, with sizes printed in base 16 and no separator (other than possible leading zeroes) between cols and rows.

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

<sup>(Posting an answer already since this really isn't my challenge.)</sup>

`⎕SD` [**S**creen **D**imensions](http://help.dyalog.com/15.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/sd.htm)

Sample run:

```
      ⎕SD
25 79
```

Answer (score 8):

### C#, 59 bytes

```c#
using c=System.Console;_=>c.WindowWidth+"x"+c.WindowHeight;
```

Compiles to a `Func<int, string`, however, the input is not used.

Comment: Does not work; I found this returns the size the console would be if AllocConsole() were called, not the size the console standard input and output are actually connected to. Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688348/how-do-i-determine-size-of-ansi-terminal  What I held back when asking the question is I was actually running on a Windows environment with stdin & stdout connected to a ssh pipeline. The win32 ssh implementation does not provide the necessary.

Answer (score 7):

## NodeJS, <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
> s=process.stdout;console.log(s.columns,s.rows)
80 25
```

Uses `process.stdout`s `columns` and `rows` values.

Comment: Thanks @ETHproductions, added console.log to output to console :)

Comment: No problem :-) The output can be in any consistent format, so I think you can save a couple bytes by doing `console.log([s.columns,s.rows])`.

Comment: If space between is consistent, then console.log(s.columns,s.rows) saves two more! Thanks again!

Comment: 1 byte off: `with(process.stdout)console.log(columns,rows)`

Comment: And a few more bytes off (if this counts): `with(process.stdout)write(columns+[rows])`. Or, if it doesn't count: `with(process.stdout)write(columns+' '+rows)`

Comment: @Markasoftware Ooh, that's clever. I don't think the first one should count, though.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, <s>41</s> <s>36</s> 21 + 13 = 34 bytes

Run with the command line flag `-rio/console`

```
p IO.console.winsize
```

This is my first Ruby golf, so tell me if there is anything I can do better.

*5 bytes saved thanks to SztupY*

*2 bytes saved thanks to manatwork*

---

This outputs height then width as a length two list.

Example output:

```
[25, 80]
```

Comment: you can potentially move the requires into the -r command line parameter which is only 2 extra bytes

Comment: No need for the single quotes around `io/console`, no shell will perform undesired expansion on it if left unquoted.

Answer (score 6):

## GNU Forth, 7 bytes

```
form .s
```

> form       – urows ucols        gforth       “form”
>
> The number of lines and columns in the terminal.

### Sample Output

```
<2> 24 80
```

[Try It Online !](https://tio.run/nexus/forth-gforth#@5@WX5SroFf8/z8A)

Answer (score 4):

## Swift, 99 bytes

```
import Foundation;var w=winsize();ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO,UInt(TIOCGWINSZ),&w);print(w.ws_col,w.ws_row)
```

Thanks to the guys at Vapor for their [Console package](https://github.com/vapor/console/blob/master/Sources/Console/Terminal/Terminal.swift#L175).

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell + Mode, 11 Bytes?

Output may not be acceptable in current form.

the `mode` command is a default windows utility

[Meta Post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12268/making-assumptions-about-hardware) regarding usage of `mode` without specifying `con`

```
(mode)[3,4]
```

gets the output of mode:

```
<Whitespace>
Status for device CON:
----------------------
    Lines:          3000
    Columns:        120
    Keyboard rate:  31
    Keyboard delay: 1
    Code page:      850
```

then the 4th & 5th lines (`[3,4]`) outputting:

```
PS H:\> (mode)[3,4]
    Lines:          3000
    Columns:        120
```

Comment: Save two bytes: `(mode)[3,4]-replace"\D"`

Comment: for this to work here, i need to use `(mode con)[3..4]`

Comment: Ah @FelipeNardiBatista is probably right that you need con.

Comment: is the `-replace"\D+"` necessary?

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista is `con` neccessary? this gets the first lines absolutely, and I believe `con` is always first? i'd say a `standard` system will also only have one output for mode, which is what we should assume?

Comment: in my system, con is the last one, i get LPT1, COM3, COM2, COM1 and then CON

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista I think since a fresh install of windows with no strange hardware ~should~ only have one it probably isn't required? at least a brand new win10 vm with only the basics has nothing, my work laptop and home PC only display con too.

Comment: that's not my call, just stating what happens here

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista I can't find a meta post that clears this up at all, might make one myself regarding system architecture/hardware/assumptions.

Comment: @ConnorLSW It's just that my system does work fine, but your answer simply doesn't work here

Answer (score 4):

## C# 94 bytes (whole app)

MetaColon's whole app answer can be shortened quite a lot:

```
using c=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){c.Write(c.WindowWidth+' '+c.WindowHeight);}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Batch, <s>25</s> <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

<sub><sup>Saved 6 bytes by piping directly to the "find" command.

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Adám / OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118636/tell-me-my-console-dimensions/118681#comment290720_118681).

Saved 1 byte thanks to [comment by OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118636/tell-me-my-console-dimensions/118687#comment290692_118636).</sup></sub>

```
mode con|find "n"
```

This outputs the command itself since echo is on but, as [commented by OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118636/tell-me-my-console-dimensions/118687#comment290692_118636), a leading line is OK.

---

<sub>Depending on your setup, it may work with only 13 bytes. However, it seems that having anything using COM ports will cause overly verbose output.</sub>

```
mode|find "n"
```

Comment: Save a byte `s:` → `n`.

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Yeah, and mine says I've got 9001 lines. It's just a setting: Properties>Layout>Screen Buffer Size.

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Windows console dimensions are not the same as the window dimensions. That's why scroll bars show up when you make the window smaller. [Per OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118636/tell-me-my-console-dimensions/118681#comment290685_118636), this exact solution is OK.

Comment: @Adám Dangit, I looked for a shorter string and don't know how I overlooked it. It's probably because I started with just `mode` but found that adding ` con` was shorter than looking for two different sets of characters with `findstr`.

Comment: @Adám Based on [your comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118636/tell-me-my-console-dimensions/118687#comment290692_118636), would this be valid: `@mode|find "L" /i` ? It returns Lines, Columns, and Keyboard Delay with 17 bytes instead of the 18 above. Do those leading / trailing lines need to be empty?

Comment: Yes, but better is: `mode|find/i"n"` at only 14 bytes.

Comment: `@mode|find "L" /i` outputs 11 lines for me, and `@mode|find/i"n"`output 25 lines, with info of other devices

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Ah, it probably depends on connected devices. `mode con|find "n"` it is, then.

Comment: @EngineerToast You can remove the `@`, no?

Comment: This prints the screen buffer dimensions, not those of the console window.

Comment: is `con` definitely required? I've been using mode from multiple cli's on multiple devices for years and never gotten output other than the single device, If a 'standard' system can run it without `con` that's -4, and I think it makes sense.

Comment: @ConnorLSW It seems to also output information for anything on COM ports. as Felipe Nardi Batista [pointed out](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118636/tell-me-my-console-dimensions/118681?noredirect=1#comment290734_118681), their systems outputs a ton on information. I prefer solutions that are robust versus those that require specific setups to work, so I'll leave it as is. However, it's worth noting.

Comment: @Adám OVER 9000?!

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 85 Bytes

```cs
()=>System.Console.Write(System.Console.WindowWidth+"x"+System.Console.WindowHeight);
```

If you want a whole application code, we'd have **<strike>115 101</strike> 94 Bytes**:

```cs
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main()=>C.Write(C.WindowWidth+"x"+C.WindowHeight);}
```

However you could mean the *Buffer* size as well, we'd have **85 Bytes** again

```cs
()=>System.Console.Write(System.Console.BufferWidth+"x"+System.Console.BufferHeight);
```

Or as a whole application code (obviously **<strike>115 101</strike> 94 Bytes** again):

```cs
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main()=>C.Write(C.BufferWidth+"x"+C.BufferHeight);}
```

*Saved 14 Bytes in the whole application code with the help of Caius Jard*

Comment: 104 bytes whole app, perhaps you can extend the logic to your other variations: `using c=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){c.WriteLine(c.WindowWidth);c.Write(c.WindowHeight);}}`

Comment: (I'm not sure how to golf if I have a shorter answer; do i edit yours, comment yours, or post my own?)

Comment: @CaiusJard You could post your own answer or comment an improvement and let the answerer decide if they want to incorporate it or not.

Comment: I wanted to, just couldn't edit my comment in time... Posted my own answer (that included it) virtually simultaneously though so I prmise I wasn't nicking your inspiration :). Not too sure whether I feel it's cheating to essentially be writing a function that returns the answer, rather than a whole app - all the other answers are pretty much a whole app, but then again CSharppPad.com will accept your "sole function" version and run it.. should look up the rules on golfing i guess

Comment: @CaiusJard Functions/methods are allowed implicitly unless explicitly disallowed in the challenge itself. Therefore, an anonymous function is fine, see my answer for a version that works well.

Comment: @CaiusJard You're right. I hope you don't consider it cheated if I update my answer to your version.

Comment: if you `using System` you can shorten your answer

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista the problem is, that it wouldn't be a lambda expression anymore then - I'm not sure, wether it'd be allowed.

Comment: @MetaColon it is

Answer (score 2):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>24</s> <s>16</s> 12 bytes

*Revised after Anders Tornblad comment.*

```
con:size? .s
```

Returns the current size of the console in rows and columns printing stack content.

Output:

```
2  n: 000000000285e5e0 1   300
1  n: 000000000285e4c0 1   90
```

Comment: Since the question allows any output format, do you really need `swap`?

Comment: @Anders Tornblad - Thank you for your wise comment. I improved my code.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8 (no libraries), Windows, 270 bytes

[Posting seperately by recommendation of Adam.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58225/discussion-between-meq5anlrk3lqs3kfsa5hbvstwe0niu-and-adam)

```
interface B{static void main(String[] a)throws Exception{Object[]r=new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c mode").getInputStream())).lines().toArray();System.out.print(r[3]+"\n"+r[4]);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
interface B {
    static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        Object[] r = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c mode").getInputStream())
        ).lines().toArray();
        System.out.print(r[3] + "\n" + r[4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `cmd/c mode` instead of `cmd /c mode`.

Comment: Just tried, Runtime.exec() interprets that as trying to execute `cmd/c` resulting in `CreateProcess error=2`. :(

Answer (score 2):

## Java + *nix, 113

```
interface B{static void main(String[] a)throws Exception{new ProcessBuilder("stty","size").inheritIO().start();}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
interface B{
    static void main(String[] a)throws Exception{
        new ProcessBuilder("stty","size").inheritIO().start();
    }
}
```

`ProcessBuilder.inheritIO` causes a child process input/output to be inherited; this is the default in C with `exec`. In Java, the default is "piped." As you can see, this is way shorter than using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` (which is also deprecated) and constructing a `BufferedReader` through a long and convoluted call that is the result of the Java API designers' apparent unwillingness to add an overload for convenience.

Comment: I wish `ProcessBuilder` would work on Windows, but the `mode` command outputs more than 4 lines :(

Answer (score 1):

## C (linux, C89 only), <s>45</s> 41

inspired by https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118696/42186 by @dieter

```
main(m){ioctl(0,21523,&m);write(1,&m,4);}
```

this outputs the size as binary data. Not sure if this counts as "any format". You would need something extra (less, hexdump, od, ascii table) (or an esoteric terminal emulator that automatically does this for you) to make it human readable. Example usage:

```
$ ./a.out | od -sAn
     58    204
```

The terminal size is 204 cols by 58 rows.

Thanks to @Random832 for using `od` instead of `hexdump`.

Comment: I think hex is pushing it. All other answers use decimal, so I'm going to add this requirement to OP. Sorry.

Comment: od -s will do it in decimal and is shorter than hexdump

Comment: @Random832 Cool, didn't know that, +1! But this answer became invalid anyway, when the rules changed from "any format" to a very specific format (something like: base 10 in ascii in mainstream terminal emulators)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/), 19 Bytes

```
system/console/size
```

Output:

```
>> system/console/size
== 106x26
```

Can also get the screen resolution as in the previous [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118894/49214)

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin + [Jline 2](https://github.com/jline/jline2), 58 bytes

```
{print(jline.TerminalFactory.get().run{"$width $height"})}
```

Because why not. Turns out the standard lib [actually has no way to determine console size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1286677/7079453) so pulling in a library is required, lest you want to gold launching another process and parsing the input stream... [*would be a shame if somebody did that..*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119012/62024)

Comment: Don't put two answers in one post.

Comment: @Adám It's more of an afterthought, so I think it's fine. You have enough rep to edit it directly, do so if you really believe a 270b with arbitary restrictions should be a seperate answer.

Comment: Each submission competes against other submissions in the same language. Java is inherently verbose, but yours is the shortest (and only) Java submission. Also, while I can edit your post, I cannot post a separate answer in your name.

Comment: I was implicating that if you remove my Java answer, I will repost it myself. And while you have a point that the answer is currently the shortest Java answer, it is coded under restriction of using no external libraries. In order to address your argument, I will mark it as non-competing and code a proper Java answer later.

Comment: Post it as **Java (no libraries)** and make another submission called **Java with …**. That will get you three upvotes from me.

Comment: Posting 3 answers doesn't sound right for me. I already feel as if I'm violating implict conduct by planning to post a second one. [This meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/181/62024) suggests that I should post seperate answers **if they're interesting enough**. Java in general doesn't sound interesting to me.

Comment: Oh yes it is. I find the Java answers the most entertaining answers on PPCG. The sheer amount of typing to do simple things! And now, without libraries‽ This is great!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58225/discussion-between-meq5anlrk3lqs3kfsa5hbvstwe0niu-and-adam).

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore 64 BASIC, 7 bytes

```
?"40x25
```

The C64 has a fixed-size text console of 40 x 25 characters.  It is not necessary to query the console size, which is a good thing, as there is no way to query it.

Comment: This seems like cheating, although to be fair, the question (nor its inspiration) does not specifically prohibit it.

Comment: Relevant: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1063/43319

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 7 bytes

```
termdim
```

Leaves output on the stack, as is allowed per default. Example usage:

```
λ stacked -pe "termdim"
(117 26)
```

Bonus: `` termdim'x'#` `` to have it `117x26`.