# Loading Forever... Windows style

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, animation

Make a Windows style Loading bar by the following instructions.

<sup>(notice that this is different than [Loading... Forever](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101289/loading-forever))</sup>

Your output should start by `[....      ]`.

Every tick, you should wait 100 ms, then move each dots by one character right. if the dot is on the tenth character, move it to the first. Notice that you should clear the screen before outputting again. The output is ordered as the following:

```
[....      ]
[ ....     ]
[  ....    ]
[   ....   ]
[    ....  ]
[     .... ]
[      ....]
[.      ...]
[..      ..]
[...      .]
```

..Then it loops forever.

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins <strike><sup>I doubt I would even accept a winning answer tho</sup></strike>
- Please provide a gif file of the loading bar in action if possible.

Comment: Can we output, say, twenty newlines before each output to 'clear' the screen?

Comment: @Okx Yes, if your language has no other way of clearing the screen.

Comment: How much error can the delay be?(e.g. +- 0.5 seconds) I'd suggest 250 milliseconds error....

Comment: Can I suggest not including the fixed time delay on future challenges? I find it's appeared on a lot of recent challenges, and each time I write the same ungolfable boilerplate to make the system wait n milleseconds.

Comment: Is the use of `\r` allowed, instead of literally clearing the screen?

Answer (score 19):

## V, <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
i[´.¶ ]<esc>ògó$X|p
```

`<esc>` is `0x1b`.

And the hexdump:

```
00000000: 695b b42e b620 5d1b f267 f324 587c 70    i[... ]..g.$X|p
```

#### Explanation

```
i                       " Insert
[                       " a [
´.                      " 4 .s
¶<space>                " 6 spaces
]<esc>                  " and a ]. Then return to normal mode
ò                       " Recursively do:
 gó                     "  Sleep for 100 milliseconds
 $                      "  Go to the ]
 X                      "  Delete the character to the left of the ]
 |                      "  Go to the [
 p                      "  And paste the deleted character right after the [
                        " Implicit ending ò
```

[image: gif]

Comment: How to test in Vim?

Comment: @Phoenix `i....      <esc>qq:sl 100m<CR>$X|P@qq@q` should work (`<esc>` is obviously the escape key and `<CR>` is a linefeed) (there are 6 spaces after the 4 dots)

Comment: Glad to see the `gó` function being useful. Nice answer BTW :)

Answer (score 19):

### CSS/HTML, <s>202</s> <s>190</s> 186 + 45 = <s>247</s> <s>235</s> 231 bytes

```css
pre{position:relative}x{position:absolute;display:inline-block;width:10ch;height:1em;overflow:hidden}x>x{width:14ch;left:-10ch;animation:1s steps(10,end)infinite l}@keyframes l{to{left:0
```

```html
<pre>[<x><x>....      ....</x></x>          ]
```

Edit: Saved <s>12</s> 14 bytes thanks to @Luke.

Comment: Can't you save 6 bytes by renaming the animation to something like `b`?

Comment: @Luke I can't believe I forgot to do that...

Comment: You can save 2 more bytes by dropping the `ch` at the end; `0` doesn't need a unit.

Comment: @Luke Indeed, nor do I need the `}`s.

Comment: How about changing `<x>` to `<span>` (and in the CSS as well: `x` becomes `span` and `x>x` becomes `span>*`)? That saves the `display:inline-block;`, but costs only 15 bytes. So a total of 6B are saved.

Comment: @Luke I don't care about the display but I do want to avoid repeating the `position:absolute;`.

Answer (score 12):

## PowerShell, <s>67</s> 66 Bytes

```
for($s='.'*4+' '*6;$s=-join($s[,9+0..8])){cls;"[$s]";sleep -m 100}
```

-1 by using shortened constructor thanks to Beatcracker

replaces the string with a copy of the string where the last char is put in front of the remaining chars, clears the screen, prints it, and then sleeps for 100 ms.

saved a lot of bytes by using the for loop constructor rather than wrap the logic inside the string.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the `for` loop trick and making me re-read [about_Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join).

Comment: P.S. You can golf one more byte using `$s='.'*4+' '*6`.

Comment: @beatcracker thanks for that - updated :)

Comment: The script does not start by `[....      ]`. You can fix it without penalty: `for($s='.'*4+' '*6){cls;"[$s]";$s=-join($s[,9+0..8]);sleep -m 100}`

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>99</s> <s>93</s> <s>85</s> 83+2 ([-u flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print/230780#230780)) bytes

<sup>-12 bytes thanks to ovs</sup>
<sup>-2 bytes thanks to totallyhuman</sup>

```python
import time
s=4*'.'+6*' '
while 1:print(end='\r[%s]'%s);time.sleep(.1);s=s[9]+s[:9]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#FctBCoAgEADAu6/wEqsJghCBii8xby0kmIkr9Hyjuc/Md3v64CPfyChsK2hQ@woc2Hvlgty41nMdAusZ4OhxoQQLSf8HTQWxCW2kp0DRJkXR2TTnBw)

Comment: Why do you have `flush=True`? It works without for me

Comment: @L3viathan because my (ubuntu) terminal wasn't flushing. This flushing behaviour is OS dependent =/

Comment: Save some bytes with `print(end='\r[%s]'%s,flush=1)`

Comment: You can remove flush entirely by using the `-u` command line flag. [Related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/230780)

Comment: You can also save some bytes with `s[9]+s[:9]`.

Comment: By meta consensus, the -u option is considered a different programming language and hereby doesn't count to more bytes

Answer (score 10):

## Windows batch , <s>201</s> 181 bytes

*Turns out using the old-school method actually saves bytes!*

```
@for %%p in ("....      " " ....     " "  ....    " "   ....   " "    ....  " "     .... " "      ...." ".      ..." "..      .." "...      .")do @echo [%%~p]&timeout 0 >nul&cls
@%0
```

---

Note:

```
get-screenrecorder.level
- low grade

get-gpu.level
- horrible

if get-screenrecorder.level == low grade || get-gpu.level == horrible {
     say("GIF may not be accurate");
}
```

[image: GIF!]

Please note that my GIF recorder skipped a few frames, making the loading bar jumps `:(`

Comment: Rather than calculating the number of dots, if you just kept a variable with the dots and spaces and performed string manipulation on it you could probably get this down to 100 bytes.

Comment: I would try work on this, thanks for your tips :)!

Comment: timeout/t 0 >nul instead of ping 1.1 -n 1 -w 100>nul will be within the 100ms +/- 250ms timing requirement (should be around 25 - 100ms normally) so can save a few bytes there (https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)

Comment: Also removing the `@echo off` and replacing the do with  `do @(echo %%~p&timeout/t 0 >nul&cls)` will also work and should save 11 characters (200 bytes on my computer)

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, <s>67</s> 77 Bytes

+10 Bytes as I forgot the square brackets.

```
Animate["["<>"....      "~StringRotateRight~n<>"]",{n,1,10,1},RefreshRate->10]
```

Comment: Really, Mathematica has a built-in `Animate`? :|

Comment: Yup, it will animate just about anything over a given variable. :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to include the rectangular brackets that most other answers do.

Comment: Oh rats, didn't look closely enough. Ok fixed.

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>126</s> <s>125</s> <s>124</s> <s>123</s> <s>122</s> <s>121</s> <s>119</s> <s>118</s> <s>117</s> <s>114</s> 115 bytes

This one uses a bitmask to keep track of where the dots are.

I had to add another byte as I was only outputting 5 spaces before.

```c
m=30;f(i){usleep(3<<15);system("clear");for(i=1;i<1920;i*=2)putchar(i^1?i&m?46:32:91);m+=m&512?m+1:m;f(puts("]"));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#FYxBCoMwEAD/koPsVgpurAWzBl/SQggRA66K0YNIn92ztccZhjnFlgV3EPHY0hDCDGXTUIWc9rQGAeWH4BaF3E0LREscG6p1wfFmNc7b6nt3@Te1MZP28TSlNjUhS24lq0i3kpOR63@lCdRLIfLnFBdHwKODP3zH6e6d78MP)

[image]

Comment: WHY is your command prompt font Comic Sans MS?!?!?!

Comment: Why has no one asked why it's pretending to be a Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 8):

## Javascript (ES6), 86 bytes

```js
setInterval('with(console)clear(),log(`[${x=x[9]+x.slice(0,9)}]`)',100,x='...      .')
```

Comment: +1 for `with`. *Always* +1 for `with`!

Comment: @Shaggy https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118402/tell-me-my-screen-resolution/118410#118410 #SelfPromotion :p

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6) + HTML, <s>104</s> <s>85</s> 83 bytes

```
f=(s="....      ")=>setTimeout(f,100,s[9]+s.slice(0,9),o.value=`[${s}]`)
<input id=o
```

- Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Johan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55822/johan-karlsson)'s suggestion that I use an `input` instead of a `pre`.

---

### Try It

Requires a closing `>` on the `input` tag in order to function in a Snippet.

```js
(f=(s="....      ")=>setTimeout(f,100,s[9]+s.slice(0,9),o.value=`[${s}]`))()
```

```html
<input id=o>
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be 10 characters between the `[]`s?

Comment: You're right, @Neil; there are 6 spaces - if I'm going to count things by eye, the least I could do is wear my glasses!

Comment: Can't you use an `<input>` instead of `<pre>`and then `value` instead of `innerText`?

Comment: Good call, @JohanKarlsson; that saves 2 bytes.

Comment: Hey! This is the same byte count: `s='....      ';setInterval(f=>{o.value='[${s=s[9]+s.slice(0,9)}]'},100);<input id=o`, maybe someone can improve it (replace quotation mark with `)

Answer (score 5):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

<s>[ CỤ‘Ṁ~ððÐ]ʠḷẸḍt</s>

<s>]ʠ[Ð.×4¤×6⁺ḷẸḍt</s>

<s>]ʠ⁶¤⁴.ȧ[ėÐḷẸḍt</s>

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%5D%CA%A0%E2%81%B6%C2%A4%E2%81%B4.%C8%A7%5B%C4%97%C3%90%E1%B8%B7%E1%BA%B8%E1%B8%8Dt&input=&run=true)

---

### How it works

```
]ʠ⁶¤⁴.ȧ[ėÐḷẸḍt

]ʠ⁶¤⁴.ȧ[ėÐ     # Set up for the animation.
]              # Pushes the literal string "]" onto the stack.
 ʠ             # Move the top of the stack down by one such that the "]" will remain on top.
  ⁶¤           # Pushes the string "¤" six times onto the stack where "¤" represents a space.
    ⁴.         # Pushes the string "." four times onto the stack.
      ȧ        # Take everything on the stack and create an array.
       [       # Pushes on the string literal "[".
        ė      # Take what is on the top of the stack and place it at the bottom (moves the "[" to the bottom).
         Ð     # Pushes the stack to the screen which in Noodel means by reference.

          ḷẸḍt # The main animation loop.
          ḷ    # Loop endlessly the following code.
           Ẹ   # Take the last character of the array and move it to the front.
            ḍt # Delay for a tenth of a second.
               # Implicit end of loop.
```

---

### Update

```
[Ð]ıʠ⁶¤⁴.ḷėḍt
```

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%5B%C3%90%5D%C4%B1%CA%A0%E2%81%B6%C2%A4%E2%81%B4.%E1%B8%B7%C4%97%E1%B8%8Dt&input=&run=true)

Don’t know why this took me a while to think of. Anyways, this places it at **13 bytes**.

```
[Ð]ıʠ⁶¤⁴.ḷėḍt

[Ð]ıʠ⁶¤⁴.     # Sets up the animation.
[             # Push on the character "["
 Ð            # Push the stack as an array (which is by reference) to the screen.
  ]           # Push on the character "]"
   ı          # Jump into a new stack placing the "[" on top.
    ʠ         # Move the top of the stack down one.
     ⁶¤       # Push on six spaces.
       ⁴.     # Push on four dots.

         ḷėḍt # The main loop that does the animation.
         ḷ    # Loop the following code endlessly.
          ė   # Take the top of the stack and put it at the bottom.
           ḍt # Delay for a tenth of a second.
```

```html
<div id="noodel" code="[Ð]ıʠ⁶¤⁴.ḷėḍt" input="" cols="12" rows="2"></div>

<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/noodel-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/ppcg.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Never heard of Noodel before, but it seems to be the right tool for the right job! +1

Comment: @KevinCruijssen, [ETHProductions](https://github.com/ETHproductions) has a good list with [languages for code golfing](https://github.com/ETHproductions/golfing-langs):)

Comment: Just when I thought I outgolfed you, I notice you have already golfed your solution twice

Comment: @KritixiLithos, I was scared you were going to beat me so I spent forever trying to get to __14 bytes__. But, now you are close again!! Dang!!

Comment: Are you sure that characters like `⁶` and `Ẹ` are encoded in a single byte?

Comment: @nitro2k01. In the editor, no it is not. The editor uses the character encoding as what works best with _JavaScript_. These characters are then encoded based off the _Noodel_ code page. Then, once again because of what is easier with _JavaScript_, _Noodel_ decodes that into the original characters. Sounds stupid, but I did that just to make it to where the _noodel_ function takes in the proper encoding. So, those characters are __1 byte__ to _Noodel_. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @tkellehe Well, no. That's still characters (of some unknown length) not bytes (commonly defined as 8 bits in modern computing).

Comment: @nitro2k01 Noodel uses [its own code-page with 256 characters](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html), which are all saved as a single byte in their own encoding. Similar as some other golfing languages do, like [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) or [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md). If you would save these characters as default UTF-8 encoding, they will indeed be 2 or 3 bytes instead, but in their own encoding they are 1 byte each.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Didn't realize it had its own codepage.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 24 bytes

```
`1&Xx'['897B@YS46*93hhDT
```

Try it at [**MATL Online!**](https://matl.io/?code=%601%26Xx%27%5B%27897B%40YS46%2a93hhDT&inputs=&version=19.10.0) Or see a gif from the offline compiler:

[image]

#### Explanation

```
`        % Do...while
  1&Xx   %   Pause for 0.1 s and clear screen
  '['    %   Push this character
  897B   %   Push [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
  @      %   Push current iteration index, 1-based
  YS     %   Circularly shift the array by that amount
  46*    %   Multiply by 46 (code point of '.')
  93     %   Push 93 (code point of ']')
  hh     %   Concatenate horizontally twice. Numbers are interpreted as chars
         %   with the corresponding code points
  D      %   Display
  T      %   Push true. Used as loop condition. Results in an infinite loop
         % End (implicit)
```

Comment: Your link crashes, meaning that I cannot kill it.

Comment: @LeakyNun What do you mean exactly that it crashes? It works for me, and I can kill it. Sometimes there are timeout issues. If it doesn't start, try refreshing the page

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 67 bytes

```php
for($s="...      .";$s=substr($s.$s,9,10);usleep(1e5))echo"\r[$s]";
```

no comment

Answer (score 4):

## C#, <strike>162</strike> 157 bytes

```
()=>{for(string o="[....      ]";;){o=o.Insert(1,o[10]+"").Remove(11,1);System.Console.Write(o);System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);System.Console.Clear();}};
```

or as whole program for 177 bytes

```
namespace System{class P{static void Main(){for(string o="[....      ]";;){o=o.Insert(1,o[10]+"").Remove(11,1);Console.Write(o);Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);Console.Clear();}}}}
```

Comment: +1 Something to golf: `for(string o="[....      ]";;)` can be golfed to `var o="[....      ]";for(;;)`. Or you can us a port of [my Java 7 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120244/52210) to golf the total some more: `()=>{var o="....      "for(;;){o=(o+o).Substring(9,10);System.Console.Write("["+o+"]\n");System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);System.Console.Clear();}};`

Comment: Would string interpolation trim anymore off? Something like `$"[{o}]\n"`

Comment: If you replace `System.Console.Write(o)` with `System.Console.Write(o+"\r")` you can remove the `System.Console.Clear();`

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>28</s> 27 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṙ©-j@⁾[]ṭ”ÆȮœS.1®ß
897ṃ⁾. Ç
```

[image: Example run]

#### How?

```
ṙ©-j@⁾[]ṭ”ÆȮœS.1®ß - Link 1, the infinite loop: list of characters s
ṙ                  - rotate s left by:
  -                -   -1 (e.g. "...      ." -> "....      ")
 ©                 -   copy to the register and yield
     ⁾[]           - literal ['[',']']
   j@              - join with reversed @rguments
         ”Æ        - literal '\r'
        ṭ          - tack (append the display text to the '\r')
           Ȯ       - print with no newline ending
              .1   - literal 0.1
            œS     - sleep for 0.1 seconds then yield the printed text (unused)
                ®  - recall the value from the register
                 ß - call this link (1) again with the same arity

897ṃ⁾. Ç - Main link: no arguments
897      - literal 897
    ⁾.   - literal ['.',' ']
   ṃ     - base decompression: convert 897 to base ['.',' '] = "...      ."
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pure bash, 68

```
s=${1:-....      }
printf "[$s]\r"
sleep .1
exec $0 "${s: -1}${s%?}"
```

Answer (score 4):

## C (gcc), <s>202</s> <s>198</s> <s>196</s> <s>189</s> <s>96</s> <s>99</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>79</s> <s>77</s> <s>75</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

Saved <s>7</s> 8 bytes thanks to [Digital Trauma](/a/120322/61563).

```
f(i){usleep(dprintf(2,"\r[%-10.10s]","....      ...."+i%10)<<13);f(i+9);}
```

Or, if your system's `stdout` doesn't need to be flushed after every write without a newline:

## C (gcc), 70 bytes

```
f(i){usleep(printf("\r[%-10.10s]","....      ...."+i%10)<<13);f(i+9);}
```

#### How it works

- `usleep(` sleeps for the next return value in microseconds.
- `dprintf(2,` prints to file descriptor 2, or `stderr`. This is necessary because while `stdout` is line-buffered (meaning output will not show until it prints a newline), `stderr` is character-buffered (all output is shown immediately).
- `"\r` prints a carriage return (clears the current line).
- `[%-10.10s]"` is the `printf` format specifier for a string with exact length 10 (no matter what string provided the output will always be a string with length 10), padded with spaces to the right if necessary. This will be enclosed with brackets.
- `"....      ...."` is the loading bar.
- `+i%10` offsets the loading bar by the current index modulo 10. For example, if `i == 3`, `i % 10` is equal to 3. Offsetting the loading bar by 3 makes it equal to `".      ...."`.
- When the offset-ed string is passed to the `printf` format specifier, it limits to a length of 10 if necessary and adds spaces to the end if necessary. Therefore, the loading bar will always be between `[....      ]` and `[.      ...]`.

Comment: `i;f(){for(;;i=++i%10)usleep(7500*dprintf(2,"\r[%-10.10s]","....      ...."-i+10));}` should work.

Comment: Great golfing!  Save 1 more byte with `f(i){usleep(dprintf(2,"\r[%-10.10s]","....      ...."+i%10)<<13);f(i+9);}`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma [The spaces in your code didn't render properly.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12400/61563) However, I see what you meant, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>81</s> 78 bytes

-1 byte (noticing I missed use of `%s` when Rod submitted an [almost identical Python 3 version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120236/53748) at the same time!)
-2 bytes (using [totallyhuman's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120216/loading-forever-windows-style/120235#comment295545_120236) - replace `s[-1]+s[:-1]` with `s[9]+s[:9]`)

```python
import time
s='.'*4+' '*6
while s:print'\r[%s]'%s,;s=s[9]+s[:9];time.sleep(.1)
```

[image: Example run]

Comment: How it's flushing the output? this is the reason why I'm using python3 on my answer (it would take more bytes to flush on python2)

Comment: @Rod the `\r` overwrites the line and the `,` makes it print a tuple rather than a string - I saw it a while back somewhere and have used it before too.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was doing, but the output wasn't being printed in real time (had to use `sys.stdout.flush()`)

Comment: Found the culprit : my ubuntu terminal :c

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>139</s> 124 bytes

```java
String s="....      ";void c()throws Exception{System.out.print("["+s+"]\r");s=(s+s).substring(9,19);Thread.sleep(100);c();}
```

- Mentioning of `\r` thanks to *@Phoenix*.

The carriage return `\r` resets the 'cursor' back to the begin of the line, which can then be overwritten. Unfortunately, online compilers nor the Eclipse IDE doesn't support this, so I've added a gif at the end of this answer to show it from Windows Command Prompt.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#bY@xboMwGIR3nuLkpbZIHaKqQ@QydOiYKd3SDA52iyWwEb8JiSKenTp0TG856aQ7fVc1mgi7WwY4H@HKYtXqS/nyqrBe490Ya0AB1zDABP8UUeuzhUZ0rX0OQ5z3sXf@B1QymYRFTJ2DM6i4iHUfRsLHpbJddMHf9leKtpWpKbtUjJwdWE45O371TCgqOeUkJA0nWnb5drXZCvVZ91YbSY21Hd8UhVCZ@@Yuz98SrHggHf8jzRKOmmagG06Nq0BRx2QLaaud539PDkdogQfu7P7L2xE7LuR9KQVTNs2/) (Slightly modified so you won't have to wait for the time-out before viewing the result. Also, the TIO doesn't support carriage returns, so every line is printed without overwriting the previous line.)

**Explanation:**

```java
String s="....      ";            // Starting String "....      " on class level
void c()                          // Method without parameter nor return-type
 throws Exception{                // throws-clause/try-catch is mandatory for Thread.sleep
  System.out.print("["+s+"]\r");  //  Print the String between square-brackets,
                                  //  and reset the 'cursor' to the start of the line
  s=(s+s).substring(9,19);        //  Set `s` to the next String in line
  Thread.sleep(100);              //  Wait 100 ms
  c();                            //  Recursive call to same method
}                                 // End of method
```

**Output gif:**

[image]

Comment: You can clear the line by replacing `println` with `print` and outputting a carriage return. Might not work in your IDE's terminal, but it would work in any other sane one.

Comment: @Phoenix By carriage return you mean `\r\n`? How does `System.out.print(someString+"\r\n);` clear the console.. It's the same as using `System.out.println(someString);`.. It simply goes to the next line, but doesn't remove any previous line printed.. :S

Comment: No, I mean `\r`, without `\n`. That resets the "cursor" to the beginning of the line so printing anything will overwrite that line.

Comment: @Phoenix Ah of course. Thanks. Modified my answer and added a gif to show the result. Too bad online compilers nor the Eclipse IDE aren't supporting this.. >.>

Answer (score 3):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>150</s> <s>145</s> <s>132</s> <s>129</s> 124 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to sudee.*

I feel like I don't see enough Go here... But my answer is topping C so... pls halp golf?

```
package main
import(."fmt"
."time")
func main(){s:="....      ";for{Print("\r["+s+"]");Sleep(Duration(1e8));s=(s+s)[9:19];}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/go#Hcq7CsMgFADQ3a8Id/IiFbI1kWz9gEDHNIPItZXWB2qmkM/ubEvOfFrS5q2f1HntAnM@xVy5BOsrMAnVeQJkdgvmDBz3Mk4g/7oTKBvzPmcXKodHXkAUASugun@IEr9tWVcXA@/piqjKxIsouAxjP6zqOFr7hngx2rzoBw)

Comment: Not familiar with Go, but I would assume you can convert `100000000` to `10^8` to save 5 bytes.

Comment: @goatmeal I tried that but it's apparently bitwise negation. I also tried `10**8` which also gives an error.

Comment: You can use scientific notation: `1e8`.

Comment: @sudee Aha, that would be the way to use large numbers. Thanks!

Comment: No longer topping [C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120321/61563) :P

Comment: @MDXF I should've phrased that differently, I meant my answer is being *out-golfed* by C.

Answer (score 3):

## VBA 32-bit, <sub><s>159</s> <s>157</s> <s>143</s> <s>141</s></sub> 134 Bytes

VBA does not have a built in function that allows for waiting for time periods less than one second so we must declare a function from `kernel32.dll`

**32 Bit Declare Statement (41 Bytes)**

```vba
Declare Sub Sleep Lib"kernel32"(ByVal M&)
```

**64 Bit Declare Statement (49 Bytes)**

```vba
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib"kernel32"(ByVal M&)
```

Additionally, we must include a `DoEvents` flag to avoid the infinite loop from making Excel appear as non-responsive. The final function is then a subroutine which takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

**Immediate Window function, 93 Bytes**

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the range `A1` on the ActiveSheet

```vba
s="...      ....      .":Do:DoEvents:Sleep 100:[A1]="["&Mid(s,10-i,10)&"]":i=(i+1)Mod 10:Loop
```

#### Old Version, 109 Bytes

Immediate window function that takes no input and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vba
s="...      ....      .":i=0:Do:DoEvents:Sleep 100:Debug.?"["&Mid(s,10-i,10)&"]":i=(i+1) Mod 10:Loop
```

**Ungolfted and formatted**

```vba
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal M&)
Sub a()
    Dim i As Integer, s As String
    s = "...      ....      ."
    i = 0
    Do
        Debug.Print [REPT(CHAR(10),99]; "["; Mid(s, 10 - i, 10); "]"
        DoEvents
        Sleep 100
        i = (i + 1) Mod 10
    Loop
End Sub
```

*-2 Bytes for removing whitespace*

*-30 Bytes for counting correctly*

*-14 Bytes for converting to immediate window function*

**Output**

*The gif below uses the full subroutine version because I was too lazy to rerecord this with the immediate window function.*

[image: VBA loading Gif]

Comment: What's that `a` at the top of the output?

Comment: @MDXF that is the call to run subroutine `a` as is listed above; this is functionally equivalant to the more verbose `call a()`.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Just looking for bad submissions. Your's isn't, then, so +1

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 69 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [@Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings).*

```pl
$_="....".$"x6;{print"\ec[$_]
";select$a,$a,!s/(.*)(.)/$2$1/,.1;redo}
```

That `select undef,undef,undef,.1` is the shortest way to sleep less than 1 second in Perl, and it takes a lot of bytes...

---

Slightly longer (79 bytes), there is:

```pl
@F=((".")x4,($")x6);{print"\ec[",@F,"]\n";@F=@F[9,0..8];select$a,$a,$a,.1;redo}
```

Comment: Evening, managed to get this down a little more 69 (or 68 with a literal ESC): https://gist.github.com/dom111/e3ff41c8bc835b81cbf55a9827d69992 I feel like the tried to use `!print` but you need parens so it ends up the same length :/

Comment: @DomHastings Nice, thanks! You still know how to golf :D

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes

```
'.4×ð6×J[D…[ÿ],Á¶т×,т.W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#ASUA2v//Jy40w5fDsDbDl0pbROKAplvDv10sw4HCttGCw5cs0YIuV///)

**Explanation**

```
'.4×ð6×J                  # push the string "....      "
        [                 # forever do:
         D                # duplicate
          …[ÿ],           # interpolate the copy between brackets and print
               Á          # rotate the remaining copy right
                ¶т×,      # print 100 newlines
                    т.W   # wait 100ms
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, <del>93</del> <del>90</del> 96 bytes

```
s="...      ....      ."
for((;;)){ for i in {0..9};do printf "\r[${s:10-i:10}]";sleep .1;done;}
```

[view here](https://asciinema.org/a/4b02bns85e01zev7jqdhx6vdx)

couldn't get nested { } in for syntax

Comment: I intended to post a quite similar solution, but is pointless now. But may give some inspiration to improve your: https://pastebin.com/Ld6rryNX

Comment: much better! i'm not stealing from you, i knew i had to work out this one...

Comment: edited, printf padding can't help in shortening s. wraping the string as @DigitalTrauma looks better.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```
s=?.*4+' '*6;loop{$><<"[%s]\r"%s=s[-1]+s.chop;sleep 0.1}
```

Heavily influenced by other answers here.

Saved a byte thanks to @manatwork. Also apparently I have trouble counting characters -- I use ST3 and apparently it will include newlines in the count of characters in the line if you're not attentive.

Comment: How does it work? Does this assume that the input is stored in `s`?

Comment: @Riker He defines `s` at the beginning of the program as 4 `.`s and a few spaces

Comment: `s[0..8]` → `s.chop`

Answer (score 2):

## Batch, <s>99</s> 98 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to SteveFest!*

(I could remove `\r` from the code, but in the spirit of batch golfing, I won't.)

```
@SET s=....      
:g
@CLS
@ECHO [%s%]
@SET s=%s:~-1%%s:~,-1%
@ping 0 -n 1 -w 100>nul
@GOTO g
```

[image: Recorded with LICEcap]

There are four spaces after the first line.

The main logic is modifying the string. `%s:~-1%` is the last character of `%s%` and `%s:~0,-1%` is all but the last character of `%s%`. Thus, we are moving the last character to the front of the string, which rotates the string.

Comment: Aw... I've been looking for this...

Comment: Golf 1 byte: the `0` in the variable substring can be removed

Comment: You use `cmder`. Nice job.

Comment: @SteveFest Huh, TIL. Thanks!

Comment: @MDXF It's the only reason I'm still sane :P

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Well, there's [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/), which comes with bash. Quite useful, it's what I use.

Comment: `timeout/t 0 >nul` saves some bytes

Comment: I'm curious why won't you remove the `\r`s?

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 72 bytes

```groovy
s="*"*4+" "*6
for(;;){print("["+s+"]"+"\n"*20);s=s[9]+s[0..8];sleep 100}
```

**Explaination**

```groovy
s="*"*4+" "*6 //creates the string "****      "
for(;;){ //classic infinite loop
    print("["+s+"]"+"\n"*20) //prints the string with [ at the beginning and ] at the end. After that some newlines
    s=s[9]+s[0..8] //appends the final char of the string to beginning, creating a cycling illusion
    sleep 100 //100 ms delay
}
```

Comment: Didn't know a proper way to clear the console in Groovy/Java. If someone has a way of doing it, please tell me

Comment: You can use `\r` to return the cursor to the start of the line. It appears that at least several answers are doing this. From there, you could delete the *20, saving 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (Windows), 159 bytes

```
import System.Process
import Control.Concurrent
main=mapM id[do system"cls";putStrLn('[':["....      "!!mod(i-n)10|i<-[0..9]]++"]");threadDelay(10^5)|n<-[0..]]
```

Explanation

```
mapM id             sequentially perform each IO action in the following list
[                   start a list comprehension where each element is...
  do                  an IO operation where
    system "cls";       we clear the screen by calling the windows builtin "cls"
    putStrLn(           then display the string...
      '[':                with '[' appended to
      [                   a list comprehension where each character is...
        "....      "!!       the character in literal string "....      " at the index
        mod(i-n)10          (i - n) % 10
      |i<-[0..9]]         where i goes from 0 to 9
      ++"]"             and that ends with ']'
    );
    threadDelay(10^5)   then sleep for 100,000 microseconds (100 ms)
|n<-[0..]]          where n starts at 0 and increments without bound
```

Haskell's purity made generating the cycling dot pattern somewhat complex.  I ended up creating a nested list comprehension that generated an infinite list of strings in the order they should be output, then went back added the appropriate IO operations.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 61 bytes

If the spec were for the dots to scroll left instead of right, it would save 1 byte because `rotate!` with no arguments shifts the array once to the left.

```
s=[?.]*4+[' ']*6
loop{print ?[,*s,"]\r";s.rotate!9;sleep 0.1}
```

Answer (score 1):

## GNU sed (with exec extension), 64

Score includes +1 for `-r` flag.

```
s/^/[....      ]/
:
esleep .1
s/[^. ]*(.+)(.)].*/\c[c[\2\1]/p
b
```

Answer (score 1):

## c, 100

```
char *s="....      ....     ";main(i){for(i=0;;i=(i+9)%10)dprintf(2,"[%.10s]\r",s+i),usleep(3<<15);}
```

Comment: Why print to `stderr` using `dprintf` and not just use `printf`?

Comment: @MDXF Because by default `stderr` is character buffered, whereas `stdout` is line buffered.  Since I don't want to print any `\n`, then with `printf()` I'd have to explicitly `fflush(stdout)` as well as `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Good point, but actually, you wouldn't have to `#include <stdio.h>` to flush STDOUT. `fflush(0)` flushes all buffers.

Comment: Save three bytes by renaming `main` to `f`, that counts.

Answer (score 1):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 282 bytes

```
canvas # #
def # 1000 ! Obj N new M move > 10
newObj 0 # #
pen 255 255 255
N! 0 > >0
M! 1 > >
N! 0 > >0
M! 2 560 >
x=8
lblx
x-1
N! 0 > >
if x x
M! 3 20 >
M! 4 20 >0
M! 5 550 >
M! 6 550 >0
lbla
x=4
lbly
A=6+x
B=60+50*(((x-1)+a)%>)
M! A B 50 
x-1
if x y
refresh
a+1
a%>
wait >0
GOTO a
```

TIO currently does not support graphical output, but the official interpreter does. I think this is the first time I have gotten a chance to test out the graphical output functionality of SILOS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), <s>85</s> <s>72</s> <s>71</s> <s>66</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```
f(i){Udprintf(2,"\r[%-10.10s]","....      ...."+i%10)<<13);f(i+9
```

Explanation:

```
f(i){                                                           function that takes integer
     U                                                          sleep
      dprintf(2,                                                print unbuffered
                "\r[%-10.10s]",                                 string with exactly 10 characters, wrapped with spaces
                               "....    ...."                   a string that, when printed with exactly 10 characters, will always have output that is in the loading screen
                                             +i%10              scroll through the string
                                                  )<<13);       sleep 10<<13 microseconds
                                                         f(i+9  recursion :D
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>31</s> 22 bytes

*Saved 9 bytes thanks to @obakaron*

```
Li@O¬OpT=T?Té :'.²²+6î
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=TGlAT6xPcFQ9VD9U6SA6Jy6ysis27g==)

Comment: `p4 ` can be shortened to `²²`, `Sp6` can be replaced by `6î`, and `Oq ` can be replaced by `O¬`

Comment: You're missing the enclosing `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 58 bytes

```
"....      (6 spaces)
Ans+Ans
While 1
For(X,11,2,-1
ClrHome
Disp "["+sub(Ans,X,10)+"]
Wait .1
End
End
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to submit a 68k version but realized that 1) None of my TI-92 Plus have a new enough AMS to use the clock, and 2) even if they did, the granularity is in seconds

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 44 bytes

```apl
{∇r⊣⎕DL.1⊣⎕←⎕TC[20⍴2],1⌽'][',r←¯1⌽⍵}10↑4⍴'.'
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#e9TR7pOfmPK/@lFHe9GjrsWP@qa6@OgZglgdbfFAXohztJHBo94tRrE6ho969qrHRqvrFD1qm3BoPYj7qHdrraHBo7aJJkAl6nrq/4HGcHGBtbZNqAZqB1Iaxo/aJoNMCtZUt1IH6fgPshIA) with a slightly modified version: `⎕←` replaced by `∆_` which outputs with timestamps.

`4⍴'.'` four periods

`10↑` take the first ten characters of that (pads with spaces)

`{`…`}` apply the following function

`¯1⌽` rotate one character from the tail to the head

`r←` assign that to *r*

`'][',` prepend the brackets

`1⌽` rotate one character from the head to the tail

`⎕TC[`…`]` index the list of **T**erminal **C**ontrol characters with

`20⍴2` twenty repetitions of the number two (the second element is the newline)

`⎕←` output that

`.1⊣` discard that in favour of the number 0.1

`⎕DL` **D**e**l**ay that many seconds (returns elapsed time)

`r⊣` discard that in favour of *r* (which is then returned by the function)

`∇` recurse (tail calls do not work up a stack, and can thus be repeated forever)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 132 bytes

```
import Control.Concurrent
main=mapM_(\x->putStrLn("\27[H\27[J["++x++"]")>>threadDelay(10^5))$iterate(\x->last x:init x)"....      "
```

First, we define a function `r` to rotate a string to the right.  We begin with `"....      "` and construct an infinite list of its right-rotations, then for each `x` of these, print:

- An ANSI escape sequence to clear the screen,
- A left-bracket,
- `x` itself,
- A right-bracket,
- And a newline character so the terminal will flush.

Then `threadDelay` waits 100000 microseconds before continuing onto the next element.

Since we are applying these operations to an infinite list, it will continue forever.

Comment: `f x=last x:init x` should be shorter than using `reverse`.

Comment: @Laikoni Wow, thanks for that! Saved a whole dozen bytes

Comment: Save another byte by moving the `$` to the position of the `.`. Also is the newline needed if the screen is cleared anyway? If not then `putStrLn` can be shortened to `putStr`.

Comment: @Laikoni Right, don't know why I didn't see that.  In my case, the `Ln` is needed, else the terminal never displays anything.  I think that's terminal-dependent though — else I would just use a carriage return instead of the ANSI escape

Answer (score 1):

## VBA (Excel), 109  bytes

Using Immediate Window and `Cell A1` as output

```
a="...      .":Do:b=Right(a,1):a=b &Left(a,9):[A1]="["& a &"]":c=Timer+.1:Do While Timer<c:DoEvents:Loop:Loop
```

Comment: `Do While:...:Loop` -> `While:...:Wend` for -3 bytes

Answer (score 0):

## CJam, 39 bytes

```
'.4*S6*+{_a`'"-oDcoes{es1$m100<}g;1m>}h
```

Can't make a GIF right now...

**How it works**

```
'.4*S6*+       e# Push a string containing 4 dots and 6 spaces
{              e# Do:
 _             e#  Copy the string
 a`            e#  Wrap it in an array and take its string representation: ["....      "]
 '"-           e#  Remove quote characters from it: [....      ]
 o             e#  Print it
 Dco           e#  Print a carriage return (ASCII 13), moving the cursor back to the start
 es            e#  Push the current time in milliseconds
 {es1$m100<}g  e#  Loop until the current time is at least 100 more than that time
 ;             e#  Delete the old time
 1m>           e#  Rotate the string 1 space to the right
}h             e# Repeat while the TOS is truthy. The string being printed is non-empty, so
               e#   it is always truthy, and will repeat forever.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 28 bytes

```
J+*4\.*6d#.d.1p"\r"pj=.>J1`Y
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 61 bytes

```
$_='....      ';loop {"^M[$_]".print;s/(.*)(.)/$1$0/;sleep .1}
```

(That `^M` is a single carriage return character.)

I really tried to base the output on a lazy infinite list, but couldn't nearly approach the terseness of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

### C, <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```
i;f(){usleep(printf("\r[%-10.10s]","....      ...."+i%10)*7692);f(i+=9);}
```

Modified and improved version of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120321.

Displays correct output on MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

### C, <s>98</s> 93 Bytes

```
main(){char b[]="x...      .";for(;;)*b=b[10],usleep(12<<printf("\r[%s]",memcpy(b+1,b,10)));}
```

[View Video](https://asciinema.org/a/azksfuvz78hcvjitc2bmnoem7)

Comment: @MDXF, Besides screwing up the pointer arithmetics, gcc does not allow the following on the global scope: `b[]="x...      .";`

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 71 bytes

```
s="...       ."';do;printf('[%s]\r',s=circshift(s,1));pause(.1);until 0
```

For once my Octave answer is not MATLAB compatible. Specifically this solution uses

- Both `"` and `'` for quotes, to transpose a string

  - MATLAB: `('asd')'`
  - Octave: `"asd"'`
- Octave specific `do ... until 0` structure, one char shorter than `while 1 ... end`
- Octave's `printf`,one char shorter than the `fprintf` in MATLAB

[image: Loading image...]

Answer (score 0):

## C, 91 bytes

```
main(i){for(char*s="....      ....    ";;i+=9)usleep(dprintf(2,"[%.10s]\r",s+i%10-1)<<13);}
```

If it doesn't have to begin at the left: (89 bytes)

```
main(i){for(char*s="....      ....    ";;i+=9)usleep(dprintf(2,"[%.10s]\r",s+i%10)<<13);}
```

Comment: Something not quite right with this, sometimes it displays `[a....     ]`

Comment: -7 bytes: eliminate `char*s=` and use the raw string in `dprintf`, e.g. `"....      ....    "+i%10-1`.

Answer (score 0):

### R, 100 bytes

```r
z="....      "
repeat{flush.console()
cat("\r[",z,"]",sep="")
z=sub("(.)(.+)(.)","\\3\\1\\2",z)
Sys.sleep(.1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), <s>122</s> <s>114</s> <s>118</s> 110 bytes

```fs
let rec t s=printf"[%s]\r"s;System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);t((string s.[8])+s.Substring(0,8))
t"      ..."
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fs-mono#@5@TWqJQlJqsUKJQbFtQlJlXkqYUrVocG1OkVGwdXFlckpqrF5JRlJqYkpmXDmXpBeekphZoGBoYaFqXaGgUlwC1pSsU60VbxGpqF@sFlyZBhDQMdCw0NblKlBTAQE9PT@n/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## JS (ES6), 179 bytes

```
x=`[....      ]
[ ....     ]
[  ....    ]
[   ....   ]
[    ....  ]
[     .... ]
[      ....]
[.      ...]
[..      ..]
[...      .]`.split`
`;c=0;setTimeout(y=>alert(x[++c]),100)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 64 bytes

```
for(){cls;"[$('...      .'*2|% s*g(9-$i++%10)10)]";sleep -m 100}
```

Where `$string|% s*g $From $Length` [is a shortcut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745) to summon `$string.SubString($From,$Length)`

This solution has one small disadvantage:

- there will be an overflow exception after the Windows style Loading bar has worked for 988 million years.

## Powershell, 65 bytes

```
for(){9..0|%{cls;"[$('...      .'*2|% s*g $_ 10)]";sleep -m 100}}
```

This Windows style Loading bar is an Immortal Eldar from Valinor.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 22 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Oq"[{'.²²úA éU°}]"Lt@ß
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=T3EiW3snLrKy%2bkEg6VWwfV0iTHRA3w)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Θo░a↑▐»xr←9hV╣ä&N╞
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e96fb06118deaf78721b396856b984264ec6&i=)