# Is there a language that supports Turing machines?

Tags: tips

Is there a programming language that supports single tape Turing machines specified in some format?

I am aware multiple formats for expressing them exist, but is there a standard one using which an acceptable answer can be published on this site?

If it doesn't exist can somebody create one? Golfing Turing machines has academic relevance too.

Comment: [This](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html) is one turing machine sim that you can at least link too, TIO has one too. Unfortunately, there aren't any golfy ones I know of. But your question is not very clear.

Comment: @Wezl Any way I can submit Turing machines as answers and have them satisfy the requirements of the site, is what I meant to say

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I have seen answers in pure turing machine code. Example: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200380/95627

Comment: @nph oo so that simulator is acceptable? By the way the spaces seem redundant and nearly double the total byte count

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code It appears to be acceptable. I think you can leave out the spaces.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic for the site.  It should have been asked on or migrated to meta, but it is too late for that now.

Answer (score 2):

It should be acceptable to post answers in pure turing machine code. I have seen people do this before.

Examples:

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/200380/95627

[Simple cat program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/simple-cat-program/193623#193623)

If anyone knows more about this, you can edit.

Answer (score 1):

[I’ve made one.](https://gitlab.com/Tom_Fryers/turma)

It’s an interpreter written in Python, so it’s not ideal for anything intensive, but the source format is fairly concise for golfing. It uses Unicode characters as tape symbols.